# How to make a drop-shadow for a Graphics3D objects?

Tags: graphics3d, image-processing

What's the best way to make a drop shadow for a 3D object?

```
 image = Graphics3D[Sphere[], Boxed -> False]
```

[image: sphere without drop shadow]

I can get a blurry black outline of this:

```
imageShadow = 
 Blur[RegionBinarize[ColorNegate[image], (* bottom left corner --> *) {{1, 1}}, 
   0.1], 20]
```

which could act as a good shadow:

[image: a shadow]

But combining them together is a bit harder... Any suggestions?

Comment: Older versions of *Mathematica* had the routine `Shadow[]` in the package `Graphics\`Graphics3D\``. You might want to look into it.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6955692/615464

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries good find. I didn't check the old site...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This produces a 2D shadow. If you meant a 3D shadow (on the *x-y* plane), see code below.

```
image = Rasterize[Graphics3D[Sphere[], Boxed -> False]];
shadow = Blur[RegionBinarize[ColorNegate[image], {{1, 1}}, 0.1], 20];

image = SetAlphaChannel[image, ColorNegate@Binarize[image, {1, 1}]];

Show[{shadow, image}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The position of the shadow has to be fine tuned manually.

I also managed to construct it in 3D (rotatable), though I cannot make the bottom polygon transparent.

```
shadow = Blur[
   RegionBinarize[Graphics[Circle[], ImagePadding -> 60], {{1, 1}}, 
    0.1], 40];
shadow = SetAlphaChannel[shadow, ColorNegate@shadow];

Graphics3D[{
  Sphere[],
  EdgeForm@None, Opacity@.7, Texture@shadow, 
  Polygon[{{-1, -1, -2}, {1, -1, -2}, {1, 1, -2}, {-1, 
     1, -2}, {-1, -1, -2}}, 
   VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]
  }, Boxed -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Excellent - just what I needed! Thanks.

Answer (score 45):

Objects obscure their own shadows when viewed from the position of the light source. Consider the following 3D scene:

[image]

If this scene is illuminated with a light source located at the camera position, the shadow of the cow will land on any part of the walls or floor which is obscured by the cow. Suppose we rasterize this scene with the lighting turned off and the walls glowing white - this provides a silhouette of the cow:

[image]

To use this silhouette as a shadow texture, it is necessary to map from the 3D coordinates of the wall polygons to the 2D image position. This can be done using the `ViewMatrix` which @Heike shows how to compute in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5764/862).

Here is some code which allows a 3D scene to be interactively rotated with a button which creates a shadow from the current viewpoint, outputting a copy of the `Graphics3D` with the shadow applied and a single light source at the appropriate position.

First the code (thanks to Michael E2 for fixing the initialisation of `ViewVector`):

```
theta[{x_, y_, z_}] := ArcTan[z, Norm[{x, y}]];
phi[{x_, y_, z_}] := If[Norm[{x, y}] > .0001, ArcTan[x, y], 0];
alpha[vert_, v1_] := ArcTan[{-Sin[phi[v1]], Cos[phi[v1]], 0}.vert, 
   Cross[v1/Norm[v1], {-Sin[phi[v1]], Cos[phi[v1]], 0}].vert];
tt[v1_, vert_, center_, r_, scale_] := TransformationMatrix[
   RotationTransform[-alpha[vert/scale, v1], {0, 0, 1}].
   RotationTransform[-theta[v1], {0, 1, 0}].
   RotationTransform[-phi[v1], {0, 0, 1}].
   ScalingTransform[r {1, 1, 1}].
   TranslationTransform[-center]];
pp[ang_] := {{1, 0, -Tan[ang], 1}, {0, 1, -Tan[ang], 1}, 
   {0, 0, -Tan[ang], 0}, {0, 0, -2 Tan[ang], 2}};
spos[{t_, p_}, {x_, y_, z_}] := {#1, #2}/#4 & @@ (p.t.{x, y, z, 1});
shadoweffect = # ~Blur~ 10 ~ImageAdd~ 0.3 &;

shadowCaster[gr_, shadowpolys_] := 
 DynamicModule[{pr, center, scale, v1, vv, theta, vert, va, vm, tex, vcf},
  pr = Charting`get3DPlotRange@Graphics3D[gr];
  scale = 1/Abs[#1 - #2] & @@@ pr;
  center = Mean /@ pr; va = 25 Degree; vert = {0., 0., 1.};
  v1 = 4.5 (Last@Transpose[pr] - center) + center; vv = {v1, center};
  Panel[Column[{
     Dynamic[Graphics3D[{gr, shadowpolys}, ViewAngle -> Dynamic[va], 
       ViewVector -> Dynamic[vv, (vv = #; center = vv[[2]]; v1 = vv[[1]] - center) &], 
       ViewVertical -> Dynamic[vert], Boxed -> False]],
     Button["Shadow",
      vm = {tt[v1, vert, center, Cot[va/2]/Norm[v1], scale], pp[va/2]};
      tex = Rasterize[Graphics3D[{gr, {Glow[White], EdgeForm[], shadowpolys}}, 
         ViewMatrix -> vm, Boxed -> False, Lighting -> None],  ImageSize -> 800]; 
      vcf = With[{m = {tt[v1, vert, center, Cot[va/2]/Norm[v1], scale], 
             pp[va/2]}}, spos[m, #] &];
      Print[Graphics3D[{gr, {Texture[shadoweffect@tex],
          shadowpolys /. Polygon[pts_, rest___] :> 
          Polygon[pts, rest, VertexTextureCoordinates -> vcf /@ pts]}}, 
        Lighting -> {{"Directional", White, vv}, {"Ambient", GrayLevel[0.1]}}, 
          Boxed -> False]], Method -> "Queued"]}]]]
```

It works like this. Create some 3D objects which will cast shadows:

```
cow = Translate[
   Scale[ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "Cow"}][[1]], 3], {0.2, 0, 0.75}];
```

and some polygons which will receive the shadows:

```
walls = {
   Polygon[{{-1, -1, 0}, {-1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, -1, 0}}],
   Polygon[{{-1, -1, 0}, {-1, -1, 1.5}, {1, -1, 1.5}, {1, -1, 0}}],
   Polygon[{{-1, -1, 0}, {-1, -1, 1.5}, {-1, 1, 1.5}, {-1, 1, 0}}]};
```

Then evaluate

```
shadowCaster[cow, walls]
```

[image]

Rotate the `Graphics3D` to the desired viewpoint and click the button to get this:

[image]

Note that there is only one shadow texture, which is used by all the shadow receiving polygons. It is therefore relatively quick even when a large number of polygons are used. e.g. here are ~3000 polygons approximating a curved surface:

```
surface = {EdgeForm[], Cases[Normal@
     Plot3D[Exp[-2 (x^2 + y^2)^4] - 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
      PlotPoints -> 40, PlotRange -> All, 
      MaxRecursion -> 0], _Polygon, -1]};

shadowCaster[cow, surface]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is awesome - ray-tracing next?  I did have a problem, if all variables weren't initialized properly.  Here are some suggestions:
``pr = Charting`get3DPlotRange@Graphics3D[gr];
scale = 1/Abs[#1 - #2] & @@@ pr;
center = Mean /@ pr;
va = 25 Degree;
vert = {0., 0., 1.};
v1 = 4.5 (Last@Transpose[pr] - center) + center;
vv = {v1, center};``

Comment: @MichaelE2, many thanks for the improved initialisation code - I just couldn't figure out how to get it right.

Comment: The cow-on-a-hill is very impressive.

Comment: Great, this is the way to go for smooth looking shadows on arbitrary polygons (I didn't see this until now).

Answer (score 25):

Suppose you have a flat surface with normal `n` going through point `p0` and a directional light with direction `dir`,  then the shadow of a point `p` onto this surface can be calculated according to

```
proj[p0_, n_, dir_][p_] := p - (p - p0).Normalize[n]/dir.Normalize[n] dir
```

Suppose you have a shape created with a `ParametricPlot3D`, for example

```
pt[r_, ph_, th_] := {r Cos[ph] Sin[th], r Sin[ph] Sin[th], r Cos[th]}
rf[ph_, th_] := 3/2 + 2 Cos[2 th] Sin[ph]^2

shape = ParametricPlot3D[pt[rf[ph, th], ph, th], {ph, 0, 2 Pi}, {th, 0, Pi}, 
  Mesh -> False]
```

Then the shadow of this shape could be calculated according to

```
shdw = With[{p0 = {0, 0, -4}, n = {0, 0, 1}, dir = {1, 0, -1}},
   ParametricPlot3D[proj[p0, n, dir][pt[rf[ph, th], ph, th]], 
    {ph, 0, 2 Pi}, {th, 0, Pi}, Mesh -> False, PlotStyle -> Black]];

Show[shape, shdw, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

To get blurry edges on the shadow you could do something like this

```
With[{p0 = {0, 0, -4}, n = {0, 0, 1}, dir = {1/3, 1/2, -1},
    plotr = {{-8, 8}, {-8, 8}, {-5, 4}}},

  (* blurred image of shadow to be used as a texture *)
  tex = Blur[Rasterize[
    ParametricPlot[proj[p0, n, dir][pt[rf[ph, th], ph, th]][[;; 2]], 
      {ph, 0, 2 Pi}, {th, 0, Pi}, 
      Mesh -> False, 
      PlotStyle -> {Black, Opacity[1]}, 
      Axes -> False, Frame -> False,
      PlotRange -> plotr[[;; 2]],
      Background -> None], 
    Background -> None], 10];

  shdw = Graphics3D[{Texture[ImageData[tex]], EdgeForm[],
    Polygon[
      p0 + RotationTransform[{{0, 0, 1}, n}][Flatten[{#, 0}]] & /@ 
        Tuples[plotr[[;; 2]]][[{1, 2, 4, 3}]],
      VertexTextureCoordinates -> Tuples[{0, 1}, 2][[{1, 2, 4, 3}]]]}];

  Show[shdw, shape,
    Lighting -> {{"Directional", White, {0, -1, 1}}}, 
    PlotRange -> plotr,
    Axes -> False]]
  ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Similar to István's solutions, I'm using a blurred rasterized image of the projected shape as a texture for the surface on which the shadow is projected. To get a transparent texture I'm using `ImageData[tex]` as the texture rather than `tex` itself. To get the scaling right when applying the texture, I'm using the same `PlotRange` for `tex` as for the polygon.

Comment: Very good answer!

Comment: I'll just note that this is more or less what `Shadow[]` in older versions of *Mathematica* does.

Comment: Wish I could up-vote twice! @J.M. what is `Shadow[]`? Couldn't find it in the documentation.

Comment: @Dror, It's one of the routines in the old ``Graphics`Graphics` `` package in earlier versions of *Mathematica*...

Answer (score 21):

Since a drop shadow is a projection, I thought it's useful to provide a more general solution that creates this projection for arbitrary Graphics3D objects with less manual tuning. I am skipping the blur effect because I want to focus on the projection issue (Mathematica isn't a ray tracer, so I feel it's a bit too painful to simulate shadow boundaries using blur).

Here is my code:

```
Options[project] = {"ObjectCenter" -> {0, 0, 0}, 
   "DarkShadow" -> True};
project[x_, direction_, normal_, OptionsPattern[]] := Module[
  {d, n, darkShadow, center},
  darkShadow = OptionValue["DarkShadow"];
  center = OptionValue["ObjectCenter"];
  d = Normalize[direction];
  n = Normalize[normal];
  x /. Graphics3D[gr_, opts___] :> Graphics3D[
     {
      If[darkShadow, Black],
      GeometricTransformation[
       If[darkShadow,
        gr /. {
          Glow[_] -> Glow[],

          r_?(MemberQ[{RGBColor, Hue, CMYKColor, GrayLevel}, 
               Head[#]] &) -> Black
          },
        gr
        ],
       Composition[
        TranslationTransform[direction + center],
        Quiet[Check[RotationTransform[{d, n}], Identity],
         {RotationMatrix::degen, RotationTransform::spln}
         ],
        ScalingTransform[10^-3, d],
        Quiet@Check[
          ScalingTransform[1./(n.d), n - (n.d) d],
          Identity
          ],
        TranslationTransform[-center]
        ]
       ]
      },
     opts
     ]
  ]
```

The argument `x` is a 3D plot or graphics object. The second variable, `direction`, is parallel to the light rays and its length is equal to the offset between the object and its shadow (assuming the object was centered at the origin). The third argument, `normal`, is the normal vector of the surface onto which the shadow is projected.

**Edit**

The translation by vector `direction` is applied *after* the object has effectively been moved to a plane containing the origin. This happens in the "flattening step" (the multiplication by `10^-3` in `ScalingTransform`). If you want the translation to start from a different position, this can be specified via the option `"ObjectCenter"`. For an example with a more specific description, [see also this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/30522/245).

**End edit**

To illustrate this, I'll define a sample object (displayed below with its shadow):

```
gg = Graphics3D[{{Opacity[.5], Cuboid[]}, {Blue, 
    Translate[Scale[Cuboid[], .2], {1, 1, 1}/2]}, , {Glow[Red], Red, 
    Translate[Scale[Sphere[], .5], -{1, 1, 1}/4]}}, Boxed -> False]
```

Now display it with some coordinate axis for orientation, assuming light going in the direction {0,1,1} and falling on a surface tilted into the space diagonal {1,1,1}:

```
Show[gg, 
     project[gg, 2.1 {0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}],
     Graphics3D[{Map[{Apply[RGBColor, #], Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, #}]]} &, 
    2 IdentityMatrix[3]]}]
]
```

[image: 3D object and its shadow under illumination from diagonally below]

The projection is stretched if the shadow surface isn't perpendicular to the rays. Of course there is the special case where the shadow surface is at a grazing angle to the light. I decided to handle this by not stretching the shadow.

Also observe that translucent regions create less dark shadows. And the whole thing is still a 3D object, not a bitmap.

Another example:

```
Show[gg, 
     project[gg, -1.5 {0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}], 
     Graphics3D[{Map[{Apply[RGBColor, #], Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, #}]]} &, 
    2 IdentityMatrix[3]]}]
]
```

[image: 3D object and its shadow under illumination from above]

Comment: That's an impressive piece of code. I'm going to work through it later today. Thanks!