# Extract values for ViewMatrix from a Graphics3D

Tags: graphics3d, options

Under [*More Information*](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ViewMatrix.html?q=ViewMatrix&lang=en) in the help page of `ViewMatrix` the following entry can be found

> With the setting `ViewMatrix->Automatic`, explicit forms for the matrix `m` can be found using `AbsoluteOptions[g,ViewMatrix]`.

Trying this with a basic example

```
gr = Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}];
AbsoluteOptions[gr, ViewMatrix]

(* Out[11]= {ViewMatrix -> Automatic} *)
```

shows, that this does not work as I would have expected it. Even setting `ViewMatrix` explicitly to `Automatic` does not help. I tried this on Linux and MacOSX.

Can someone tell me how this is supposed to be used and how I can extract explicit values for the viewing matrix which is used for the projection?

Comment: According to the documentation, "With the default setting ViewMatrix->Automatic, the matrices {t,p} are found automatically from the settings for options such as ViewPoint, ViewVertical, and ViewAngle."  It may be useful to take examine the code at http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/UsingViewMatrix/ to see how the default settings can be used to produce the two needed matrices.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

The documentation is wrong. It should have been fixed, but `AbsoluteOptions` does not work with `ViewMatrix` (on all platforms). M- introduced interactive 3D graphics since V6, and after that getting values through `AbsoluteOptions` (which is an old function) becomes very tricky since the Kernel (who evaluates the option) cannot fully know what is happening on FrontEnd side. To compare, before V6, the Kernel was solely responsible for rendering 3D scene (Postscript!), and of course it could tell every matrix value.

Instead, you can try to use 5 values that can define the matrix using `Dynamic`:
`ViewPoint`, `ViewAngle`, `ViewVertical`, `ViewCenter`, and `ViewRange`.

[image]

For instance, the following example takes those 5 values from one graphics, and use it for another:

```
DynamicModule[
 {point = {1.3, -2.4, 2}, angle = N[35 Degree], vertical = {0, 0, 1}, 
  center = Automatic},
 Grid[{{
    Framed[
     Graphics3D[{
       (* Objects *)
       EdgeForm[], Specularity[White, 20],
       FaceForm[Red], Sphere[{-0.2, -0.1, -0.3}, .2],
       FaceForm[Blue], Cylinder[{{0., 0.3, -.5}, {0., 0.3, 0.}}, .1],
       FaceForm[Green], Cone[{{0.2, 0., -0.5}, {0.2, 0., -0.1}}, .2]
       },
      Boxed -> True, Lighting -> "Neutral",
      ImageSize -> 300, RotationAction -> "Clip",

      (* View control *)
      ViewPoint -> Dynamic[point],
      ViewAngle -> Dynamic[angle],
      ViewVertical -> Dynamic[vertical],
      ViewCenter -> Dynamic[center]
      ],
     FrameStyle -> LightGray],

    (* The second object *)
    Framed[
     Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3},
      ImageSize -> 300, Axes -> False,
      (* View control *)
      ViewPoint -> Dynamic[point],
      ViewAngle -> Dynamic[angle],
      ViewVertical -> Dynamic[vertical],
      ViewCenter -> Dynamic[center]
      ],
     FrameStyle -> LightGray]
    }}]
 ]
```

Examples:
[image: Mathematica graphics]

and

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This free course explains about the values in vary detail (with some cool demos--OK. shameless self-promotion :) ):

[Wolfram Training: Visualization: Advanced 3D Graphics](http://www.wolfram.com/training/courses/gen422.html)

Also, in essence, you can reconstruct the view matrix and projection matrix out of those values, but I need to take a look at an old textbook to make sure that I am not saying something wrong :)

Comment: +1 Very useful diagram and explanation. Much better than the documentation for the individual View settings!

Comment: +1 for this very illustrative answer, although I already know all this from OpenGL, rendering, and so on. The reason, why I specifically asked how to extract the used projection is, because I want to transform the underly 3d mesh points by myself. For this, I need the used projection for any arbitrary Mathematica `Graphics3D`. Can we get this from the FE?

Comment: @Yu-Sung Chang, since this clearly answers my question, I'll accept this. Maybe, I ask a follow-up in another post and I would be grateful when you would look at it too;-)

Comment: @halitutan, Certainly!

Comment: This image should be part of the documentation.

Comment: @Yu-Sung Chang This is much needed and much appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: @Yu-SungChang Was the documentation fixed? Your diagram/post should definitely be added to the details for `Graphics3D` refpage!

Comment: Reminds me of https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/DynamicViewPointSynchronize

Answer (score 55):

It got a bit out of hand, but here's a way to construct a `ViewMatrix` pair from the triple `ViewVector`, `ViewAngle`, and `ViewVertical`. The left figure is the `Graphics3D` object using `ViewVector`, `ViewAngle`, and `ViewVertical` and the right is the one using `ViewMatrix`. If you rotate the left figure or scale it (by dragging the figure while keeping <kbd>Alt</kbd> depressed), the `ViewMatrix` is updated automatically.

```
DynamicModule[{tt, pp, bb, gr, center, scale, v1, vv,
  theta, phi, alpha, vert, viewAngle},
 gr = {Cuboid[{-1, -1, -1}, {0, 0, 0}], 
   Cuboid[], {Red, Cuboid[{-1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1}]},
   {Blue, Cuboid[{2, 0, 1}, {3, 1, 2}]}};
 bb = PlotRange[Graphics3D[gr]];
 scale = 1/Abs[#1 - #2] & @@@ bb;
 center = Mean /@ bb;
 vv = {{6, 5, 2}, Mean /@ bb};
 v1 = (vv[[1]] - center);
 vert = {0, 0, 1} - {0, 0, 1}.v1 v1;
 viewAngle = 50 Degree;

 theta[v1_] := ArcTan[v1[[3]], Norm[v1[[;; 2]]]];
 phi[v1_] := If[Norm[v1[[;; 2]]] > .0001, ArcTan[v1[[1]], v1[[2]]], 0];
 alpha[vert_, v1_] := ArcTan[{-Sin[phi[v1]], Cos[phi[v1]], 0}.vert, 
   Cross[v1/Norm[v1], {-Sin[phi[v1]], Cos[phi[v1]], 0}].vert];

 tt[v1_, vert_, center_, r_] := TransformationMatrix[
   RotationTransform[-alpha[vert/scale, v1], {0, 0, 1}].
    RotationTransform[-theta[v1], {0, 1, 0}].
    RotationTransform[-phi[v1], {0, 0, 1}].
    ScalingTransform[r {1, 1, 1}].
    TranslationTransform[-center]];

 pp[ang_] := {{1, 0, - Tan[ang], 1}, {0, 1, - Tan[ang ], 1}, {0, 
    0, -Tan[ang ], 0}, {0, 0, -2 Tan[ang] , 2}};

 Panel[Column[{Labeled[#, 
       Style["Transforming ViewVector/ViewVertical/ViewAngle to ViewMatrix", 
       15, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Bold], 
       Top, Background -> White, Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Gray] &@
     Grid[{
       {Labeled[Dynamic@
          Graphics3D[{gr}, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"},
           ViewAngle -> Dynamic[viewAngle], 
           ViewVector -> Dynamic[vv, (vv = #; center = vv[[2]]; v1 = vv[[1]] - center) &],
           ViewVertical -> Dynamic[vert],
           ImageSize -> 270],
         Style["ViewVector, ViewVertical, ViewAngle", FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Bold], 
         Top, Frame -> True],

        Labeled[Dynamic@Graphics3D[{gr},
            ViewMatrix -> {tt[v1, vert, center, Cot[viewAngle/2]/Norm[v1]], pp[viewAngle/2]}, 
            Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, ImageSize -> 270],
         Style["ViewMatrix", Bold, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], Top, 
         Frame -> True]},

       {Dynamic@ Labeled[N[{tt[v1, vert, center, Cot[viewAngle/2]/Norm[v1]], 
              pp[viewAngle/2]}] /. {a_?NumericQ :> NumberForm[a, 3]} //
            MatrixForm[#, TableDirections -> Row] &,
          Style["ViewMatrix", 12, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Bold], Left], SpanFromLeft}},
      Spacings -> {1, 2}],
    Button["Print ViewMatrix",
     Print[N[{tt[v1, vert, center, Cot[viewAngle/2]/Norm[v1]], pp[viewAngle/2]}]],
     ImageSize -> 150]},
   Alignment -> Left]
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: If you ever come back to the site, I just wanted to let you know I've found this answer useful many times now, especially `tt`.

Answer (score 1):

As of version 13.0, `AbsoluteOptions` is finally updated, and the mentioned issue no longer exists nowadays:

```
gr = Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}];
AbsoluteOptions[gr, ViewMatrix]
(* {ViewMatrix -> {{{0.140687, 0.114308, 0., 0.}, 
                    {-0.0450415, 0.12473, 0.154878, 4.53058*10^-6}, 
                    {-0.0614696, 0.170224, -0.113486, 3.38378}, 
                    {0., 0., 0., 1.}}, 
                   {{2.96386, 0., 0.5, 0.}, 
                    {0., 2.96386, 0.5, 0.}, 
                    {0., 0., 3.04444, -8.27738}, 
                    {0., 0., 1., 0.}}}} *)
```