# Extract current viewing parameters from a 3D view?

Tags: graphics3d

Is there a way to find out the current viewing parameters of a 3D view? What often happens is that I create a view, for example:

```
Graphics3D[{Blue, Cuboid[], Yellow, Sphere[]}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image: first view]

and then spend some time adjusting it using the mouse to pan, zoom, and rotate it:

[image: second view]

Now I'd like to know what those settings (view point, etc.) are, so that they can be integrated as defaults into the next edit. It looks like an easy problem but I can't find out how to do it. At the moment there's a lot of trial and error involved.

Comment: See for example [this answer by Yu-Sung Chang](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3538/46)

Comment: Would you mind editing in code that can be copied (not just screenshots)?

Comment: @YvesKlett sorry, didn't think the code was worth adding ...

Comment: Nah, I´d say it is always worth prepping the question as far as possible to attract and encourage answers.

Comment: BTW, the excellent [upload palette](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5/can-i-easily-post-images-to-this-site-directly-from-mathematica-yes) works wonders here...

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can dynamically extract `ViewPoint` and others like this (also useful for synchronization of different plots etc.):

```
vp = Options[Graphics3D, ViewPoint][[1, 2]];

Graphics3D[Cuboid[], ViewPoint -> Dynamic[vp]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This value is now constantly updated:

```
Dynamic[vp]
```

> {1.3, -2.4, 2.}

This seem also to work fine with other functions that use the `ViewPoint` option. Below, `ViewPoint` and `ViewVertical` are in sync for both objects:

```
{vp, vv} = Options[Graphics3D, {ViewPoint, ViewVertical}][[All, 2]];

Grid[{{Graphics3D[Cuboid[], ViewPoint -> Dynamic[vp], 
    ViewVertical -> Dynamic[vv]], 
   ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[u], Sin[u] + Cos[v], Sin[v]}, {u, 0, 
     2 Pi}, {v, -Pi, Pi}, ViewPoint -> Dynamic[vp], 
    ViewVertical -> Dynamic[vv]]}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Should this technique work with `ParametricPlot3D`, etc?

Comment: @texasAUtiger yes it should... just about for any function using the  `ViewPoint` option.

Comment: It does not seem to work with `Show` though

Answer (score 57):

Perhaps the most easiest way is to use `Options`

1. `Graphics3D[Cuboid[]]` to plot the figure;
2. Manipulate the figure at your will,such as zooming in, rotate and so on;
3. Copy the manipulated figure and add `//Options` after it, and press enter. You will get the options of the manipulated figure.

[image]

Comment: I've put this to good use. I set variable *view* with a rotated-and-shrinked copy-pasted graphics *gr* with postfix extraction: `view = gr // Options[#, {ViewPoint, ViewVertical}] &` and then use `Sequence @@ view` in the cell that generated gr.

Answer (score 23):

The following function may be helpful:

```
ExtrahiereViews[ll_]:=
  Flatten[Union[Extract[ll,Position[ll,#]]&/@
  {ViewPoint->_, ViewCenter->_, ViewVertical->_,
   ViewAngle->_, ViewVector->_, ViewRange->_}]];
```

How to do:

1. Enter `ExtrahiereViews[]` in a cell below the graphic.
2. Move the graphic to your liking.
3. Set the cursor between the brackets of `ExtrahiereViews`.
4. Make a "Copy output from above" (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>) and evaluate. You'll get the values.

Comment: Thanks - I can't get it working yet, but thanks nonetheless, still working on it. Do you mean copy the graphic into the place where the `ll_` is? Then what happens to the `ll`? Also, should I remove the semicolon? And by Copy output from above do you mean "Insert>Output From Above" (command-shift-L on Mac)?

Comment: Plus we learn the german translation for "extract" ;-)

Comment: @cormullion 1.) If you don't move, rotate, ... the grahphics with the mouse, the output will be an empty list. 2.) Yes, you have to Ctrl+Shilt+L the graphcs between the [ ]. The `ll` used in the definition will then be replaces by the graphic (which is a mathematica object like any other).

Comment: This is how I do it now, thanks. Function defined shorter: `ExtrahiereViews[ll_] := Options[ll, {ViewPoint, ViewVertical}]` (will extract only two options I personally need).

Comment: You may find it easier to refer to your graphic by sheet output number, e.g., `ExtrahiereViews[%36]`