# Reversing one axis in Plot3D

Tags: plotting

When I rotate my 3D plot to the desired viewpoint my X axis runs from 1 at the left to 0 at the right. How can I mirror my plot so that 0 will be at the left and 1 at the right?

Extra credit: how can I get the `ViewPoint` vector after manual rotation?

Comment: You can get the answer to your extra credit question [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5375/extract-current-viewing-parameters-from-a-3d-view).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer the last part of question, this can be done by setting something like `ViewPoint -> Dynamic[vp]` in the plot definition. Then the value of `vp` will be dynamically updated to the current view point when you rotate the plot. Try for example

```
Plot3D[x^4 y, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, Pi}, PlotRange -> All, ViewPoint -> Dynamic[vp]]
Dynamic[vp]
```

Note that `vp` must be defined as a triple of numbers.

As for the first part of your question, I don't know how you're creating your plot, but if you're using `Plot3D` you could just swap the second and third argument. For example

```
vp = {1, 1, 1};
Plot3D[x^4 y Sin[5 y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, Pi}, PlotRange -> All, 
 ViewPoint -> Dynamic[vp]]
Plot3D[x^4 y Sin[5 y], {y, 0, Pi}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, 
 ViewPoint -> Dynamic[vp[[{2, 1, 3}]]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that this will effectively swap the x- and y-axis, thus changing the coordinate system from being right-handed to left-handed.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding but I don't think your answer to the first part of stevenvh's question actually answers the question. It seems to me that his problem is that his axis runs from higher value to lower value (e.g. 1 to 0) from left to right, rather than lower value to higher value (e.g. 0 to 1). Simply swapping the x and y axes won't do, because as we can see in your second plot, one of your horizontal axes still runs from higher value to lower value (about 3.2 to 0). How does one mirror that, so it runs from lower to higher value, like the other horizontal axis (0 to about 1)?

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to swapping x and y axes in Heike's answer, you can use a combination of settings for `AxesEdge` and `ViewPoint`:

```
 vp = {-2, 3, 2}; 
 Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, 0, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
 BoxRatios -> 1, AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y", "Z"}, Axes -> True, 
 AxesEdge -> {{1, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}}, ViewPoint -> Dynamic[vp], 
 PlotLabel -> Dynamic[vp]]
```

[image]

Comment: Am I right that this only places the axes on the other side of the bounding box? It doesn't allow the Y = -1 to coincide with the X = 0, it seems.

Comment: @stevenvh, does changing `AxesEdge->{{-1, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}}` give what you need?

Comment: No. I want the curve to be mirrored through the Y = 0 plane, so that Y = -1 and Y = 1 exchange places.

Comment: I see...perhaps some of form of `ReflectionTransform`..

Comment: Sorry, still not what I want, I guess. I checked ReflectionTransform, and as I understand it it reflects the function, so *that* will be mirrored, but the *axis* won't. I need a mirrored view of the curve, but because the axis is reflected, not the function. Sorry. Thanks for your time, though.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simpler way to see the `ViewPoint` vector (and many other plot attributes) after a manual rotation: just type `//Options` right after the `Graphics` object and evaluate.