# Synchronizing manual rotations for multiple Graphics3D outputs?

Tags: graphics, graphics3d

Say I make a set of three Graphics3D images, here of three different cones, by evaluating:

```
{Graphics3D[{Cone[{{0, 0, 0}, {2, 3, 4}}, 3]}], 
 Graphics3D[{Cone[{{1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}, 4]}], 
 Graphics3D[{Cone[{{1, 1, 1}, {9, 9, 9}}, 4]}]}
```

I would like to manually rotate one of the images showing a single cone, and have the other objects follow that rotation, or at least rotate to the final state once I let go of my mouse. Is this possible?

Comment: Are you asking how to couple the mouse actions that _Mathematica_ supports automatically when a `Graphics3D` image is displayed? Or are you asking how to do it using some dynamic construct such as `Manipulate`. I don't think the first is possible. At least, I don't how to do it. I'm sure the second can be done. However, in both cases, you are asking for others to do a heck of a lot work for you with no effort on your part.

Comment: @m_goldberg I just want to do the following: rotate one image manually some number of degrees $(\theta,\phi)$, then apply that same rotation to the other images.  Surely there must be some simple way to do this?  I don't necessarily need the other images to follow dynamically.

Comment: What do you mean by "manually"?

Comment: @m_goldberg I want to click and drag to orient the image how I'd like.

Comment: @m_goldberg A good enough solution here would be for me to be able to read out some absolute orientation parameter for a Graphics3D output, and then rotate the other Graphics3D outputs by that same amount.  I would also settle for a way to enter in rotation instructions for one Graphics3D output, though it would be nice to be able to do click and drag.

Comment: Related: [Extract current viewing parameters from a 3D view?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5375/extract-current-viewing-parameters-from-a-3d-view/5377#5377)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make the settings for both `ViewPoint` and `ViewVertical` dynamic:

```
DynamicModule[{vp = {2, -2, 1}, vv = {0, 0, 1}}, 
GraphicsRow[{Graphics3D[{Cone[{{0, 0, 0}, {2, 3, 4}}, 3]}, SphericalRegion -> True,
  ViewPoint -> Dynamic[vp], ViewVertical -> Dynamic[vv]], 
 Graphics3D[{Cone[{{1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}, 4]}, SphericalRegion -> True,
  ViewPoint -> Dynamic[vp], ViewVertical -> Dynamic[vv]], 
 Graphics3D[{Cone[{{1, 1, 1}, {9, 9, 9}}, 4]}, SphericalRegion -> True,
  ViewPoint -> Dynamic[vp], ViewVertical -> Dynamic[vv]]}]]
```

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

Thanks: @Szabolcs for pointing out the need for `ViewVertical` in addition to `ViewPoint` to have the three graphics line up properly.

See also: [Yu-Sung Chang's answer/tutorial](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3538/1250) in response to a related question.

Comment: Great - perfect!

Comment: +1. Well, I knew it could done with a dynamic construct, but I didn't realize it could be done this easily.

Comment: A more elaborate answer can be found [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3538/57).

Comment: @Sjoerd, thank you. I was looking for that link.

Comment: @Szabolcs, thank you; updated the answer with your suggestion.