# Automatically tracing and keeping ViewPoints in a list while manually rotating 3D graphics

Tags: graphics, dynamic

I will need to make a video from the manual rotation of a 3D graphics. In order to do this, I will need to record the set of all view points that I made during rotation. There is method that we can use to get a single viewpoint, like discussed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5375/extract-current-viewing-parameters-from-a-3d-view), but can we find a way to use AppendTo or Sow and Reap to automatically store all the view points in a list?

Comment: Why don't you use a screen recording program?

Comment: @Szabolcs: I just hope to do as many things as possible from within Mathematica :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a start:

```
(* Recording *)

vp = OptionValue[Graphics3D, ViewPoint];
vv = OptionValue[Graphics3D, ViewVertical];

vprec = list[];
vvrec = list[];
g = Graphics3D[Cuboid[],
  ViewPoint -> Dynamic[vp, (vp = #; vprec = list[vprec, #]) &],
  ViewVertical -> Dynamic[vv, (vv = #; vvrec = list[vvrec, #]) &]
  ]
```

I used a linked list for O(1) appending.

Now rotate the graphic slowly using the mouse.  The view points will be recorded.

```
(* Playback *)

vpplay = List @@ Flatten[vprec, Infinity, list];
vvplay = List @@ Flatten[vvrec, Infinity, list];

ListAnimate@
 MapThread[
  Show[g, ViewPoint -> #1, ViewVertical -> #2] &, {vpplay, vvplay}]
```

[image]

For a better result you also need to record the precise time of each step (`AbsoluteTime[]`), compute the correct frame durations and reproduce them using a custom `ListAnimate`.  (When you export to GIF you can specify frame durations---check the docs on GIF exporting).

Comment: Amazing! I will need to go deep into Dynamic... Thanks!

Comment: Adopting Szabolcs's code, we can also write something like: vprec = {}; vvrec{}; then change the Dynamic[vp, (vp = #; vprec = list[vprec, #]) &] to Dynamic[vp, (vp = #; AppendTo[vprec, #]&]. This makes the code easier to read, but may decrease performance in complex situation.

Comment: @saturasl To be precise, the time taken by `AppendTo[list, ...]` is proportional to the length of `list`.  It'll slow down as the list gets big, but I haven't tried if it makes a difference in this application.  It might not.