# How to rotate 3D graphics in ListAnimate ... without making a mess?

Tags: front-end, graphics3d, animation

`Manipulate` is, of course, wonderful … but there are LOTS of examples that are simply far too computationally intensive to use live real-time animations for. In such case, one has to use pre-generated graphics. So, let us suppose we have something like:

```
ListAnimate[  Table[Plot3D[Cos[x Sin[n y]], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {y, 0, Pi}], {n, 1, 2, .1}]]
```

All fine. Then it starts playing … and you grab the plot, and rotate it … and Mma rotates ONE SINGLE plot … and leaves all the others images in the animation as they were … creating a visually absurd animation.

Suggestion:  If a user rotates one plot in a grouped animation ... even if they pre-rendered … they should all rotate by the same amount … so the animation will still work as intended.

Any suggestions as to how to overcome this short-coming in the Mma 9 front-end user interface?

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5375/131

Comment: I seem to recall another question about rotating (two) graphics together, but I cannot find it.  Does that sound familiar to anyone else?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard [this one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3538/5478)?

Comment: @Kuba yes, I believe so; thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You can create plots with `Dynamic` `ViewMatrix` components.

However, it cancels advantage of light 2D rendered graphics. But that's your wish, isn't it? Of course it is still better than dynamic updating whole `Plot`s.

```
va = 60 Degree;
vp = {1, 1, 1};
vv = {0, 0, 1};
plot = Table[Plot3D[Cos[x Sin[n y]], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},
              ImageSize -> 300, SphericalRegion -> True, PlotRange -> 1, 
              BoxRatios -> 1,
              ViewAngle -> Dynamic@va, ViewPoint -> Dynamic@vp, 
              ViewVertical -> Dynamic@vv],
            {n, 1, 2, .1}];

ListAnimate[plot]
```

[image]

Comment: That's a very clever suggestion ... but all the plots go a bit 'weird' after you grab one of them. I tried controlling this by setting `BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 3}`, which partly helped, but still compacted the resulting plots into a small box.

Comment: @wolfies I must admit I can not handle `ViewMatrix` :) take a look at an update.

Comment: @wolfies does putting Kuba's dynamic settings within the Manipulate help: `ListAnimate[
 Table[Plot3D[Cos[x Sin[n y]], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {y, 0, Pi}, 
   ViewAngle -> Dynamic@va, ViewPoint -> Dynamic@vp, 
   ViewVertical -> Dynamic@vv], {n, 1, 2, .1}], 
 Initialization :> (va = 60 Degree; vp = {1, 1, 1}; vv = {0, 0, 1};)]`

Answer (score 4):

The key is to separate the graphics from the view properties, each with its own `Dynamic` wrapper.  That way the view properties are updated by the front end independently from the `Graphics3D` data being updated from the kernel.

This can't be done with `ListAnimate` (or at least I don't see how at this point).  Every time a new graphic is presented by `ListAnimate`, the `Dynamic` view properties are recreated, interrupting the updating by the front end.

However, if we use `Animate`, we can update the graphics elements separately from the view options.  This lets the view properties be updated continuously and the graphics rotate smoothly.

```
DynamicModule[{vp, vv, va, plots},
 va = 35 Degree;
 vp = {1.3, -2.4, 2};
 vv = {0, 0, 1};
 plots = Table[
    Plot3D[Cos[x Sin[n y]], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
      PlotRange -> {0, 1}, SphericalRegion -> True, 
      ViewAngle -> Dynamic@va, ViewPoint -> Dynamic@vp, 
      ViewVertical -> Dynamic@vv],
  {n, 1, 2, .1}];

 Animate[Graphics3D[Dynamic@First@plots[[n]], 
   Options@First@plots], {n, 1, Length@plots, 1}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]