# Constantly rotating 3d contour plot (ideally as a .gif)

Tags: graphics, image-processing

I came across a neat [image](http://goo.gl/iI1OGO) for a graph, and I wanted to reproduce this as a `.gif` using `Mathematica` (I have the 9th home edition). The following block of code produces a simple "picture":

`ContourPlot3D[{2-Sqrt[1 - x^2 - (y - Abs[x])^2] Cos[30 (2 - x^2 - (y - Abs[x])^2)]}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1.5}, {z, 1,2}]`

What I would like is something ideally like that provided in the link above, where the image is rotating without it being prompted to do so. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: possible dup: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28866/how-to-rotate-3d-graphics-in-listanimate-without-making-a-mess/28882#28882.

Comment: I'd strongly encourage you to find a much simpler example to work with. This one is horrifically slow.

Comment: Also related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39398/how-to-make-a-3d-plot-auto-rotate