# How to export 3D plot, without losing the specified view of rotation?

Tags: plotting, export

Sorry I am not sure if I got anything wrong with this version of Mathematica and Mac OS X i am running. But every time I export a 3D graph, to png or tiff, I lost the view angle, view vector viewpoint information immediately. To let you know what I meant, here is a simple code:

I typed:

```
x = RevolutionPlot3D[Sqrt[((t/5)^2 - 1)*2], {t, 5, 20}]
```

And I got a plot

```
out[1]=
```

[image: Original Plot]

Then I manually rotate the plot so that it looks better, for example like this:
[image: Manually rotated view]

Ok, now, I used Export to export it to png:

```
Export["test.png", %];
```

What I got is pathetically, the un-rotated png plot!:
[image: Exported png]

This is driving me crazy and dead.. I also tried to set Viewpoint and view vector, stuff to the code, it doesn't work for me either. I also tried Export["test.png",x] too, no luck. I understand I could easily right-click to save, But I need a background-none option to make the graph transparent..

Can any one confirm (this bug?) or i am doing something stupidly wrong? I checked the documentation and googled for 1 hour, nothing found.

So the question is, how can I export the graph as it is shown on the notebook (if I can not, then what's the point of allowing us to rotate it..)

Comment: `RightClick + Save Graphics As...` or `File/Save Selection As...` or `Export["test.png", actual graphics]`

Comment: You need to `Export` the actual rotated graphics or set the view options specifically. `x` is not changed by you rotating its graphical avatar. Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5375/131

Comment: What did you mean by this? - "PS. I will be grateful like a dead man if Mathematica support plot tools like Matlab."

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov yes, this sentence is somewhat open to interpretation :D

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) [`Read the FAQs`](http://tinyurl.com/cacvex2)!  3) When you see good Q&A, vote them up by [`clicking the gray triangles`](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.  ALSO, remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [`by clicking the checkmark sign`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Comment: You have two good answers so I'll just comment to emphasise that `%` does not refer to the contents of the last output cell, it refers to the last output expression from the kernel. Nothing you do to the output cell changes the expression stored in `%`, whether it's rotating the graphics or even deleting it entirely and replacing it with a photo of your cat.

Comment: @Kuba The reason I wanted to use export is to make the background transparent. ! Save as can not make the background transparent. Thanks for your comments!

Comment: @YvesKlett I guess you are right. Even when I am exporting using x, the angle is not rotated. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

What is stored in variable `x` is different from rotated object you have in output cell. You rotated - so you changed the properties. Many ways to do this - so in addition to comments' methods...

**1) In-Export rotation**

[image]

**2) Seeing options**

[image]

```
Export["test.png", Show[x, opts]]
```

Comment: OP may be confused because he is not using `x` but `%`.

Comment: @Kuba yes, good point, I hope he reads comments ;-)

Comment: Hi @Kuba thanks so much. I actually tried to export x directly, the result is the same (un-rotated png)~ I will try to copy the output to export to see thanks!

Comment: In Export-Rotation works for me!

Answer (score 7):

To save a PNG of a plot or graphics expression, I avoid Export. I select the displayed output and click on the **Save Selection As ...** item on the **File** menu. This will save the selected output exactly as it appears on the display.

[image: saving-plot]

Comment: Hi @m_goldberg . The reason I wanted to use export is to make the background transparent. ! Save as can not make the background transparent. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: also export can make the figure much better by setting ImageResolution->500 or so.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematica has Export for 3D I'm unsure how well it exports to 3DStudio (in past versions, poorly).

The (see URLs) can Export to Renderer format (rayshade or povray) and does preserve things (the whole scene hopfully including text and tick marks - though that is little tested it has examples of 2D plots doing it well) - when they are supported (many things are, many not, Mathematica 11.0 is simply too huge to comment on).

see [How to Render, raytrace, Export Graphics3D in Mathematica 11.0](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/146423/how-to-render-raytrace-export-graphics3d-in-mathematica-11-0)

and

https://sourceforge.net/projects/rayshade-math/

Both rayshade and povray can be used to Rotate (manipulate) the resulting output realtime without Mathematica.

Answer (score 0):

I like following solution which needs no context menu. The mouse is only needed to adjust the `ViewPoint`. It uses the [answer by Yves Klett](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5377/13042) to *Extract current viewing parameters from a 3D view?*.

```
vp = Options[Graphics3D, ViewPoint][[1, 2]];
```

```
elongatedSquareGyrobicupola = 
   Graphics3D[{Gray, EdgeForm[{Thick}], 
     PolyhedronData["ElongatedSquareGyrobicupola", "GraphicsComplex"]}, 
    ViewPoint -> Dynamic[vp], Lighting -> "Neutral", Boxed -> False]
```

Now do your manual adjustment of the `ViewPoint` and then add the export routine

[image]

```
Export["out.pdf", 
 GraphicsRow[{Show[
    elongatedSquareGyrobicupola, {ViewPoint -> Dynamic[vp]}]}, 
  ImageSize -> 1000]](*export as vector graphics*)
```