# Specifying view angle of a 3D plot

Tags: plotting, export, graphics3d

I would like to create a stereogram from a 3d plot; I would like to export two images of a 3d plot at a slightly different angle, so that when each picture is presented to a different eye, one gets the feeling it is actually 3 dimensional.

I have tried to put two plots next to eachother, then turn one plot slightly by hand (mouse), but when I then export, it is as if I hadn't turned the plot at all!

example:

```
s1 = 
  Plot3D[PDF[MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {{1, 1/2}, {1/2, 1}}], {x, y}],
    {x, -2.3, 2.3}, {y, -2.3, 2.3}]
Show[GraphicsArray[{s1, s1}]]
```

How can I specify at which angle the 3d plot is exported?

PS: Just to be clear: I don't want to rotate the function which is plotted, I want to rotate the plot, including the edges of the bounding box of the plot.

Comment: Have you checked `ViewVector`?

Comment: Seems to work. Why isn't it in the documentation of `Plot3D`?

Comment: It is in `Options@Plot3D` at least.. :)

Comment: I see. I didn't know the possibility to do `Options@` yet. Thanks.

Comment: Some graphics options appear only in the documentation of [`Graphics3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Graphics3D.html).

Answer (score 7):

Here is a small tool make it easier [thanks to that answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5377/1356):

```
With[{dplot = 
     Plot3D[PDF[MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {{1, 1/2}, {1/2, 1}}], 
       {x, y}], {x, -2.3, 2.3}, {y, -2.3, 2.3}, ImageSize -> 350, 
       ViewVector -> Dynamic@vp]},
 DynamicModule[{vp, views, plot},
   Panel@Column[{dplot, 
     Button["Record View point", AppendTo[views, vp]], 
     Button["Export", {Export["~/test.pdf", GraphicsRow[plot /@ views]]; 
       extViews = views}]}, Center],

   Initialization :> (
     extViews = 0;
     views = {};
     plot = 
     Plot3D[PDF[MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {{1, 1/2}, {1/2, 1}}], 
       {x, y}], {x, -2.3, 2.3}, {y, -2.3, 2.3}, ImageSize -> 350, 
       ViewVector -> #] &;
    vp = Options[Graphics3D, ViewPoint][[1, 2]];
    )]]
```

[image]

producing:

[image]

My problem here is that I have to write twice the `Plot3D`, one with `Dynamic@vp` one with `#`. If anyone can enlighten me.. :)

Comment: I suppose you could store the plot in a variable and then use `Show` to change `ViewVector`. But your code doesn't work for me because of problems with the syntax.

Comment: @Pickett dangdang, thanks for telling me!

Comment: It works for me (MMA 9).

Comment: @corey979 I'm glad it does, I did use v8 if I remember correctly :)