# Viewpoint options for a 3D plot

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, options

Let's say I created a 3D plot in *Mathematica*. It's not oriented the way I want it, so I manually rotate it (in the output cell) to a desired view. (I tried playing with some view options in the code, but I gave up -- I admit my spatial imagination is really bad.) Here's the question: how can I find the options in the manually adjusted graph, so that I can reproduce it with *Mathematica* code?

Comment: It's similar, but not exactly my question... I want to find out options for a graphics that I manually rotated in my *Mathematica*  (version 9.0.1) notebook. Do I have to wrap my input code into `DynamicModule`? I've never used it, so I'd have to learn it first.

Comment: @zipirovich you are right. I will leave the comment so that topic will be linked.

Comment: @zipirovich There is also [this one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48265/specifying-view-angle-of-a-3d-plot/48272#48272) if you like ;o)