# Dynamic ClipPlanes calculated from current ViewPoint

Tags: graphics3d, dynamic

(This is a follow-up question to the answer found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/77217/dynamic-viewpoint-on-notebook-startup).)

I would like to define a clip plane dynamically from the current `ViewPoint` of my `Graphics3D`. Based on the solution found in the link above, I would like to do something like this (where the `ClipPlanes` option depends on the `ViewPoint` variable `vp`):

```
DynamicModule[
   {vp},
   {vp} = Options[Graphics3D, ViewPoint][[All, 2]];
   Graphics3D[{FaceForm[Red, Blue], Sphere[]}, Axes -> True, ViewPoint -> Dynamic[vp], 
     ClipPlanes -> {{Sequence@@vp,0}}, ClipPlanesStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.2], Blue]
   ]
]
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work, and I couldn't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this may be the behavior you desire.  I am borrowing Kuba's modified [`ClipPanes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ClipPanes.html) specification.  One should not need [`RawBoxes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RawBoxes.html) here I think but it does serve the purpose to get our `Dynamic` expression into the Front End box form.

```
DynamicModule[{vp},
  {vp} = Options[Graphics3D, ViewPoint][[All, 2]];
  Graphics3D[{FaceForm[Red, Blue], Sphere[]},
    Axes -> True,
    ViewPoint -> Dynamic[vp],
    ClipPlanes -> RawBoxes @ Dynamic @ {{Sequence @@ Cross[vp, {0, 0, 1}], 1}}, 
    ClipPlanesStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.2], Blue]
  ]
]
```

[image]

In [Evaluation leak from Dynamic in Button's action](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/115888/evaluation-leak-from-dynamic-in-buttons-action/116030#116030) John Fultz writes with fair authority:

> Front end options, which includes all box options, can take `Dynamic` heads.  That basically means that the FE will compute the value of the `Dynamic` and use it for the option.  And that it will be updated whenever a `Dynamic` dependency updates.

Since:

1. `Graphic3D` expression is transformed into a `Graphics3DBox` (as may be viewed with menu command **Cell** > **Show Expression**)
2. `ClipPlanes` remains as an option therein

it stands to reason that this must work if we can keep our `Dynamic` option value unmolested, and `RawBoxes` serves to do that.

Comment: Uff, at least I was right! Nice trick.

Comment: @Kuba Thanks for adding the animation.  This is a perfect example of a time where I wish the *collaborative answer* feature I have lobbied for had been implemented, but since it has not been and I see no benefit in this case to dueling answers I would be willing to delete mine and merge its useful content into yours.  Shall I?

Comment: Of course not, it's your answer which is valid. I hope OP comes soon to change the accepted one, if that won't happen I will delete mine.

Comment: Somehow the clipping, doesn't work with this solution if I change the clip plane option to `ClipPlanes -> RawBoxes@Dynamic@{{Sequence @@ (vp), 0}}`. What I'm trying to achieve is to always hide the back of my rendered object.

Comment: @Konstantin probably FE thinks it can handle it and then it can't. Let's put there something tougher so it has not choice ;) `RawBoxes@Dynamic@{Append[vp, 1]}` - seems to work. p.s. don't quote my attempt to explain that :)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I think this question deserves a [tag:bugs], don't you agree? I'd just put `Dynamic` in the question so it's clear that something that should work, isnt'.

Comment: @Kuba Interesting conjecture and work-around!  Given that `View*` Options pass `Dynamic` I think this Option was overlooked.  Is an omission a bug?  I am honestly not sure.  Let's wait for one more affirmation before we tag it.

Comment: @Kuba I decided to post a new question about this: [(118646)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/118646/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard RawBoxes is not needed in V11.1, at least here.

Comment: @Kuba Good to know.  What about the other examples in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/118646/121?

Comment: Only `ClipPlanes` are not present and Cases returns: `{AxesLabel, AxesStyle, Epilog, PlotLabel, Prolog}`

Answer (score 3):

Skip that and go upvote Mr.Wizard's answer :-)

---

I don't know much about rendering of `Graphics3D` by `FrontEnd`, but I'd expect `ClipPlanes` to accept `Dynamic` setting. `GraphicsBox3D` stays the same after changing it so it seems it is a `FrontEnd` which handles it anyway.

It is not the case but we can deal with that problem.

- we need `Dynamic @ Graphics3d`
- we need to send info about `ViewPoint` changes different way than `Graphics3D` is returned to not choke things. That's why the outer `Dynamic` is `a-Synchronous`

Not perfect but don't know how to make it better

(*changed ClipPlanes to make them more visible*)

```
DynamicModule[{vp}, 
 {vp} = Options[Graphics3D, ViewPoint][[All, 2]];
 Dynamic[
  Graphics3D[{FaceForm[Red, Blue], Sphere[]}, Axes -> True, 
   ViewPoint -> Dynamic[vp], 
   ClipPlanes -> {{Sequence @@ Cross[vp, {0, 0, 1}], 1}}, 
   ClipPlanesStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.2], Blue],
   SphericalRegion -> True],
  SynchronousUpdating -> False
  ]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks that is exactly what I needed!

Comment: @Konstantin As a rule it is best not to Accept an answer so quickly.  It may discourage others form looking at and working on your problem, and sometimes even better answers are in store if you let them happen. :^)

Comment: Kuba, you have my vote of course, but I think it is merely a bug stopping this from working directly as-is.  `RawBoxes` seems sufficient to bypass this.  Do you concur?