# Inconsistent handling of Dynamic option values; intended, omission, or bug?

Tags: front-end, dynamic, options, boxes

In answering [Dynamic ClipPlanes calculated from current ViewPoint](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/118486/121) Kuba and I got into a brief exchange regarding how Option values wrapped in [`Dynamic`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dynamic.html) should be handled.  For background John Fultz [wrote](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/115888/evaluation-leak-from-dynamic-in-buttons-action/116030#116030):

> Front end options, which includes all box options, can take `Dynamic` heads.  That basically means that the FE will compute the value of the `Dynamic` and use it for the option.  And that it will be updated whenever a `Dynamic` dependency updates.

It would therefore appear advantageous for Option values that become Box options to preserve a `Dynamic` head, and indeed many do, however some do not.  For example:

```
gr3D = Graphics3D[{}, MapAt[Dynamic, 2] /@ Options @ Graphics3DBox];

Tally[Head /@ Values @ Options @ ToBoxes @ gr3D]
```

> ```
> {{Dynamic, 51}, {DynamicBox, 6}}
> ```

All but six Options pass their `Dynamic` values; these six allow conversion to `DynamicBox`:

```
Cases[Options @ ToBoxes @ gr3D, _[op_, _DynamicBox] :> op]
```

> ```
> {AxesLabel, AxesStyle, ClipPlanes, Epilog, PlotLabel, Prolog}
> ```

Should these six Options *also* pass `Dynamic` values or is there a design intent that they do not?

(Observations in 10.1.0 under Windows, in case this behavior is version dependent.)

---

#### Further consideration

It is worth noting that in the case of expressions which are explicitly displayed a `DynamicBox` "works" because it is an active element in the front end, therefore e.g. a dynamic value of `PlotLabel` updates appropriately:

```
Slider[Dynamic[x], {0, 1}]

Graphics3D[Ball[], PlotLabel -> Dynamic[x]]
```

[image]

However something that is *not* explicitly displayed, such as a style directive, would seem an inappropriate place for a `DynamicBox` expression, and it does indeed produce an error message:

```
x = Red;

Graphics[Disk[], AxesStyle -> Dynamic[x]]
```

> (* shown by clicking the "+" next to the error frame *)
>
> An improperly formatted directive with head DynamicBox was encountered.

**In the case of `AxesStyle` I think conversion to `DynamicBox` is simply a mistake.**

This can be bypassed by use of a [`RawBoxes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RawBoxes.html) wrapper, which if respected prevents processing during Box conversion.

```
(* Thanks to Kuba for the concise example *)

ColorSlider @ Dynamic[x]

Graphics[
 Disk[],
 Axes -> True,
 BaseStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[3],
 AxesStyle -> RawBoxes @ Dynamic[x]
]
```

[image]

The case of [`AxesLabel`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AxesLabel.html) is somewhat ambiguous as its elements are explicitly displayed, therefore individual `Dynamic` labels being converted into `DynamicBox` expressions might be appropriate.  However there are problems.

In version 10.1.0 under Windows this initially works but closing the Notebook in which it resides **hangs** the FrontEnd:

```
(*  THIS CODE MAY HANG THE FRONT-END

ColorSlider @ Dynamic[x]

Graphics[Disk[],
  Axes -> True,
  AxesLabel -> Dynamic[x]
]

*)
```

This likewise works initially but **hangs** the FrontEnd on close:

```
(*  THIS CODE MAY HANG THE FRONT-END

ColorSlider @ Dynamic[x]

Graphics[Disk[],
  Axes -> True,
  AxesLabel -> {Dynamic[x]}
]

*)
```

Adding `RawBoxes` to a bare `Dynamic` does not work right:

```
ColorSlider @ Dynamic[x]

Graphics[Disk[],
 Axes -> True,
 AxesLabel -> RawBoxes @ Dynamic[x]
]
```

> An unknown box name (RGBColor) was sent as the BoxForm for the expression. Check the format rules for the expression.

This implies an explanation for Box conversion: in `GraphicsBox` the value of `AxesLabel` needs to be in Box form.  Attempting this conversion *inside* our force-fed `Dynamic` once again produces an initial result but hangs on close:

```
(*  THIS CODE MAY HANG THE FRONT-END

ColorSlider @ Dynamic[x]

Graphics[Disk[],
  Axes -> True,
  AxesLabel -> RawBoxes @ Dynamic @ ToBoxes @ x
]

*)
```

There clearly seems to be a bug (in 10.1.0) with the use of dynamic values in AxesLabel.

Comment: None of the examples are hanging the front end in 10.4.1 on Windows, though all other observations match.

Comment: @Simon Thanks.  I guess that bug is fixed.  What do you think of the handling of `AxesStyle` and `ClipPlanes`?

Comment: It certainly seems inconsistent - why is `AxesStyle` handled differently to `FrameStyle` for example?

Comment: The conversion of options to boxes is done by ``System`Dump`GraphicsOptionsToBoxes`` which in turn calls ``Typeset`MakeBoxes`` on each option. ``Typeset`MakeBoxes`` has a huge list of downvalues, including a special case for `AxesStyle`, essentially `MakeBoxes[AxesStyle -> stuff]` becomes `AxesStyle -> MakeBoxes[stuff]`. There is no such special case for `FrameStyle` (you end up with ``Typeset`Hold[FrameStyle -> stuff]``). I suppose there are good reasons for this, which perhaps have nothing to do with Dynamic.