# How can I show the current ViewPoint, ViewAngle, ViewCenter, etc. while I am rotating interactively a 3D object?

Tags: graphics3d, dynamic, interactive

I want to find the more looking view of my 3D object. But I want to do it interactively, and then fix that view as default.
I want to show dynamically the values of `ViewPoint`, `ViewAngle`, `ViewCenter`, etc. while I am rotating the object with the mouse.

Comment: That and more: [**Extract values for ViewMatrix from a Graphics3D**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3528/5478)

Comment: @Kuba that's really clever. I would never have realized the FE would respect those `Dynamics` in the options settings. Another FE trick I'll have to keep in mind.

Comment: @MB1965 here's more: [**118646**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/118646/5478).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Edit

Kuba provided a link to [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3528/extract-values-for-viewmatrix-from-a-graphics3d) which is the right way to go about this, as well as [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/118646/inconsistent-handling-of-dynamic-option-values-intended-omission-or-bug) further discussion on using `Dynamic` in box options.

I'll leave this here as a curiosity for those who want to mess about with boxes and make their lives more difficult.

#### Original

So these operations change the box form of the expression, and with anything typeset like this we'll have to do a bit of gymnastics to the the proper result (I think).

Here's a way to do it. I make no promises this is the best way, but it is *a* way:

```
DynamicModule[{
  g = PolyhedronData@"Spikey",
  update
  },
 Column@{
   Dynamic[
    update;
    With[{b = EvaluationBox[]},
     Cases[
      NotebookRead@
       DeleteCases[
        FrontEndExecute@
         FrontEnd`ObjectChildren@
          ParentBox@b,
        b
        ],
      r : ((ViewPoint | ViewAngle | ViewCenter) -> _) :> r,
      \[Infinity]
      ]
     ],
    TrackedSymbols :> {update}
    ],
   EventHandler[
    g, {
     "MouseDragged" :> (update = RandomReal[])
     }
    ]
   }
 ]
```

You'll see that I'm using the front end packet `` FrontEnd`ObjectChildren `` to get the all of the child boxes in this `DynamicModuleBox` then deleting the dynamic box that started the call. I did this because I was originally pulling in the `Graphics3DBox`. I think it's worth leaving here because it gives a way to select a box other than the `ParentBox` or `EvaluationBox`.

I also use an `EventHandler` that forces an update in that expression whenever the mouse is dragged on the `Graphics3DBox`. I think there's no way around that one, outside of a clumsy pairing of `TrackedSymbols:>{}` and `UpdateInterval->.05(*e.g.*)`

Comment: This works but shows only `ViewPoint`. What is about `ViewAngle`, `ViewCenter`, `ViewVector` and `ViewMatrix`? Are they simply absent in the low-level box structure?

Comment: You only see `ViewAngle` and `ViewCenter` once you shift or scale. The others I just didn't check for. They might be there.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov following up on that previous comment, it seems they are not.