# How to obtain the ViewPoint

Tags: plotting

Normally, I used ViewPoint in the code in Plot3D. Most of the time, I will use mouse to rotate the 3D object to get a better view point. The problem is, when I find the best view point for me, is there any way to get the ViewPoint parameters for the rotated scene, such as {-1.25, 2.31, 1.8}, so I can repeat the plot or use it in the future?

Comment: Simply edit the output cell and wrap `Options[..., ViewPoint]` around the *already rotated output*. The graphics should be in the place of `...`.  `ViewVertical` may also change during rotating, as well as some other parameters.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

One way is to set a symbol equal to the initial default viewpoint.

```
v = Options[Plot3D, ViewPoint][[1, 2]]

(* {1.3, -2.4, 2.} *)
```

Use that symbol dynamically in the plot. Monitor the dynamic value of `v` and note the value when the rotated plot is pleasing to you:

```
Plot3D[
 Sin[x + y^2],
 {x, -3, 3},
 {y, -2, 2},
 ViewPoint -> Dynamic[v]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Dynamic[v]

 (* {2, -0.9, 2.5} *)
```

Answer (score 23):

Here is how you can extract the ViewPoint family options from a graphic after interaction. Once you have the options, simply do a copy-paste them in the initial code :

[image]

Comment: [Duplicate of this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5380/5467), but maybe more attractive ? Should I delete or move my answer ?

Comment: This is a far more intuitive, and in my opinion more useful answer to the question.

Comment: good answer. Very easy to use.