# Changing the orientation of 3D plots

Tags: graphics3d

I have a small question. Suppose I make a 3D plot using the command:

```
Plot3D[{Exp[x] + Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

This generates the following graph:

[image]

Now, what if I wish to rotate the graph and make ensure that it's orientation seems presentable enough to include in a paper. Let me give you an example based on the 3D plot that I wish to use. Here's the default 3D plot:

[image]

Clearly, the by default orientation is a mess. I rotated it by hand to the following orientation:

[image]

The output seems much better. I now embed this graph in a PDF. Here's a snippet:

[image]

The graph in question is labelled (b). Compared to the graph labelled (d), which is in the default orientation, graph (b) takes up a lot more space and is awkwardly positioned (though all this isn't clear from the snippet).

My question is, are there commands one can use to deftly manipulate the orientation of 3D plots while ensure I get the best possible output to embed in a PDF?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. You are asking how to rotate a 3d plot, but you clearly did it to get the graph in (b), so you know how to do it. Cannot you just rotate the plot until you get the orientation you want, and then export the rotated version?

Comment: You really should look at the `View*` options. See e.g. [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5375).

Comment: If you want to understand how works the View options have a look at http://12000.org/my_notes/faq/mma_notes/MMA.htm#x1-6900051
question 100

Comment: @cyrille.piatecki the link doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

There are several options for manipulating the orientation of a 3D plot, but I know of no automatic way to orient a plot optimally.

The options you should familiarize yourself with are the following:

- [ViewPoint](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ViewPoint.html) and [ViewCenter](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ViewCenter.html) (or [ViewVector](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ViewVector.html) alone)
- [ViewVertical](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ViewVertical.html)
- [ViewAngle](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ViewAngle.html)
- [ViewRange](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ViewRange.html)

Or alternately (arguably, more advanced):

- [ViewMatrix](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ViewMatrix.html)

Although there is no simple way to tell Mathematica to auto-orient your plots, a trick that I find very useful is to orient the plot manually by dragging camera after it is plotted, then copying the rotated graphic. You can then type, for example,  `ViewPoint /. AbsoluteOptions[`<paste>`]` into an input cell and evaluate it to see the setting for `ViewPoint` in the current rotation. I frequently use this to figure out what orientation is best for a particular 3D plot.