# How to harvest graphics orientation

Tags: graphics, graphics3d

A common problem for me is finding the right perspective for 3D graphics.

This example accepts the default viewpoint and produce this:
[image: default]

Using the mouse, the image is manipulated to something like this:
[image: modified]

How do I harvest the perspective information so that it can be added to the graphic? My goal is to avoid having to manual adjustments across many files and to automate my process. This precludes using "Save graphics as...".

And for extra credit, how to get rid of white space? Trim Bounding Box produces this unsatisfactory result.

[image: headless]

Comment: I typically make a `Manipulate` and adjust the three parameters to find the best Viewpoint.

Comment: @David G. Stork: Are there other parameters, like distance?

Comment: Distance is derived from the three coordinates:  `{1,1,1}` and `{10,10,10}` are from the same direction, but different distances.

Comment: @David G. Stork: Can I interrogate to get the settings from the Manipulate sliders?

Comment: ... and simply click on the teeny + signs at the right of each slider to read their values.  `Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5], Sphere[], Red, Thickness[0.02], 
   Line[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}]},
  ViewPoint -> {x, y, z}], {{x, 1}, -5, 5}, {{y, 1}, -5, 
  5}, {{z, 1}, -5, 5 }]`

Comment: @David G. Stork: Ah yes. Please consider promoting this to an answer.

Comment: See this previous question: [Extract current viewing parameters from a 3D view?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5375/484)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[
 {Opacity[0.5], Sphere[], 
 Red, Thickness[0.02], Line[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}]},
  ViewPoint -> {x, y, z}], 
  {{x, 1}, -5, 5, Appearance -> "Open"}, 
  {{y, 1}, -5, 5, Appearance -> "Open"}, 
  {{z, 1}, -5, 5, Appearance -> "Open"}]
```

or `Appearance -> "Labeled"`

or...

if you want to copy the viewpoint, go to the teeny + at the upper-right corner of the Manipulate panel and select `PasteSnapshot`, which will paste the values of the parameters.

Comment: A very nice compliment to the answers in helpful link by @Rahul.