# Something like ViewPoint Selector

Tags: graphics3d

I find out, unintentionally, that in version 5.0 of the Mathematica software there was a dialog called `ViewPoint Selector`.

[image]

Is there anything similar in this regard that presents a dialog box for this?

I wish the outputs can be used in some way in the Graphics3D function through the context menu.

Comment: I have seen in some answers that it is possible using a line of code, but without any graphic visualization. I thought of something like what's in the picture. But I did not want to use `Manipulate` because my desktop hangs when I use this function.

Comment: Just a note, it comes from times where 3d graphics were not interactive. Now you can rotate/zoom/pan graphics 3d. Is there any specific use case for this?

Comment: To enter the desired values in ViewPoint. Ex: `ViewPoint -> {0, -2, 0}`

Comment: You can pass `ViewPoint` as an option to your `Graphics3D`. Alternatively you can use a `Dynamic` value for it.

Comment: Two [related](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5375) [questions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3528).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example illustrating a `Dynamic` version of [`ViewPoint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ViewPoint.html) with sliders, etc.

```
Grid[
  {
   {
    Panel[
     Graphics3D[
      First@PolyhedronData["Spikey"],
      Axes -> True,
      AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0},
      ViewPoint ->
       Dynamic[
        Replace[{x, y, z},
         Except[{__?NumericQ}] -> {1.3`, -2.4`, 2.`}
         ],
        {x, y, z} = #; &
        ],
      SphericalRegion -> True
      ],
     Background -> White
     ],
    VerticalSlider[Dynamic[z], {-5, 5}]
    },
   {Slider2D[Dynamic[{x, y}], {-5, 5}], SpanFromLeft}
   }
  ] // Panel
```

[image: dynamic view point]

There's a [`Slider2D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slider2D.html) for `{x,y}` and a [`VerticalSlider`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VerticalSlider.html) for `z`.

Plus you can interact the the graphic in the standard way.

Really this is just an impoverished form of [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3538/38205)

Comment: The one more thing needed is the output of the `{x,y,z}` to make the final image for `Export` or for future usage.

Comment: @Rom38 that's easy enough to get, since they're global variables. Or do you just want a monitor? Both are quite easy.

Comment: yes, it is easy but it is good to do to complete the answer about ViewPoint selector. Because you solution does not select anything than view :) which is available in MMA by default.