# How to extract the AspectRatio of a plot?

Tags: plotting, options

How do I extract the `AspectRatio` from a plot? (For example for the `PlotRange`, I can use `PlotRange[plot]`. The same does not work for the `AspectRatio`.)

---

I would be happy to extend this question into how to extract various options and attributes of plots. See for example also this question/answer [about extracting viewpoints](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5378/4502).

Comment: See the docs: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsAndPrograms.html#15639

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For example:

```
p1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, π}]
AbsoluteOptions[p1, AspectRatio]
```

> {AspectRatio -> 0.618034}

If this number looks familiar, it is because the default `AspectRatio` is  `1/GoldenRatio // N`.

Comment: ctrl-shift-e converts any graphic into its raw expression where you can look up a wide range of values, copy them, use them in options, etc.