# Plotting implicitly-defined space curves

Tags: plotting

It is known that space curves can either be defined parametrically,

$$\begin{align*}x&=f(t)\\y&=g(t)\\z&=h(t)\end{align*}$$

or as the intersection of two surfaces,

$$\begin{align*}F(x,y,z)&=0\\G(x,y,z)&=0\end{align*}$$

Curves represented parametrically can of course be plotted in *Mathematica* using `ParametricPlot3D[]`. Though implicitly-defined plane curves can be plotted with `ContourPlot[]`, and implicitly-defined surfaces can be plotted with `ContourPlot3D[]`, no facilities exist for plotting space curves like the intersection of the torus $(x^2+y^2+z^2+8)^2=36(x^2+y^2)$ and the cylinder $y^2+(z-2)^2=4$:

[image: torus-cylinder intersection]

Sometimes, one might be lucky and manage to find a parametrization for the intersection of two algebraic surfaces, but these situations are few and far between, especially if the two surfaces are of sufficiently high degree. The situation is worse if at least one of the surfaces is transcendental.

> How might one write a routine that plots space curves defined as the intersection of two implicitly-defined surfaces?

It would be preferable if the routine returns only `Line[]` objects representing the space curve. A routine that handles only algebraic surfaces would be an acceptable answer, but it would be nice if your routine can handle transcendental surfaces as well. A bonus feature for the routine might be the ability to determine if the two surfaces given do *not* have a space curve intersection, or intersect only at a single point, or other such degeneracies.

Comment: Finally, I'll be able to properly intersect the [columns with the roof](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5649/5)

Comment: @R.M, Funny, I thought getting the intersection of two parametrically-defined surfaces was an even tougher problem... so I decided not to ask for it in the question. :) That would be nice, though.

Comment: @J. M.♦ Can we extend the question a bit by considering intersection of two `BSpline` surfaces that has no explicit analytical form? This will be very effective for 3D modeling.

Comment: @Plato: that might be best done as a separate question... (that would be covered by the "two parametrically-defined surfaces" case, as `BSplineSurface[]` objects can be transformed into `BSplineFunction[]`s).

Comment: There is of course a followup to this: how does one get the equation (algebraic preferred, numerical acceptable) of those intersections? :)

Comment: @rcollyer Regarding the equation: if you accept a _differential equation_ then it's easy: take the cross product of the gradients of the implicit functions, and perhaps normalize it (call it `t[r]`, where r is a 3D point). Then the curve is described by `D[r[u],u] == t[r[u]]` for curve parameter `u`. This is because `t` must be tangent to both surfaces for all points `r` on the intersection curve. You "just" have to integrate that equation with a starting point `r0` on the intersection.

Comment: I was debating whether I should write an answer based on that, but it would be less efficient. If someone wants to try it anyway, you could perhaps directly use the [field line plotter in this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/769/245).

Comment: @Jens if comment upvotes counted ... the term "just" made me laugh. :)

Comment: In line with other functions (Solve, Reduce,...) it would be nice to go: ContourPlot3D[ (x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 8)^2 - 36 (x^2 + y^2) && y^2 + (z - 2)^2 - 4,{x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, {z, -2, 2}] (I don't know how to put a comment in..)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

I take zero credit for this. It is a method I learned from Maxim Rytin.

```
ContourPlot3D[{(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 8)^2 - 36 (x^2 + y^2), 
  y^2 + (z - 2)^2 - 4}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, {z, -2, 2}, 
 Contours -> {0}, ContourStyle -> Opacity[0], Mesh -> None, 
 BoundaryStyle -> {1 -> None, 2 -> None, {1, 2} -> {{Green, Tube[.03]}}}, 
 Boxed -> False]
```

[image: torus-cylinder intersection]

Comment: +1 Magical ;-) `{1,2}->Green` means intersection (boundary) between surface 1 and 2 will be green. Here is a minimal set of options to make it work: **ContourPlot3D[{(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 8)^2 - 36 (x^2 + y^2), y^2 + (z - 2)^2 - 4}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, {z, -2, 2}, ContourStyle -> None, Mesh -> None, BoundaryStyle -> {1 -> None, 2 -> None, {1, 2} -> Green}]**

Comment: Nice! I find it interesting, though, that the docs do not say that the `Filling` format specification can be applied to `BoundaryStyle`. Very useful.

Comment: I'll just note that if you take a look at the `InputForm[]` of the output of Daniel's version, the `Polygon[]` objects representing the isosurfaces are still there, just transparent. One could of course do something like `ContourPlot3D[{(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 8)^2 - 36 (x^2 + y^2), y^2 + (z - 2)^2 - 4}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, {z, -2, 2}, BoundaryStyle -> {1 -> None, 2 -> None, {1, 2} -> {}}, ContourStyle -> None, Mesh -> None]` (as Vitaliy comments) if one just wants the curves themselves. So many *unused* points, though...

Comment: @J. M. Thanks for the updates. I seem to be getting an awful lot of upvotes for code that was never of my own devising, and not notably better (that I can tell) than that in the other response. Embarrassed am I.

Comment: As rightly you should be keeping all the geometric goodies to yourself. There should be a [tag:spelunking] tag…

Answer (score 40):

This is admittedly a hack, and does not work as well with `PlotPoints` / `MaxRecursion` as a dedicated function would (you will notice that I needed to increase `PlotPoints` for a good result), but it's a good way to make a quick and dirty plot:

```
ContourPlot3D[(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 8)^2 == 36 (x^2 + y^2), 
   {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, {z, -2, 2}, 
   MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z}, y^2 + (z - 2)^2 - 4]}, 
   Mesh -> {{0}}, 
   ContourStyle -> None,
   PlotPoints -> 30, BoxRatios -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

**Addendum**

Per @whuber's comment below, the same thing can be achieved using `RegionFunction`:

```
ContourPlot3D[(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 8)^2 == 36 (x^2 + y^2), 
 {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, {z, -2, 2}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, y^2 + (z - 2)^2 < 4], 
 ContourStyle -> None, Mesh -> None, BoxRatios -> Automatic]
```

The style can be adjusted using `BoundaryStyle`.

I believe that this will give good quality results even without increasing `PlotPoints`, but I'll need to do some more testing before I can be certain about that...

Comment: What made this problem hard back in the days of old *Mathematica* was that the version of `ContourPlot3D[]` available in the standard packages didn't have the `MeshFunctions` option, and thus it took a bit of labor to look at which polygons were intersecting. This is nice, even if it is quick-and-dirty. :)

Comment: +1 With suitable graphics settings, the `RegionFunction` option will accomplish something similar.

Comment: @J.M. I think Mathematica's plotting framework is really powerful, and it uses adaptive sampling at every stage.  I am not sure if mesh lines are computed with a higher resolution than the surface or not, but the system definitely has the capability to do this for the intersection of two surfaces: it does it when computing exclusions.  Try e.g. `Plot3D[Boole[x^2 + y^2 < 1], {x, -1.1, 1.1}, {y, -1.1, 1.1}]` and note how smooth and sharp the circle boundary is.  If you turn off exclusions (`Exclusions -> None`), it'll be a lot more jagged.

Comment: @whuber And you just answered the question that didn't fit in the comment I wrote above!  `RegionFunction` will sample the intersection curve very smoothly, similarly to how `Exclusions` are computed! (The `Plot` example above.)  This should give a better result than `MeshFunctions`, I think, but I'd need to test it.

Comment: +1. With `Mesh -> All, PlotStyle -> None, PlotPoints -> 3` you'll see the possibly pre-generated smooth circle boundary.

Comment: (Expectedly) $ y^2 + (z - 2)^2 > 4 $ for second function shows main torus.

Answer (score 35):

### Introduction

I worked up my solution and then saw that Jens had suggested this approach in a comment.  Well, here's my approach.  It is fairly general.  I made no attempt to determine how many connected components there are and finding parametrizations of each one.

1. Find a point on the intersection.  This could be a difficult step, depending on how much is known about the surfaces.

   - A known point.
   - Use `Solve` or `NSolve`, if they work.  One might be able to solve one variable in terms of the others or use a hyperplane that intersects the intersection of the surfaces.
   - Use root-finding, provided a feasible starting point is known.  I'll give a pseudo-Newton's Method function for hunting down an intersection point below.
2. Integrate the normalized cross product of the gradients of the function `{f, g}` that define the surfaces `{f == 0, g == 0}`.  Since the cross product is perpendicular to both gradients of `f` and `g`, it will be tangent to the intersection curve.  Using the normalized vector yields a unit-speed parametrization.  This is fairly easy with `NDSolve`.

   - Determining the limits of integration usually needs some user-input.
   - We can get a periodic interpolation of closed curves.

### Utility functions

**`findPoint[{f, g}, {{x, y, z}, {x0, y0, z0}}]`** - finds a point on the intersection of `{f == 0, g == 0}`, starting at  `{x0, y0, z0}`.  It uses Newton-Method-like step **`pseudonewton`**.

**`periodicEvent[v, v0, p0]`** - stops integration when the solution has completed a loop, using the condition `v == v0` to trigger the event; `p0` should be the initial point and `v0` should be the corresponding coordinate.

**`findIntersection3D[{f, g}, {{x, y, z}, {x0, y0, z0}}, {t, t1, t2}]`** - finds a parametrization of the intersection of `{F == 0, g == 0}` near the point `{x0, y0, z0}`.

**`periodicReinterpolation[if]`** - converts the `InterpolatingFunction` `if` to a periodic one.  Just something "extra"; it plays no crucial role.

**`showall[{f, g}, sol]`** - another "extra," which shows the plots of `f == 0`, `g == 0`, and the intersection parametrized by `sol`.

### Examples

The three examples below were each shown with `showall[{f, g}, sol]`.

*OP's example.* Converting to a periodic interpolation is not necessary; it is done merely to show it can be done.

```
{f, g} = {(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 8)^2 - 36 (x^2 + y^2), y^2 + (z - 2)^2 - 4};
sol = findIntersection3D[{f, g}, {{x, y, z}, #}, {t, 0, 100}, 
      "EventFunctions" -> {periodicEvent[y[t], #[[2]], #] &}] & /@
   {{-4, 0, 0}, {4, 0, 0}} /. if_InterpolatingFunction :> periodicReinterpolation[if];
```

*Helix.*  OK, paramterization by hand is easy, but I've always liked this construction of the helix as the intersection of two corrugated sheets.  I used `Solve` to find the point of intersection at the bottom of the plot range (`z == -4`).  It's actually shorter to write it out explicitly, but in principle

```
{f, g} = {x - Cos[2 z], y - Sin[2 z]};
sol = findIntersection3D[{f, g}, {{x, y, z}, 
     {x, y, z} /. First@Solve[{z == -4, {x - Cos[2 z], y - Sin[2 z]} == {0, 0}}},
   {t, 0, 100}, 
   "EventFunctions" -> {WhenEvent[z[t] == 4, "StopIntegration"] &}];
```

*A somewhat random transcendental surface and sphere.*

```
{f, g} = {x + Sin[y] + Cos[2 z], x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 9};
sol = findIntersection3D[{f, g}, {{x, y, z}, {0, 0, 2}}, {t, 0, 100}, 
   "EventFunctions" -> {periodicEvent[x[t], First[#], #] &}];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Code

**Root-finding.**  I have not seen Newton's Method used on an underdetermined system, but that's basically that `findPoint` does.  In the main function, `findPoint` starts the search at the point `{x0, y0, z0}` passed to `findIntersection3D`.

```
ClearAll[findPoint, pseudonewton, periodicEvent, findIntersection3D, 
  periodicReinterpolation, showall];

pseudonewton[f_List, {x_, y_, z_}] := pseudonewton[f, D[f, {{x, y, z}}], {x, y, z}]; 
pseudonewton[f_List, df_?MatrixQ, {x_, y_, z_}] := 
 With[{df0 = df /. Thread[{x, y, z} -> #], f0 = f /. Thread[{x, y, z} -> #]},
   # - PseudoInverse[df0].f0] &; 
findPoint[f_List, {{x_, y_, z_}, {x0_, y0_, z0_}}] := 
 NestWhile[pseudonewton[f, D[f, {{x, y, z}}], {x, y, z}], {x0, y0, z0}, 
  Norm[f /. Thread[{x, y, z} -> #]] > 1*^-15 &, 2, 100];
```

**Constructing the intersection.** Although one specifies an interval `{t, t1, t2}` in calling `findIntersection3D` (see above, Utility functions), events are probably the easiest way to control the interval of integration.  The option `"EventFunctions" -> list` takes a list of functions whose input is the starting point found by `findPoint`.  They should output an `WhenEvent` expression.  The function `periodicEvent` returns a event function that detects when the path computed by `NDSolve` returns to its starting position.  When the variable `v` equals the number `v0` and the point `{x[t], y[t], z[t]}`, is close to the starting point `p0`, integration stops; the number `v0` should be the corresponding coordinate of `p0`.  In certain cases, `periodicEvent` might need tweaking.  The condition that the distance be within `0.1` is coordinated with the option `MaxStepSize -> 0.1` in `NDSolve`.  If the step size is greater, the event may be missed.  It can also happen that the starting point `p0` is at an extreme value of the variable `v` that `periodicEvent` tracks.  Either change the variable or pass a `periodicEvent` for two or three variables.

```
periodicEvent[v_, v0_, p0_] := 
  WhenEvent[v == v0 && Norm[{x[t], y[t], z[t]} - p0] < 0.1, "StopIntegration"];

Options[findIntersection3D] = Join[{"EventFunctions" -> {}}, Options[NDSolve]];
findIntersection3D[funcs : {_, _}, {{x_, y_, z_}, {x0_, y0_, z0_}}, {t_, t1_, t2_},
   opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
  Module[{vel, eqn, ics, invariants},
   vel = Cross @@ D[funcs, {{x, y, z}}] // Normalize;
   eqn = {x'[t], y'[t], z'[t]} == (vel /. {v : x | y | z :> v[t]}); 
   ics = findPoint[funcs, {{x, y, z}, N@{x0, y0, z0}}];
   invariants = funcs /. {v : x | y | z :> v[t]};
   First@NDSolve[{
      eqn,
      {x[0], y[0], z[0]} == ics,
      Through[OptionValue["EventFunctions"][ics]]},
     {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 100},
     FilterRules[{opts}, Options[NDSolve]],
     MaxStepSize -> 0.1,
     Method -> {"Projection", "Invariants" -> invariants}]
   ];
```

**Extras.**

```
showall[{f_, g_}, sol_] := Show[
   ContourPlot3D[{f == 0, g == 0}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, {z, -4, 4},
     ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.5], Mesh -> None],
   ParametricPlot3D[{x[t], y[t], z[t]} /. sol // Evaluate, 
    Evaluate@Join[{t}, Flatten[x["Domain"] /. First@sol]], 
    PlotStyle -> Black]
   ];

periodicReinterpolation[if_InterpolatingFunction] := 
  Module[{coords = First@if["Coordinates"], values = if["ValuesOnGrid"]},
   If[Chop@First@Differences[if /@ Flatten[if["Domain"]]] != 0,
    Print["Warning: The endpoints are significantly different."]];
   values[[-1]] = values[[1]];
   Interpolation[Transpose@{coords, values}]
   ];
```

Comment: Looks great. I'll test this when I have *Mathematica* access again.

Comment: Finally tried it out (after making a few modifications to use `Method -> "EventLocator"` instead); it works nicely for nonsingular curves. Two things: why not use `LeastSquares[]` for `pseudonewton[]`; and, have you already seen [this](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2687702)?

Comment: @J.M. I might have forgotten or not know about `LeastSquares`; or because I think of Newton's method in terms of "dividing by the derivative" and `PseudoInverse` expresses that idea. Testing `LeastSquares`, it seems slightly slower but that's hardly important here.  I probably saw the article in 1998, but I didn't remember it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

After version 10, using mesh-based geometric regions, it's become simpler

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 8)^2 == 36 (x^2 + y^2) && 
    y^2 + (z - 2)^2 == 4, {x, y, z}];
disReg = DiscretizeRegion[reg]
Graphics3D[{Red, MeshPrimitives[disReg, 1]}]
```

[image]