# Solve trigonometric equation

Tags: equation-solving, functions, trigonometry

I'm looking for a solution (graphic, numeric or analytic) for a function of the form:

$$a^2\tanh(x)=\tan(ax),\quad a ≥ 1,\ x > 0$$

preferably using *Mathematica*. Any advice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Numerically (using `FindRoot` as you do):

```
fn[x_, a_] := a^2*Tanh[x] - Tan[a*x]
xmax = 5;
firstSol[a_] := First@Select[N@Sort@DeleteDuplicates@Rationalize[Quiet@Chop@
     FindRoot[fn[x, a] == 0, {x, Range[0.1, xmax, 0.1]}][[1, 2]],10^-10], # >= .1 &]
```

Then you can either `Manipulate` or `Table`:

```
Manipulate[Column[{"First Solution = " <> ToString@firstSol[a],Plot[fn[x, a], {x, 0, 5},
  ImageSize -> 500,Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Point[{firstSol[a], 0}]}]},
  Alignment -> Center], {a, 1, 5, 1}]
```

[image: Manipulate&FindRoot]

Or:

```
Table[firstSol@a, {a, 1, 5}]
```

> {3.9266, 0.555377, 0.435336, 0.346333, 0.285585}

Although `xmax` and the domain in which you want to find solutions has to be chose carefully. In your function `a` has a big influence.

Comment: Thanks, I'm only interested in the first, non-trivial solution. Öskå, one last question: why doesn't it work to nest your solution into a 'while loop' for `a` and get all results at once? Any advice on how to do so?

Answer (score 10):

We will show:

- How to reproduce and improve the WolframAlpha plot, and what it shows about the problem
- How to use `NDSolve` to approximate the function
- How to use `FindRoot` to improve an `NDSolve` solution (necessary for the first root)
- How to define `x` as a function of `a`, for `a >= 0`

Here is a plot some of the solutions. (We omit the trivial solution `x[a_] := 0`, as in the OP.)

[image: Plot of several solution curves]

### WolframAlpha

WolframAlpha makes a very rough picture, which is roughly equivalent to the first contour plot.  We can improve upon this by excluding the discontinuities where `Cos[a * x] == 0` or `a * x == (2 k + 1) π/2`; further, we can find the missing branches in the region of interest (`a >= 1`, `x > 0`) by increasing the number of `PlotPoints`.

```
Block[{a1, a2, x1, x2},
 {a1, a2} = {-4.492122341961456`, 4.186102420126525`};
 {x1, x2} = {-5.314327054433177`, 5.314327054433177`};
 GraphicsRow[
  {ContourPlot[a^2*Tanh[x] - Tan[a*x] == 0, {a, a1, a2}, {x, x1, x2},
    PlotLabel -> "WolframAlpha"],
   ContourPlot[a^2*Tanh[x] - Tan[a*x] == 0, {a, a1, a2}, {x, x1, x2},
    Exclusions -> Cos[a*x] == 0, 
    PlotLabel -> "Excluding discontinuties"],
   ContourPlot[{a^2*Tanh[x] == Tan[a*x]}, {a, 1, 4}, {x, 0, 4},
    PlotPoints -> 50, Exclusions -> Cos[a*x] == 0, 
    PlotLabel -> "Region of interest"]},
  ImageSize -> 600]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

However, there will be limit to how far one can increase the quality of the plot, and not just because of the time it takes.  The reason is that the regions in which the function is negative grow vanishingly thin as `a` increases, making it unlikely for `ContourPlot` to find points where the function changes sign.  This can be seen in both plots below.  Indeed, the plot on the right shows that an inflection in the graph develops, which can confuse `FindRoot`, if it is not supplied with good initial points.  This makes using `Table` and `FindRoot` to create an `Interpolation` difficult.  It will be easier to use `NDSolve`.  (Note that the sought-after solutions are where green switches to red; the white parts are the excluded discontinuities.)

```
Row[{
  ContourPlot[a^2*Tanh[x] - Tan[a*x], {a, 0, 4}, {x, 0, 4}, 
   Contours -> {0}, Exclusions -> Cos[a*x] == 0, 
   ColorFunction -> "RedGreenSplit", 
   ContourStyle -> {Thickness[Medium], Blue}, ImageSize -> 225], " ",
  Plot3D[a^2*Tanh[x] - Tan[a*x], {a, 0, 4}, {x, 0, 4}, 
   PlotPoints -> 100, Exclusions -> Cos[a*x] == 0, 
   MeshFunctions -> {Function[{a, x, f}, f]}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
   MeshStyle -> {Thick, Blue}, MeshShading -> (ColorData["RedGreenSplit"] /@ {0, 1}), 
   PlotRange -> {-10, 20}, ImageSize -> 350, ViewPoint -> {10, -1, 1}]
  }]
```

[image: Contour, surface plot]

### Solving for the curve using NDSolve

There are two things I long for (which means I do not think they are available as built-in features): 1) A function that returns an interpolation of a branch of the solution to an equation, and 2) a way to pass `NDSolve` an extra error measure to be minimized.

One can set up a differential equation for an integral curve on a surface from the gradient of its equation.  In this case, we are seeking a level set, so our differential equation results from differentiating the equation, treating `x` and as function `a` (or vice versa as desired):

```
D[a^2 * Tanh[x[a]] - Tan[a * x[a]], a] == 0
```

To get a level curve we feed `NDSolve` an initial point on it, which we can find with `FindRoot`.  There is a solution `x[a]` below each discontinuity `Cos[a * x] == 0`. Thus at `a == 1`, the discontinuity is at `x == (2 k + 1) π/2`.  For the sake of an example, we'll choose `x == 3 π/2` and initial value `x0` just below it.

```
FindRoot[a^2*Tanh[x0] - Tan[a*x0] /. a -> 1, {x0, 3 π/2 - 0.1}]
  (* {x0 -> 3.9266} *)

NDSolveValue[
  {D[a^2*Tanh[x[a]] - Tan[a*x[a]], a] == 0, 
   x[1] == (x0 /. FindRoot[a^2*Tanh[x0] - Tan[a*x0] /. a -> 1, {x0, 3 π/2 - 0.1}])}, 
  x, {a, 1, 10}];
Plot[%[a], {a, 1, 10}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True]
```

[image: Plot of first 3π/2 solution]

### Using FindRoot to correct the first solution

The above approach works for the other branches except the one below `a * x == π/2`.  The differential equation is indeterminate at `a = 1`, `x = 0`, so we will start by fudging a little and then correct the errors.  For the initial value for `x[1]`, we find a root for a nearby `a` with `x < π/2/a`.  Note the value of this solution at `a = 1` is far from the correct value `0`.

```
FindRoot[a^2*Tanh[x0] - Tan[a*x0] /. a -> 1.1, {x0, π/2/1.1 - 0.1}]
  (* {x0 -> 0.358323} *)

sol0 = NDSolveValue[
   {D[a^2*Tanh[x[a]] - Tan[a*x[a]], a] == 0, 
    x[1] == (x0 /. FindRoot[a^2*Tanh[x0] - Tan[a*x0] /. a -> 1.1, {x0, π/2/1.1 - 0.1}])},
   x, {a, 1, 10}];
sol0[1]
Plot[sol0[a], {a, 1, 10}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True]

  (* 0.358323 *)
```

[image: Plot of solution nearest the x axis]

This can be corrected with `FindRoot`.
The output of `NDSolve` is an `InterpolatingFunction` (say, `ifn`) that has for a certain grid of domain values (accessed via `ifn["Grid"]`), corresponding values of the solution (accessed via `ifn["ValuesOnGrid"]`).  We can improve the solution by improving the values on the grid.

```
sol0Imp = Interpolation @ Transpose @ 
     {sol0["Grid"], 
      MapThread[
       x0 /. FindRoot[a^2*Tanh[x0] - Tan[a*x0] /. a -> #1, {x0, #2}] &,
       {First /@ sol0["Grid"], sol0["ValuesOnGrid"]}]};
sol0Imp[1]
Plot[sol0Imp[a], {a, 1, 10}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True]
  (* 1.2661*10^-8 *)
```

[image: More accurate plot of solution nearest the x axis]

The other branches normally do not need this improvement.  `NDSolve` does a good job approximating them.

### Defining the functions

We will label the branches `k = 0, 1, 2, ...`, where `k` corresponds to the branch below `a * x == (2k + 1) π/2`.  Here I randomly chose the domain `1 <= a <= 10`.  One can change it, or as shown below, have the domain automatically extended.  The result of `NDSolve` is [memoized](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/memoization?sort=votes), so that it is a one-time cost for each `k`.

```
xfn[0] := xfn[0] = Module[{sol, a, a0 = 1.1, x, x0},
    sol = NDSolveValue[
       {D[a^2*Tanh[x[a]] - Tan[a*x[a]], a] == 0, 
        x[1] == (x0 /. FindRoot[a^2 * Tanh[x0] - Tan[a * x0] /. a -> a0,
                                {x0, π/2/a0 - 0.1}])},
       x, {a, 1, 10}];
    Interpolation @ Transpose @
      {sol["Grid"], 
       MapThread[
        x0 /. FindRoot[a^2 * Tanh[x0] - Tan[a * x0] /. a -> #1, {x0, #2}] &,
        {First /@ sol["Grid"], sol["ValuesOnGrid"]}]}
    ];
xfn[k_] := xfn[k] = Block[{a, x, x0},
   NDSolveValue[
     {D[a^2 * Tanh[x[a]] - Tan[a*x[a]], a] == 0, 
      x[1] == (x0 /. FindRoot[a^2 * Tanh[x0] - Tan[a * x0] /. a -> 1,
                              {x0, (2k + 1) π/2 - 0.1}])},
     x, {a, 1, 10}]
   ]
```

The output of the plot is shown above.  One can see that this procedure is reasonably fast.  The second plot if faster because of memoization, and the difference shows the time it takes to compute the 20 solutions.

```
Plot[Evaluate@Table[xfn[k][a], {k, 0, 19}], {a, 1, 8},
   Axes -> False, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {0, 8}, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[0.02], 
   AspectRatio -> 1]; // Timing
  (* {0.339130, Null} *)

Plot[Evaluate@Table[xfn[k][a], {k, 0, 19}], {a, 1, 8},
   Axes -> False, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {0, 8}, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[0.02], 
   AspectRatio -> 1]; // Timing
 (* {0.048151, Null} *)
```

#### Automatically extending the domain

Here is a way to extend the domain.  We use `NDSolve` to fill in the next segment of the domain, restarting it from where it left off, and stitch the old and new interpolations together.  The next segment extends from the old endpoint to `10.` times that endpoint (`1.`, `10.`, `100.`, etc.).  The new interpolation replaces the old one in `xfn0[k]`.  There is a small overhead in checking that the argument `a` to `xfn[k]` is in the currently defined domain (conveniently stored in the `InterpoltingFunction` `xfn0[k]`), which does not noticeably affect the timing of the plot above.

```
ClearAll[xfn, xfn0]; (* redefine xfn *)
xfn0[k_]["Domain"] := {{1., 1.}};
xfn0[k_]["Grid"] := {};
xfn0[k_]["ValuesOnGrid"] := {};
xfn0[0, {1., 10.}] := xfn0[0] = Module[{sol, a, a0 = 1.1, x, x0},
    sol = NDSolveValue[
           {D[a^2*Tanh[x[a]] - Tan[a*x[a]], a] == 0, 
            x[1] == (x0 /. FindRoot[a^2 * Tanh[x0] - Tan[a * x0] /. a -> a0,
                                    {x0, π/2/a0 - 0.1}])},
           x, {a, 1, 10}];
    Interpolation @ Transpose @
      {sol["Grid"], 
       MapThread[
        x0 /. FindRoot[a^2 * Tanh[x0] - Tan[a * x0] /. a -> #1, {x0, #2}] &,
        {First /@ sol["Grid"], sol["ValuesOnGrid"]}]}
    ];
xfn0[k_, {a1_, a2_}] := xfn0[k] = Module[{sol, a, x, x0, x1},
    If[xfn0[k]["Domain"][[1, 2]] == 1.,

      x1 = x0 /. FindRoot[a^2*Tanh[x0] - Tan[a*x0] /. a -> 1., {x0, (2 k + 1) π/2 - 0.1}];
      xfn0[k]["Grid"] = {{1.}};
      xfn0[k]["ValuesOnGrid"] = {x1},

      x1 = Last@xfn0[k]["ValuesOnGrid"]
     ];
    sol = NDSolveValue[{D[a^2*Tanh[x[a]] - Tan[a*x[a]], a] == 0, x[a1] == x1},
                       x, {a, a1, a2}];
    Interpolation @ Transpose @
      {Join[xfn0[k]["Grid"], Rest@sol["Grid"]], 
       Join[xfn0[k]["ValuesOnGrid"], Rest@sol["ValuesOnGrid"]]}
    ];
xfn[k_][a_] /; 1 <= a < xfn0[k]["Domain"][[1, 2]] := xfn0[k][a];
xfn[k_][a_?NumericQ] := (xfn0[k, xfn0[k]["Domain"][[1, -1]] {1., 10.}]; xfn[k][a]);

xfn[0][1]
  (* 1.2661*10^-8 *)

xfn[0][1132]
  (* 0.00138714 *)
```

Comment: wow! what an epic and deep answer! (+1)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution that give the root in the kth segment  :

```
root[a_,k_] := FixedPoint[(k Pi + ArcTan[a^2 Tanh[#]])/a &, k Pi +1/2]

root[2.73, #] & /@ Range[0, 3]
```

> {0.465728, 1.67378, 2.82772, 3.97879}

**Edit**

Thanks to Öska's remarks, here is a more robust solution :

```
root[a_, k_] := 
 FixedPoint[(k Pi + ArcTan[a^2 Tanh[#]])/a &,
             k Pi + 0.5,   
             SameTest -> (Abs[#1 - #2] < 10^-8 &)
           ]
```

Comment: Great @andre, this does work and can also be used inside a loop. merci.

Comment: Strangly it only works (or it takes ages?) with Reals but not with Intergers. And also does not work if `a=1`. Any idea why?

Comment: @Öskå This is due to the fact that the expression in `FixedPoint[]` isn't numerical in these cases. I presume that `FixedPoint[]` apply a equality test on a litteral expression  which change continuously. The solution : `root[a_,k_] := FixedPoint[(k Pi + ArcTan[a^2 Tanh[#]])/a &, k Pi + 0.5]`

Comment: @Öskå Concerning the case a=1. , you can make it work by relaxing the equality test : `root[a_, k_] := 
 FixedPoint[(k Pi + ArcTan[a^2 Tanh[#]])/a &, k Pi + 0.5, 
  SameTest -> ( Abs[#1 - #2] < 10^-8 &)]`

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple way to eyeball things:

```
Manipulate[Plot[{a^2 Tanh[x], Tan[a x]}, {x, 0, Pi}], {a, 1, Pi}]
```

[image]

Comment: Cool. I wonder why/how wolfram alpha can solve it graphically and mathematica can't. I'm right now doing something similar by plotting a table of FindRoot[Tan[a*x] == a^2*Tanh[x], {x, 0.45}]