# How do I invert a function with two arguments?

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, inverse

I begin with a function defined by

```
c[u_, mH_]
```

I won't go into details because it comes from countless lines of partial differential equations, boundary conditions and perturbations. But suffice to say it is a rather complex function of two variables.

I have managed to plot the following:

```
LogLinearPlot[c[u, 135], {u, 100, 10^18}, PlotRange -> All]
```

That is to say, c(u) at a fixed value of mH.

However, my next step is to plot mH(u) for a fixed c (namely c=0). How do I invert this function in order to achieve this? I've tried

```
Reduce[c[u, mH] == 0, mH, Reals];

msol = NSolve[coup[u, mH] == 0, mH[u]];
```

etc... But nothing works. Any ideas? My knowledge of Mathematica is a bit rudimentary.

Comment: `ContourPlot[c[u, mH] == 0, {u, 100, 500}, {mH, 0, 100}]` (insert suitable limits).

Comment: By the way, is there any way to scale the quantities in your problem so that you don't have to plot all the way out to `10^18`? I could see that causing issues.

Comment: I used `NDSolve` [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/27984/4999) to integrate the derivative of the equation, to construct a numerical approximation to the solution.  I've done it several times on this site, as have others, but that's the one that showed up first in a search.