# Jumps in NDSolve results

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I need to compute using `NDSolve` routine, some function $F(x)$, having two possible values $F_1(x)$ and $F_2(x)$ depending on whether the argument exceeds some critical value $x>x_c$. The problem is that `NDSolve` routine return "jumping results" for the region $x>x_c$.

As an example of a problem assume following system (some simple forced pendulum with nonlinear frequncy shift, so-called "fold over" effect):

```
w00 = 7000;
G0 = 50;
Q = 14000;
hU = 0.6*G0;
w0 = w00 - x;

(* example NDSolve call with sample value for x -- see below for actual usage *)
Block[{x = 8000},
 NDSolve[
  {A'[t] + G0*A[t] + I*(w0+Q*Abs[A[t]]^2)*A[t] == I*hU, A[0] == 10^-6}, 
  A[t], {t, 0, tmax},
  MaxSteps -> Infinity, AccuracyGoal -> 50, MaxStepSize -> 0.01
  ];
 ]
```

I am interested in $|A(t)|^2$ dynamics depending on the parameter `x`.
Here $G0,Q,hU$ are some constants

Exact solution:

```
exact = ContourPlot[
  A == (hU^2/((G0)^2 + (w0 + Q*A)^2)),
  {t, 6000, 9000}, {A, 0, 0.2},
  PlotPoints -> 40, ContourStyle -> {Dashed, Thick},
  PlotRange -> All
]
```

Numerical solution:

```
Calc[x_] := Module[{
   w0 = 7000, G0 = 50, Q = 14000, At = 10^-6, tmax = 4,
   hU, w00, G1
  },

  hU = 0.6*G0;
  w00 = w0 - x + Q*Abs[A0[t]]^2;
  G1 = 1.0 G0;

  s2 = NDSolve[{
    A0'[t] + G0*A0[t] + I*w00*A0[t] == I*hU,
    A0[0] == 0.7 + 0.5 I
   }, A0[t], {t, 0, tmax}, 
   MaxSteps -> Infinity, AccuracyGoal -> 50, MaxStepSize -> 0.01
  ];

  {Abs[A0[t] /. s2 /. t -> tmax][[1]]}
]
Dynamic[z]
For[h1 = {}; z = 9000, z > 6000, z = z - 50,
 AppendTo[h1, {z, First@Calc[z]^2}];
]
numerical = ListPlot[h1, PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Thick]
```

Comparing both:

```
Show[exact, numerical]
```

[image: Comparing NDSolve and exact solutions]

Solid line – `NDSolve` solution, dashed line - exact solution

The result and number of jumps greatly depends on initial conditions:

```
A[0] == 0.7 + 0.5*I
```

[image]

```
A[0] == 10^-6
```

[image]

The problem is I want to divide the two "branches" of the function $F_1$ and $F_2$ and plot them independently. How can I do this using `NDSolve` and force it to go along the chosen branch and not "jump?"?

Comment: To closers: yes, this is an old, unanswered question. But (a) it is upvoted, (b) OP has been seen only 2 months ago, and (c) I cannot agree that it is at all unclear. Potentially it is too localized, but I'm not sure about that. I appreciate the help but this is not quite what I had in mind by closing old questions. I think the best thing to do is to bounty it--please leave a comment if you think it should still be closed.

Comment: I just evaluated the code and I ended up with lots of warnings, maybe it needs some cleaning up.

Comment: @RaymondGhaffarianShirazi thanks. I fixed the errors so that the OP's observations are reproducible now.

Comment: Thanks, I give it look, I suspect I faced a similar challenge and those sloped vertical lines where produced by plot command actually.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Judging from the definition of `Calc`, I think the 5th line of code in the first code block, `w0 = w00 - t`, was meant to be `w0 = w00 - x` as originally written; I think what's missing is an example value for `x`.  But that `NDSolve` in the first code block is superfluous. I will update the edit...

Comment: @MichaelE2 thanks, I think you are right. To be honest, I wasn't sure if there was any benefit to having that listed there as well as later on. I didn't delete it only because apparently OP thought it was relevant.

Answer (score 10):

*(Update: I forgot to copy some of the code)*

For values of `z = x` beyond the critical value (just below `z == 7500`), there are three real equilibria, two stable spirals and one (unstable) saddle.

```
eq[x_] := Module[{q = x},
   w0 = 7000;
   G0 = 50;
   Q = 14000;
   hU = 0.6*G0;
   w00 = w0 - q + Q*Abs[A0[t]]^2;
   At = 10^-6;
   G1 = 1.0 G0;
   tmax = 4;
   e1 = D[A0[t], t] + G0*A0[t] + I*w00*A0[t] == I*hU];

realeq[x_] := (* the real and imaginary parts in terms of A0[t] = u[t] + I v[t] *)
 ComplexExpand@
   Through[{Re, Im}[Subtract @@ eq[x] /. {A0 -> (u[#] + I v[#] &)}]] == {0, 0}

equil = NSolve[realeq[7575] /. {u'[t] -> 0, v'[t] -> 0}, {u[t], v[t]}, Reals]
(*
{{u[t] -> -0.163309,  v[t] -> 0.0483454},
 {u[t] ->  0.207442,  v[t] -> 0.0832793},
 {u[t] -> -0.0560372, v[t] -> 0.00528008}}
*)
```

Stability:

```
Det@D[First@realeq[7575] /. {u'[t] -> 0, v'[t] -> 0}, {{u[t], v[t]}}] /. equil
(*  {-106153., 192263., 237015.}  *)

StreamPlot[
 ComplexExpand@
  Through[{Re, Im}[
    A0'[t] /. First@Solve[eq[7575], A0'[t]] /. {A0[t] -> u + I v}]],
 {u, -0.3, 0.3}, {v, -0.3, 0.3}, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[Medium], Green, Point[{u[t], v[t]} /. equil]},
 StreamPoints -> Fine]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]
>   *Fig. 1. Phase plot with separatrices showing the basins of attraction.*

As `z` changes, the basins of attraction for each spiral point change, and as they move, the initial conditions changes which basin it lies in.

```
Calc[x_] := Module[{q = x},
   w0 = 7000;
   G0 = 50;
   Q = 14000;
   hU = 0.6*G0;
   w00 = w0 - q + Q*Abs[A0[t]]^2;
   At = 10^-6;
   G1 = 1.0 G0;
   tmax = 4;
   e1 = D[A0[t], t] + G0*A0[t] + I*w00*A0[t] == I*hU;
   s2 = NDSolve[{e1, A0[0] == (0.7 + 0.5 I) + 0*10^-6}, {A0}, {t, 0, 
      tmax}, MaxSteps -> Infinity, AccuracyGoal -> 50, 
     MaxStepSize -> 0.01];
   {Evaluate[Abs[A0[t] /. s2 /. t -> tmax]][[1]]}];

movie = Table[Calc[z];
   ParametricPlot[Through[{Re, Im}[A0[t] /. s2]], {t, 0, 4}, 
    Epilog -> {PointSize[Medium], Red, 
      Point[Through[{Re, Im}[A0[4] /. First@s2]]], Green, 
      Point[{u[t], v[t]} /. 
        NSolve[ComplexExpand@
           Through[{Re, Im}[
             Subtract @@ e1 /. {A0[t] -> u[t] + I v[t], A0'[t] -> 0}]] == {0, 0},
         {u[t], v[t]}, Reals]]},
    PlotRange -> 1, MaxRecursion -> 15,
    PlotLabel -> HoldForm["z"] == z],
   {z, 7550, 7650}];
```

[image]

To get a result like the one the OP wants, one would need to adjust the initial condition as a function of `z`.  But if, as it seems, the OP just wants to get a function representing the curve in the contour plot, one could use a different method, such as the ones I used here:

- [Getting an InterpolatingFunction from a ContourPlot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7944/getting-an-interpolatingfunction-from-a-contourplot/66582#66582)
- [How to find an approximate solution in a region when Solve or NSolve does not work?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/41871/how-to-find-an-approximate-solution-in-a-region-when-solve-or-nsolve-does-not-wo/64161#64161)