# Why is FindRoot failing to evaluate this function?

Tags: equation-solving, functions

I have a (somewhat long) script which runs cleanly until the very last stage.  Here, I'm using `FindRoot` to attempt to parameterize implicit curves in the zero set of a two variable function.  The `FindRoot` is giving me the familiar error

"is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table..."

and

"is not a list of numbers with dimensions..."

Now, I know using `?NumericQ` is a common solution here, and I think I've done that correctly below, but I'm still getting errors.  I'm hoping someone can perhaps parse through what I'm overlooking here:

`M = 1;
tau = (0.5) + (0.4)*I;
w1 = Pi/2;
w2 = Pi*(tau)/2;
inv = WeierstrassInvariants[{w1, w2}];
E2[t_] = 1 - 
   24*Sum[(n*Exp[2*Pi*I*(t)*n])/(1 - Exp[2*Pi*I*(t)*n]), {n, 1, 
      300}];
z[u_?NumericQ] = (I*
     M/2)*(WeierstrassZeta[u, inv] - ((1/3)*N[E2[tau], 50]*(u)));
WP[x_, y_] = WeierstrassP[w1*x + w2*y, inv];
L = -(1/3)*N[E2[tau], 50];
f[x_, y_] = Re[WP[x, y] - L];
g[x_, y_] = Im[WP[x, y] - L];
ContourPlot[{f[x, y] == 0, g[x, y] == 0}, {x, 0, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
V1 = Quiet[
   FindRoot[{f[x, y] == 0, g[x, y] == 0}, {x, 0.8}, {y, 0.5}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 50]];
V2 = Quiet[
   FindRoot[{f[x, y] == 0, g[x, y] == 0}, {x, 1.2}, {y, 1.5}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 50]];
V3 = Quiet[
   FindRoot[{f[x, y] == 0, g[x, y] == 0}, {x, 0.8}, {y, -1.5}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 50]];
V4 = Quiet[
   FindRoot[{f[x, y] == 0, g[x, y] == 0}, {x, 1.2}, {y, -0.5}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 50]];
A1 = x /. V1;
B1 = y /. V1;
A2 = x /. V2;
B2 = y /. V2;
A3 = x /. V3;
B3 = y /. V3;
A4 = x /. V4;
B4 = y /. V4;
Z1 = Quiet[N[z[w1*A1 + w2*B1], 50]]
Z2 = Quiet[N[z[w1*A2 + w2*B2], 50]]
Z3 = Quiet[N[z[w1*A3 + w2*B3], 50]]
Z4 = Quiet[N[z[w1*A4 + w2*B4], 50]]
m = (Im[Z1] - Im[Z2])/((Re[Z1] - Re[Z2]));
ListPlot[{{Re[Z1], Im[Z1]}, {Re[Z2], Im[Z2]}, {Re[Z3], 
   Im[Z3]}, {Re[Z4], Im[Z4]}}, PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}]
Zed[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] = z[w1*x + w2*y];
Quiet[ContourPlot[{Im[
     N[Zed[x, y]]] - (m*(Re[N[Zed[x, y]]] - Re[(M/2)]) - Im[M/2]), 
   0}, {x, 0, 2}, {y, -4, 4}, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, 
  MeshStyle -> {{Thick, Blue}}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
  PlotStyle -> 
   Directive[Orange, Opacity[0.1], Specularity[White, 30]], 
  PlotPoints -> 75, WorkingPrecision -> 50, ClippingStyle -> None]]
deriv[expr_, var_] := 
  D[expr, var] //. {Re'[e_] :> Re[D[e, var]]/D[e, var], 
    Im'[e_] :> Im[D[e, var]]/D[e, var], 
    Arg'[e_] :> Im[D[e, var]/e]/D[e, var], 
    Abs'[e_] :> (Re[e] Re[D[e, var]] + 
        Im[e] Im[D[e, var]])/(Abs[e] D[e, var])};
Fun[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := 
  Im[N[Zed[x, y]]] - (m*(Re[N[Zed[x, y]]] - Re[(M/2)]) - Im[M/2]);
TGrad[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := {deriv[Fun[x, y], x], 
   deriv[Fun[x, y], y]};
rot90[{x_, y_}] := {y, -x}
step[f_, pt : {x_, y_}, pt0 : {x0_, y0_}, resolution_] := 
  Module[{grad, grad0, t, contourPoint}, 
   grad = TGrad[x, y] /. {x -> pt[1], y -> pt[2]};
   grad0 = grad /. Thread[pt -> pt0];
   contourPoint = 
    grad0 t + pt0 /. 
     First@FindRoot[f /. Thread[pt -> grad0 t + pt0], {t, 0}];
   Sow[contourPoint];
   grad = Normalize[grad /. Thread[pt -> contourPoint]];
   contourPoint + rot90[grad] resolution];
result = Reap@NestList[step[Fun[x, y], {x, y}, #, .08] &, {0, 1}, 100];`

Believe it or not, all that really does need to be there in some capacity.  I should point out that the portion of the above code with `deriv[expr_, var_]` came from this very helpful post [Derivative of real functions including Re and Im](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3810/derivative-of-real-functions-including-re-and-im) and the portion of the code at the end, came from this post [How to find an approximate solution in a region when Solve or NSolve does not work?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/41871/how-to-find-an-approximate-solution-in-a-region-when-solve-or-nsolve-does-not-wo/64161#64161)

Can anyone see where my syntax is going wrong leading to the errors I'm getting above?

Comment: Try this first: 1) use `inv = N[Weierstrass...];`, 2) use `:=` instead of `=` everywhere you have patterns on the left hand side. Now you will get some error messages that clearly indicate that `Fun` and `TGrad` are not being called in a way that works.

Comment: What do you mean by patterns?  I thought I used := in all functions.  I'm not totally sure I see how this will give more transparent errors

Comment: Patterns are the things with underscores, like `x_`. When your function depends on an input, you usually want to evaluate the expression for the function for each given input. Hence one uses `:=`. There are lots of such functions above where you use `=`. Just try it on a fresh kernel and see!

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer So making all those changes, I got precisely the same errors, except the code immediately stopped, as opposed to running indefinitely.  Not sure if that signifies anything helpful.

Answer (score 2):

There seem to be other oddities in this code.  `TGrad[x, y] /. {x -> pt[1], y -> pt[2]}` doesn't make sense to me.  You probably meant to use `pt[[1]]` which is shorthand for `Part[pt, 1]`.  But even this shouldn't be needed as values of `x` and `y` should be populated from the destructuring pattern `pt : {x_, y_}`.  More importantly `deriv` would appear to need a Symbol for its second argument, as it is passed to `D`, but `TGrad` is expressly defined for a numeric parameter `x_?NumericQ` and this is passed to `deriv[Fun[x, y], x]`.

Comment: @spietro, what Mr.Wizard observes is what I would deduce from the error messages that appear with the changes I gave you. Often, when you define functions such as `TGrad` to do something, but you still see `TGrad` explicitly in the error message, it means that it haven't evaluated the way you would expect.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer I appreciate both comments above, thanks.  So I got rid of the junk next to `TGrad` (I didn't know how the destructuring pattern worked) and I also added `?NumericQ` to the second argument of `deriv`.  Running the code, there are similar, but different errors saying "0 (and 1) are not valid variables."  The functions which show up in the errors are `Fun`, `TGrad`, and `D`.  So apparently I'm not calling these properly.  Specifically, the error claim that my output of `Fun` is not a list of numbers with dimension {1}.  Can you see where I'm calling this improperly?