# Nullclines do not match vector field

Tags: differential-equations

I have the following system of differential equations.

$$ \begin{align*} x'&=(p-e)y-kx\\ y'&=kx/h-y \end{align*} $$

I found that when $p-e>h$ I get a saddle.

Nullclines are

$$ \begin{align*} y&=kx/(p-e)\\ y&=kx/h \end{align*} $$

Here is my Mathematica code to plot vector field and nullclines.

```
p=2; 
e=1; 
k=0.5; 
h=0.5;
g1 = VectorPlot[{(p-e)*y-k*x, k*x/h-y}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]; 
g2 = ContourPlot[{(p-e)*y-k*x==0, k*x/h-y==0}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}];
Show[g1, g2]
```

The vector field seems to be fine, I can see the saddle. However, nullclines do not "match" the vector field. 
[image]

What I expected is something like this:
[image]

I would appreciate if anyone explains why nullclines are off with the vector field.

Comment: The null clines are correct.  You appear to be looking for the saddle paths, which is different.

Comment: How to calculate them?

Comment: You should add an edit to your question to this ask this new question, so you can get an answer that matches your question.  (Comments disappear eventually.)

Comment: To expand on Alan's comment, the nullcline are when one variable isn't changing.  You can see that on one nullcline, the arrows are all left or right (change only in x), and on the other, the arrow are all up and down (change only in y).

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/135302

Comment: I did it here for two of the four curves emanating from the saddle: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/166066/4999

Answer (score 3):

This plots the separatrices because the ODE system is linear.  Normally, you want the initial conditions `ics` very close to the equilibrium `cp`. But the automatic method used for `StreamPoints` in [`VectorPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VectorPlot.html) and [`StreamPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StreamPlot.html) prunes streamlines that get close to one another.  In general, one usually has to use `NDSolve` to construct the solutions.

```
cp = {0, 0};   
jac = D[{(p - e)*y - k*x, k*x/h - y}, {{x, y}}];    (* Jacobian *)
ics =   (* initial velocity vectors of the separatrices at  cp  *)
 Flatten[{cp + #, cp - #} & /@ Eigenvectors[jac /. {x -> 0, y -> 0}], 1];

VectorPlot[{(p - e)*y - k*x, k*x/h - y}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
 StreamPoints -> {Append[{#, Red} & /@ ics, None]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Since the system is linear, possibly the OP wants actual line:

```
dirs = Eigenvectors[jac /. {x -> 0, y -> 0}];

VectorPlot[{(p - e)*y - k*x, k*x/h - y},
 {x, -10.1, 10}, {y, -10.1, 10},
 Epilog -> {Red, InfiniteLine[cp, #] & /@ dirs}, PlotRangePadding -> 0.1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]