# How to solve a non-linear equation?

Tags: equation-solving, complex

I am trying to solve the following non-linear equation:

$\frac{i e^{-x^2} \sqrt{\pi } x}{K^2}+\left(-0.131251-0.0379031 x^2-0.0151154 x^4-0.0100462 x^6+0.5 \left(0.00273859 +0.0400003 K^2\right) x^8+(0. +0.0000362178 i) x^9+0.5 \left(\text{6.72230790401107$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-6}+0.000122761 K^2\right) x^{10}+(0. +\text{7.371834962565406$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-8} i) x^{11}+0.5 \left(\text{3.049800199384706$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-9}+\text{7.195529551699709$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-8} K^2\right) x^{12}+(0. +\text{3.611964212904051$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-11} i) x^{13}+0.5 \left(-\text{1.2612171276659422$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-12}-\text{1.7472476684229308$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-11} K^2\right) x^{14}+\text{2.7423509229173302$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-15} K^2 x^{16}\right)/\left(0.0200001 K^2 x^8+0.0000613803 K^2 x^{10}+\text{3.5977647758498545$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-8} K^2 x^{12}-\text{8.736238342114654$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-12} K^2 x^{14}+\text{2.7423509229173302$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-15} K^2 x^{16}\right)$

Here's the *Mathematica* code I used:

```
Solve[(I E^-x^2 Sqrt[\[Pi]] x)/
    k^2 + (-0.13125090233975123 - 0.037903065816010294 x^2 - 
      0.015115427229185784 x^4 - 0.010046171350985062 x^6 + 
      0.5 (0.0027385850487922922 + 
         0.04000027499878133 k^2) x^8 + (0. + 
         0.000036217780642055754 I) x^9 + 
      0.5 (6.72230790401107*10^-6 + 
         0.00012276053475132815 k^2) x^10 + (0. + 
         7.371834962565406*10^-8 I) x^11 + 
      0.5 (3.049800199384706*10^-9 + 
         7.195529551699709*10^-8 k^2) x^12 + (0. + 
         3.611964212904051*10^-11 I) x^13 + 
      0.5 (-1.2612171276659422*10^-12 - 
         1.7472476684229308*10^-11 k^2) x^14 + 
      2.7423509229173302*10^-15 k^2 x^16)/(0.020000137499390665 k^2 x^8 + 
         0.00006138026737566407 k^2 x^10 + 
      3.5977647758498545*10^-8 k^2 x^12 - 
      8.736238342114654*10^-12 k^2 x^14 + 
      2.7423509229173302*10^-15 k^2 x^16) == 0, x]
```

where x is a complex variable and k is a real one.

I get this error message:

> > Solve::nsmet : This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve. >>

Please, I need to find x in terms of k and plot the output x versus k.

How can I use *Mathematica* techniques to solve this equation?

Comment: Ummm…are you looking for a symbolic solution in terms of the unknowns or a numerical solution (in which case you need to provide values for the a, b, c…).  Regardless, what makes you think there is a solution?

Comment: Also, `K` is a system symbol so don't use it.  The black colouring warns you about this.

Comment: symbolic solution and/or a numerical solution if possible !

Comment: I should leave this to the mathematicians, but I seriously doubt you're going to find a symbolic solution.  If you want a numeric solution, you need to specify the values of a, b, c...

Comment: I'm afraid this type of question is not a Mathematica question.  It is a math question.  It sounds like you just want a solution to the equation.  Asking to do it using Mathematica doens't automatically make it a Mathematica question.  Adding "...using Mathematica" cannot be used as an excuse to ask *anything* here...  First you need to make it clear (to yourself and to us) that it is at all reasonable to expect that there is a simple symbolic solution.  If you need a numeric solution then rephrase your question to make that clear and provide sufficient information (values of parameters).

Comment: Please see the new edition of equation

Comment: You are still using UpperCase k in your question after your edits. When clearly it was mentioned in the comments that it is a system symbol (search/replaceAll?)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized; i.e, it applies only to the local situation and needs of its poster and answers will not benefit others.

Comment: Have you tried `NSolve`?

Comment: You can get a good idea of where the solutions are by playing around with this: `Manipulate[ContourPlot[Abs[expression] /. {x -> zr + I zi} // Evaluate, {zr, -4, 4}, {zi, -4, 4}, PlotPoints -> 30, Contours -> Table[c, {c, 0, 1, 0.1}], FrameLabel -> {"Re[x]", "Im[x]"}], {{k, 1}, 0.1, 5, ContinuousAction -> False, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]`, where `expression` is the left hand side of the equation in your `Solve`.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5968/plotting-implicitly-defined-space-curves

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7944/getting-an-interpolatingfunction-from-a-contourplot

Answer (score 5):

I believe the OP's equation has infinitely many solutions `x` for a given `k`.  That might pose some difficulty.  It does for giving a definitive answer.

From [Plotting implicitly-defined space curves](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5968/plotting-implicitly-defined-space-curves), you can find ways to plot the solutions.  The method below follows [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5968/plotting-implicitly-defined-space-curves/5969#5969) by [Szabolcs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/12/szabolcs). The way that the linked question applies to the OP's case is this: The complex equation `eqn == 0` corresponds to two real equations `Re@eqn == Im@eqn == 0`; further, if we write `x = re + im I` in terms of its real and imaginary parts, we turn the equation into a pair equations in terms of three real variables `{re, im, k}`.

The variable `eqn` represents the left-hand side of the OP's equation.  I got rid of the denominators (`eqn1`) because they led to divide-by-zero errors that broke lines.

```
Clear[re, im, x];
eqn1 = Numerator @ Simplify[Expand @ First @ eqn] == 0;
mfRe = Function[{re, im, k},  Re @ First @ eqn1 /. x -> re + im I // Evaluate ];

plot = ContourPlot3D[
 0 == Im@First@eqn1 /. x -> re + im I // Evaluate,
 {re, -3, 3}, {im, -3, 3}, {k, -1, 1},
 Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshFunctions -> {mfRe},
 ContourStyle -> None, BoundaryStyle -> None, AxesLabel -> Automatic,
 MeshStyle -> {Red, Thick}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Some of the lines look broken.  One could increase [`PlotPoints`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PlotPoints.html) or [`MaxRecursion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MaxRecursion.html) to see if [`ContourPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ContourPlot.html) can connect them up.

We can extract the lines and convert them to solutions, somewhat like [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7944/getting-an-interpolatingfunction-from-a-contourplot/7953#7953) to [Getting an InterpolatingFunction from a ContourPlot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7944/getting-an-interpolatingfunction-from-a-contourplot):

```
sols = With[{pts = First@Cases[plot, GraphicsComplex[pp_, ___] :> pp, Infinity]},
   pts[[#]] & /@ Cases[plot, Line[p_] :> p, Infinity]
   ];
```

We'll see which curve is the first `Line` in the plot:

```
With[{line1 = First[sols]},
  sol1 = Interpolation[
    Transpose@{line1[[All, 3]], line1[[All, {1, 2}]]}]
  ]; 

ParametricPlot3D[Join[sol1[k], {k}], 
 Evaluate[Prepend[First@sol1["Domain"], k]], 
 PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}, {-1, 1}}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
 AxesLabel -> {re, im, k}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The function `sol1` represents an approximate solution, but not a very good one (for an exact answer, `First@eqn` would evaluate to zero):

```
sol1[0.5].{1, I}
First@eqn /. {x -> sol1[0.5].{1, I}, k -> 0.5}
(* 1.30297 - 0.652346 I *)
(* -0.00599196 - 0.00566206 I *)
```

If a more accurate result is desired, one may apply [`FindRoot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FindRoot.html) to each point:

```
With[{line1 = First[sols]},
  sol2 = Interpolation[
    {#[[3]], x /. FindRoot[
         First@eqn1 /. k -> #[[3]], {x, #[[{1, 2}]].{1, I}}]} & /@ line1]
  ]; 

First@eqn /. {x -> sol2[0.5], k -> 0.5}
(* -8.76055*10^-12 + 6.38489*10^-13 I *)
```