# How can we extract the points of a level-set from a 2D Interpolating function?

Tags: plotting, numerics, interpolation

Let us assume that we have a 2D Interpolating function `u[x,y]`. 
We can plot its contours by

`ContourPlot[u[x,y],{x,xmin,xmax},{y,ymin,ymax}]`

But how for given `u0` can we extract all points `x0,y0` such that `u[x0,y0]=u0` in a table form?

Comment: I'd say the fact that it's an interpolating function doesn't change anything, you should be able to use the methods here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/105750/9490

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6806034/4712538) may be even more directly what you want.  Or [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/66489/9490)

Comment: Thank you for your answers. But my main concern is how to get the values `x0,y0` !

Comment: Show an MWE illustrating your issue. With such general statements it's not clear what do you really want. In my opinion, the posted links adresse your issue and provide additional hints allowing to fulfill your needs. If not, then I'm mistaken because your question isn't clear enough.

Comment: @DK13 - look at either of the answers from my second comment, and they say exactly how to get those values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
u[x_, y_] := x + y
int = Interpolation @ Catenate @ Table[{{x, y}, u[x, y]}, {x, 0, 1, 0.1}, {y, 0, 1, 0.1}];
u0 = 0.5;
plot = ContourPlot[int[x, y] == u0, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Investigating

```
FullForm[plot]
```

leads to

```
pts = Cases[plot, _GraphicsComplex, Infinity][[1, 1]];

ListPlot[pts, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

The above extracts the deafult number of points used by `ContourPlot`. To extract more points, add `PlotPoints -> 100` (or any other suitable number) as an option to `ContourPlot`.

See also [Generating evenly spaced points on a curve](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8454/generating-evenly-spaced-points-on-a-curve).

Comment: thank you! How can we get denser or less denser points?

Comment: Or to homogenize the distance between the various points?