# DiscretizeRegion of ImplicitRegion too small

Tags: regions

I have a 2D function that has some sharp peeks within the my domain.  I need to find a tight region that contains these sharp peeks. The following is an example of what I would like to do.

An example function:

```
Clear[f]
f[x_, y_] := 1/(1/4 + Sqrt[(x - 1)^2 + (y - 1)^2]);
```

Clearly this function has a max of 4 at {1,1}. I can find a region around the max via:

```
zmax=3.9;
R = DiscretizeRegion[ImplicitRegion[f[x, y] >= zmax, {{x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}}]]
```

This works great but as `zmax` gets closer to 4.0 there comes a point where it no longer works like at `zmax=3.999`

Is there a way I can help `ImplicitRegion` and/or `DiscretizeRegion` to know where to look? In my real problem I start with a `zmax` that works and loop through larger and larger values for `zmax`. I have done a `FindMaximum` so I know how far I can go. I would like to do something like the following which does not work:

```
zmax=3.9;
R = DiscretizeRegion[ImplicitRegion[f[x, y] >= zmax, {{x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}}]];

rm = RegionMember[R];

zmaxmax=3.999;
R = DiscretizeRegion[ImplicitRegion[f[x, y] >= zmaxmax && rm[{x,y}], {{x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}}]];
```

Where I would like to use what I have learned in my last step to inform my next step. But sadly this does not work.

Comment: Does it help if you use the `RegionBounds` of the previous region to set the bounds on `x` and `y`, instead of fixing them to `{{x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}}`?

Comment: I'll try that, but my real problem has a few peeks of the same height that are well separated. Therefore, I may still have the same problem.

Comment: I have tried `RegionBounds` along with `ConnectedMeshComponents` so I can now get done what I need to do but I would not call it a good solution.

Answer (score 2):

Your original approach can work if you exploit `RegionPlot` as an alternative to `DiscretizeRegion`. With `RegionPlot`, the resulting `Graphics` must be deconstructed to find the corresponding region. However, you can use the `PlotPoints` option to offer some help finding small regions.

I thought the `Method->"RegionPlot"` option of `DiscretizeRegion` might be used to accomplish the same thing, but I can’t see how to pass a `PlotPoints` sub-option to it. So instead, here’s a function that spells it all out.

```
ClearAll[newDiscretizeRegion];

Options[newDiscretizeRegion] = {PlotPoints -> 40};

newDiscretizeRegion[region_, {{xMin_, xMax_}, {yMin_, yMax_}}, OptionsPattern[]] := 
    Module[
       {graphics, points, boundary, mesh},

       graphics = RegionPlot[
         {x, y} \[Element] region, {x, xMin, xMax}, {y, yMin, yMax},
         PlotPoints -> OptionValue[PlotPoints]
       ];
       points = FirstCase[graphics, _GraphicsComplex, Null, Infinity][[1]];
       boundary = FirstCase[graphics, _Line, Null, Infinity];
       mesh = First@Normal@GraphicsComplex[points, boundary/.Line->Polygon];
       DiscretizeRegion@mesh
    ];
```

Note that the `PlotPoints` option defaults to 40. Use a larger value if the region is still not found or to get added resolution in the result. This could be made more automatic, of course.

With this function, your approach would look something like this. Here the `PlotPoints` option is gradually increased, but it can be profiled differently for better speed. The final value (220 in this example) determines how smooth the mesh boundary will be.

```
ClearAll[f];

f[x_, y_] := 1/(1/4 + Sqrt[(x - 1)^2 + (y - 1)^2]);

ClearAll[deltaGoal, bounds, nextzmax, zmax, plotPoints, R];

deltaGoal = 1*^-12;
bounds = {{0, 2}, {0, 2}};
nextzmax = 3;
plotPoints = 40;

While[4 - nextzmax > deltaGoal,
  zmax = nextzmax;
  R = newDiscretizeRegion[ImplicitRegion[f[x, y] >= zmax, {x, y}], bounds, 
    PlotPoints -> plotPoints];
  bounds = RegionBounds[R, "Sufficient"];
  nextzmax = 4 - 0.1 (4 - zmax);
  plotPoints += 15;
  ];

Print[{InputForm@zmax, InputForm@bounds}];
R
```

```
{3.999999999999], {{0.9999999999999345, 1.000000000000066},{0.9999999999999345, 1.000000000000066}}]}
```

[image: Peak region]

I haven't tried to extend this for functions with multiple peaks, which you would have to find and isolate before iterating as indicated.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way that takes advantage of the undocumented `PlotPoints` form that allows specific sample points to be included.  See [Specific initial sample points for 3D plots](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19121/specific-initial-sample-points-for-3d-plots/19343#19343) for more.

**Test function**

I'll construct a function with five maxima of the same height.

```
SeedRandom[0];
ncp = 5;
cp = RandomReal[{0, 2}, {ncp, 2}];

f[x_, y_] = Simplify[     (* set up with unknown coefficients C[1], C[2],... *)
   Sum[C[i]/(1/4 + EuclideanDistance[{x, y}, cp[[i]]]), {i, ncp}],
   {x, y} ∈ Reals];
f[x_, y_] = f[x, y] /.    (* solve for the coefficients *)
    First@Solve[Equal @@@ Partition[f @@@ cp, 2, 1], Array[C, ncp - 1]] /.
     C[ncp] -> 1;

f @@@ cp
(*  {7.25243, 7.25243, 7.25243, 7.25243, 7.25243}  *)
```

**Discretizing `RegionPlot`**

Sometimes it's just easier to build things up from plots that to use the region functionality.  (I expect this to improve, since WRI does pay attention to how users use *Mathematica* and adapts its interfaces to suit common usage.)

```
max = f @@ First[cp] - 0.001;
reg = DiscretizeGraphics@
   RegionPlot[f[x, y] > max, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, PlotPoints -> {Automatic, cp}];
```

The regions are minuscule, so I made the boundaries thick enough to see.

```
HighlightMesh[reg, Style[1, Red, Thick]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

A check.  I had to exaggerate the `max` level to `max - 0.2` to get a visible result.  The regions are just too small for screen resolution.

```
Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, 
 Mesh -> {{max - 0.2}}, MeshShading -> {Automatic, Red}, 
 PlotPoints -> {Automatic, cp}, MaxRecursion -> 3]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Alternative for higher quality**

I'm not sure what the use-case is.  The regions produced above, if you zoom in on them, are very blocky and often square.  If high-resolution regions are required, then `RegionPlot` is an expensive way to go.  An alternative is to use `implicitCurve` from my answer to [Getting an InterpolatingFunction from a ContourPlot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7944/getting-an-interpolatingfunction-from-a-contourplot/66582#66582) to get a parametrization of the curve `f[x, y] == max` and use it to construct a polygon.  We can also adapt `periodicEvent` from my answer to [Plotting implicitly-defined space curves](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5968/plotting-implicitly-defined-space-curves/64923#64923) to 2D to detect when we've traced the entire loop around each maximum.  *Beware:* Region functionality is as yet only available at [`MachinePrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MachinePrecision.html). Even though, `implicitCurve` can be used with high `WorkingPrecision`, there are limits to how far it can be used to create high-precision regions.

The function

```
nbhdBoundaries[fn, level, cps]
```

uses `implicitCurve` to solve the equation `fn == level` in the neighborhood of each critical point in the list `cps`.  It returns a list of parameterizations of the boundaries.  Each parametrization is a pair of the form

```
{x -> InterpolatingFunction[<>], y -> InterpolatingFunction[<>]}
```

The function

```
discretizeParametricLoop[{x -> InterpolatingFunction[<>], y -> InterpolatingFunction[<>]}]
```

takes such a pair and returns a `MeshRegion` of the region contained by the parameterization.  (Code at bottom.)

Here are the functions applied to the example above:

```
reg = RegionUnion @@
   DiscretizeRegion /@ discretizeParametricLoop /@ nbhdBoundaries[f[x, y], max, cp];
HighlightMesh[reg, Style[1, Red, Thickness[0.01]]],
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here are the individual regions:

```
Show /@ DiscretizeRegion /@ 
   discretizeParametricLoop /@ 
    nbhdBoundaries[f[x, y], max, cp] // GraphicsRow
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Code dump:

Note that the starting value for the point in `implicitCurve` is neither checked nor adjusted for satisfying the equation `eqn`.  If it is not on the curve, what will happen is that a different level curve will be returned.  (Checking is not hard to add; adjusting and finding can in general be tricky.)

```
ClearAll[implicitCurve, periodicEvent]

variableQ = Quiet@ListQ@Solve[{}, #] &;

(* creates a WhenEvent to stop integration when variables return to their initial values *)
periodicEvent[
   vars : {x_?variableQ, ___?variableQ}, 
   p0 : {x0_?NumericQ, ___?NumericQ},
   tolerance_: 0.01] := 
  WhenEvent[x == x0 && Norm[vars - p0] < tolerance, "StopIntegration"];

Options[implicitCurve] = Join[{"Events" -> {}}, Options[NDSolve]];
implicitCurve[
   eqn_,                                                (* equation to paramterize *)
   {x_?variableQ, x0_?NumericQ},                        (* x & starting value *)
   {y_?variableQ, y0_?NumericQ},                        (* y & starting value *)
   {tmin_?NumericQ, tmax_?NumericQ | tmax : Infinity},  (* integration interval *)
    opts : OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{t, ode},
   ode = {x'[t]^2 + y'[t]^2 == 1,     (*unit speed*)
     {x[0], y[0]} == {x0, y0},        (*starting point*)
     {x'[0], y'[0]} == 
      Normalize@                      (*starting direction*)
       Cross[D[eqn /. Equal -> Subtract, {{x, y}}] /. 
         Thread[{x, y} -> {x0, y0}]]};
   First@NDSolve[{eqn /. {x -> x[t], y -> y[t]}, ode, 
      OptionValue["Events"] /. {x -> x[t], y -> y[t]}}, {x, y}, {t, 
      tmin, tmax}, FilterRules[{opts}, Options[NDSolve]]]];
```

In `nbhdBoundaries` we have to knock the initial search point for `FindRoot` off of the critical point, probably because the gradient is singular; in any case, `FindRoot` did not work reliably using the critical point as the initial point.  The offset `dy` assumes the function does not vary wildly, as in the test function.  I used the minimum distance between the critical points as a scale.  The secant line method (replace `{y, Last[cp] + dy}` by `{y, Last[cp], Last[cp] + dy}`) might be more robust or the scale might need to be adjusted in some cases.

```
ClearAll[nbhdBoundaries, discretizeParametricLoop];
nbhdBoundaries[fn_, level_, cps_] := Module[{x0, y0, dy},
   dy = Min[EuclideanDistance @@@ Subsets[cp, {2}]]/100;
   Function[{cp},
     x0 = First[cp];      (* find starting point on curve *)
     y0 = y /. FindRoot[fn == level /. x -> x0, {y, Last[cp] + dy}];
     implicitCurve[       (* integrate the parametrization *)
      f[x, y] == level,
      {x, x0},
      {y, y0},
      {0, Infinity},
      "Events" ->         (* stops the integration after one loop *)
        {periodicEvent[{x, y}, {x0, y0}, EuclideanDistance[cp, {x0, y0}]/10]}
      ]
     ] /@ cps];

discretizeParametricLoop[{_ -> xif_, _ -> yif_}] :=
  Polygon[Transpose[{xif["ValuesOnGrid"], yif["ValuesOnGrid"]}]];
```

An alternative `discretizeParametricLoop`, that uses `ParametricPlot` to give a smoother boundary:

```
discretizeParametricLoop[{_ -> xif_, _ -> yif_}] := Block[{t},
   First@Cases[
     ParametricPlot @@ {{xif[t], yif[t]}, Flatten@{t, xif["Domain"]}},
     Line[p_] :> Polygon[p],
     Infinity]
   ];
```

Comment: Thank you I have been away on vacation without a computer, soon I'll be away on vacation with a computer and I will go through the details of your response.