# Can one reorder a list for parameterization?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, functions

I'm using `ContourPlot` to extract data points from a rather non-trivial curve in the $(x,y)$-plane.  However, the points are spit out in the order of increasing $x$ value.  This curve has many turning points, and I want to order the points in such a way that they correspond to a parameter moving along the length of the curve.  I'm wondering if there's a way to reorder these data points in a compatible way for parameterizing with respect to length along the curve.

Since my code is messy and involves, maybe an example would be best.

```
data2 = Table[{x, Cos[x]}, {x, -2*Pi, 2*Pi, \[Pi]/16}] // N
dataa = RandomSample[data2]
ListPlot[dataa]
```

So here we have a small number of data points from a cosine curve, and I've placed the points in a random order.  Can one reorder the points in a way that corresponds to moving smoothly from the left to the right along the curve? *Clearly* in this case, there's a trivial solution where you order the points from smallest to largest $x$ value.  In my case, the curve is not a function of $x$, so this won't work!  So maybe is there another way, other than this trivial solution?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related Q&A, for a different approach: [(q7944)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7944).  Other related answers:[(a64161)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/64161), [(a64923)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/64923); in 3D: [(a87540)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/87540), [(a99903)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/99903)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
datab = FindCurvePath[dataa];
dataa = dataa[[Flatten[datab]]];
ListPlot[dataa]
```

[image]

If the list is split, just run

```
datab = FindCurvePath[dataa];
dataa = dataa[[Flatten[datab]]];
```

again, or go to the next step.
If it still doesn't work, run this code

```
datad = Table[
   dataa[[i]] - dataa[[i + 1]], {i, 1, Length[dataa] - 1}];
splitp = Position[datad[[All, 2]], Max[datad[[All, 2]]]][[1]][[1]]
dataa = Catenate[{Reverse[dataa[[1 ;; splitp]]], 
    dataa[[splitp+1 ;; Length[dataa]]]}];
```

As the code doesn't always produce the same result, you may have to run the entire code more than once, but eventually it sorts.
You can run:

```
Manipulate[ListPlot[dataa[[1 ;; a]],
PlotRange -> {{-2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {-1, 1}}], {a,1, Length[dataa], 1}]
```

To determine if the list is properly arranged.

If the list  is reversed, use `Reverse[dataa]` to fix.

[image]

Comment: Caveat for @spietro, the smooth curve here is found in two pieces, as can be seen from `ListPlot[dataa[[#]] & /@ datab, Joined -> True]`.

Comment: @BoLe This happens occasionally, but not always, it's something that can be fixed, but the exact code depends on the situation.

Comment: @BoLe Actually, just rerunning fixes this.

Comment: I'm not so sure. The number of `FindCurvePath` pieces can't be determined since `dataa` is in random order. However, the pieces returned by first FCP aren't in any particular order, so I don't think `Flatten` or `Join` reduce the disorder really. In addition to that, every two neighboring pieces share an index, so the indexing `dataa[[Flatten[datab]]]` should run in trouble. Did you try and run the code a couple of times and get a fixed-point FCP result of length one?

Comment: @BoLe Ok, Now it should work under all circumstances.

Comment: When I copy your last block of code and run it repeatedly (with ver. 10.4.1) on the `dataa` from the question, `data` is not sorted.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Are you running with the right list? I'll edit to make it always `dataa`.
I've run it about a dozen times now, and it always works.

Comment: I have copied your first two blocks of code, placed then in a single `Do` loop, and iterated 200 times.  The result never is entirely sorted.  In fact, the `Manipulate` plot in your answer does not show the points in order either.  Watch carefully the far left of the plot, and you will see another  point appear there about three-quarters the way through the animation.  Use `ListLinePlot` instead of `ListPlot` to see this more clearly.

Comment: @bbgodfrey
It turns out there was an error in the code, I misplaced the split, the error has been fit.
I'm now noticing a pattern, of {Reverse list, false list, correct list}, so running it 200 times gives a 1/3 chance of the correct list, as does running it once. Hence the `Manipulate[]` to check it.

Comment: You may wish to provide a complete code that stops iterating when a correctly ordered answer is obtained.  Perhaps, check with `Ordering`.

Comment: @Feyre This is fabulous, thank you.  However, when I apply it to my actual problem, there is a very strange issue.  Initially, all of the points are present, but as soon as I run your part of the code, a few clusters of them disappear.  Any idea what might be causing this?  I'm very encouraged however, because other than the missing clusters, your code orders them perfectly on the first try :)  Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Your problem can likely be avoided entirely by using Jens's lovely routine `contourRegionPlot`:

- [Saner alternative to ContourPlot fill](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3190/121)

Compare these results:

```
p1 = ContourPlot[Im[ArcSin[x + I y]], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, Exclusions -> None];

p2 = contourRegionPlot[Im[ArcSin[x + I y]], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}];

GraphicsRow[{p1, p2}]

{pts1, pts2} = Cases[#, {_, _}, {-2}] & /@ {p1, p2};

ListLinePlot /@ {pts1, pts2} // GraphicsColumn
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps `ListCurvePathPlot` can help you do what you want?

Comment: That looks potentially promising.  Applying it, it certainly connects the data points (in the proper order) with a smooth curve, but I'm not sure it will reorder the data points in the original list.  Or maybe I can just extract data points from the smooth curve it produces?  Using something like `Union` which works for `ContourPlot`

Comment: `Cases[ListCurvePathPlot[dataa], Line[z_] -> z, Infinity]` extracts the curve.  Unfortunately, it is in multiple parts that are not necessarily in order.  In other words, it still requires some sorting.