# How can i 2d-plot Cobb-Douglas function?

Tags: plotting, functions

can I plot Cobb-Douglas function in 2D without using *ContourPlot*?

I have this function:

```
u[x1_, x2_] := Log[x1] + 2*Log[x2];
```

and now I plot it using:

```
ContourPlot[u[x1,x2], {x1, 0, 10}, {x2, 0, 10}]
```

how can i 2d-plot it using simple `Plot`?

Comment: ...`Plot[]` is intended for functions of **one** variable. You have two variables in your function, so you'll have to set one of those two to a constant.

Comment: I wrote a function to get a numerical solution for an implicit curve [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/66582/4999), which can be useful in cases where the equations cannot be solved symbolically.  Here they can be, but I'm curious why not use `ContourPlot`?  It can be combined with other graphics, and it does a pretty good job on this function.  I don't see the point, unless it's a homework exercise.

Answer (score 2):

```
u[x1_, x2_] = Log[x1] + 2*Log[x2];

cp = ContourPlot[u[x1, x2], {x1, 0, 10}, {x2, 0, 10}, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

`Solve` for `x2` along the contours

```
f[x1_, c_] = x2 /. Solve[c == u[x1, x2], x2, Reals][[1]]

(*  E^(c/2)/Sqrt[x1]  *)
```

Plot the contours

```
plt = Plot[
  Evaluate[
   Table[
    Tooltip[f[x1, c], c],
    {c, -2, 6, 2}]],
  {x1, 0, 10},
  PlotRange -> {0, 10},
  Frame -> True,
  AspectRatio -> 1,
  PlotStyle -> Thick,
  ImageSize -> 360]
```

[image]

Overlaying the plots

```
Show[cp, plt]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** For a specific `{x1, x2}` then the contour is just `u[x1, x2]`

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{c = u[x1, x2]},
  Plot[Tooltip[f[x, c], c], {x, 0, 10},
   PlotRange -> {0, 10},
   Frame -> True,
   FrameLabel -> (Style[TraditionalForm[#], Bold, 14] & /@
      {Subscript[x,
         1], Subscript[x, 2]}),
   AspectRatio -> 1,
   Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4], Point[{x1, x2}]}]],
 {{x1, 5., Subscript[x, 1]}, 0, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{x2, 5., Subscript[x, 2]}, 0, 10,
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you,but I have another doubt: how can I draw only one curve that pass through fixed x1 and x2 ?

Comment: @Motosega - see edit. Pick a point, any point ...

Comment: it doesn't work. This code don't draw the blue curve...

Comment: @Motosega - Works fine here. Try starting with a fresh kernel, perhaps you have some old definitions laying around.