# How do I find the intersection of a closed 3D curve given by numerical data with a specified plane?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, equation-solving

I have a list of 3D data points which form a closed curve. My own data can't be easily generated analytically, but the qualitative behaviour is well represented by a parametric curve families such as `{Sin[a1 t] Cos[a2 t], Sin[a3 t] Sin[a4 t], Sin[a5 t]}` where the `aN` are constants. Sample data is given by:

```
dt = Table[{Sin[3 t] Cos[1 t], Sin[t] Sin[5 t], Sin[2 t]}, {t, -10, 10, 0.005}];
p1 = ListPointPlot3D[dt]
```

[image: points from a closed curve]

I want to solve for the points where this closed 3D curve cuts a plane I specify but I'm am unable to do it. For example a plane at `z = 0.5` as shown here:

```
p2 = Plot3D[-0.5, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
Show[p1, p2]
```

[image: cutting plane]

No approach I've tried so far has worked e.g. `Interpolation`, `Nearest` to -0.5, use of `Select` and `Drop`.

The data does wrap around itself multiple times and getting slightly different solution points on each pass due to differences in the stepsize or something like that is not a problem.

Related I think to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9309)

In brief:
How can I find where a closed curve given by numerical data points cuts a specified plane?
Any help you can give is much appreciated.

Comment: Since it's a closed curve, you could either use [periodic splines](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10273), [periodic Hermite interpolants](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14662), or a [Fourier fit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17704) for your closed curve, and then equate the $z$-component of your curve to the value of your cutting plane.

Comment: Why do you sample over such a broad interval? -Pi to Pi would suffice.

Comment: @BoLe, there's actually a good question in there: how might one know that his data points were sampled over more than one period?

Comment: Related: [10640](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10640/find-zero-crossing-in-a-list).  Use `zeroCrossings[Last /@ dt - 0.5]` or `zeroCrossings[plane @@@ dt]`, where `plane[x, y, z] == 0` is the equation of the plane, to find the points between which the crossing occurs.

Comment: @J. M. Thanks for the suggestion and the fast response yesterday. Very useful stuff and it got me quickly into some experimenting that did achieved some success.

Comment: @BoLe I looped around multiple times as my real data does that instead of a single loop. It comes from combining multiple time traces that don't necessarily repeated exactly. I thought the multiple loops would be constructive to the question in that sense.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes this is exactly what was needed. Its does precisely what I want. I had tried to generate something similar myself but failed miserably. I've +1'ed yourself here and whuber's answer on the related question. As this answered my question I'd happily accepted it but theres nothing to formally accept..... Could you or whuber repost a tailored answer maybe? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can use one of the `zeroCrossing` functions from the answers to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10640/find-zero-crossing-in-a-list) to construct solutions to where an ordered list of points representing a curve crosses a surface $f(x,y,z)=0$.  There are some very nice answers to the linked question with good explanations of the solutions.  Use one that returns an interval of indices where the crossing takes place ,such as [whuber's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10640/find-zero-crossing-in-a-list/10645#10645)

```
zeroCrossings[l_List] := Module[{t, u, v},
  t = {Sign[l], Range[Length[l]]} // Transpose; (*List of-1,0,1 only*)
  u = Select[t, First[#] != 0 &];               (*Ignore zeros*)
  v = Split[u, First[#1] == First[#2] &];       (*Group into runs of+and- values*)
  {Most[Max[#[[All, 2]]] & /@ v], Rest[Min[#[[All, 2]]] & /@ v]} // Transpose]
```

or the `SparseArray` version in Mr.Wizard's [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10640/find-zero-crossing-in-a-list/10653#10653), which seems to be quite efficient.

```
zeroCrossings[l_List] := 
 With[{c = SparseArray[l]["AdjacencyLists"]}, {c[[#]], c[[# + 1]]}\[Transpose] &@
   SparseArray[Differences@Sign@l[[c]]]["AdjacencyLists"]]
```

---

The OP's curve points, for which I suppose the corresponding values of `t` may be lost or unknown:

```
dt = Table[{Sin[3 t] Cos[1 t], Sin[t] Sin[5 t], Sin[2 t]}, {t, -10, 10, 0.005}];
```

To help you understand the functions below, I first give the output of `zeroCrossings`.  For the OP's example, we would be interest when `z - 0.5` is zero.  We translate down the `z` coordinates of points `dt` by `0.5` and search for the zero crossings of the translated `z` coordinates.

```
zeroCrossings[Last /@ dt - 0.5]
```

> ```
> {{168, 169}, {377, 378}, {796, 797}, {1006, 1007}, {1425, 1426},
>  {1634, 1635}, {2053, 2054}, {2262, 2263}, {2681, 2682}, {2891, 2892},
>  {3309, 3310}, {3519, 3520}, {3938, 3939}}
> ```

Each pair are the indices of points lying on either side of `z == 0.5`.

Below I use linear interpolation to find the crossing point, which seems simplest.  The function `zeroPt` returns the point where `f` is zero corresponding to the zero crossing interval `crossIDX`.  The function `zeroTime` returns the "time", interpolated between the indices of the crossing.

```
zeroPt[pts_, crossIDX_, f_] /; Length[crossIDX] >= 3 := 
  Mean[pts ~Part~ crossIDX[[2 ;; -2]]]; (* unlikely >= 4 - return all zero points? *)
zeroPt[pts_, crossIDX_, f_] /; Length[crossIDX] == 2 :=
  (#2 f[#1] - #1 f[#2])/(f[#1] - f[#2]) & @@ pts[[crossIDX]];

zeroTime[pts_, idx_, f_] /; Length[idx] >= 3 := Mean[idx];
zeroTime[pts_, idx_, f_] /; Length[idx] == 2 := First[idx] + Rescale[0., f /@ pts[[idx]]];
```

#### OP's Example

```
zeroTime[dt, #, Last[#] - 0.5 &] & /@ zeroCrossings[Last /@ dt - 0.5]
```

> ```
> {168.405, 377.843, 796.723, 1006.16, 1425.04, 1634.48, 2053.36, 2262.8,
>  2681.68, 2891.12, 3310., 3519.44, 3938.32}
> ```

```
int = zeroPt[dt, #, Last[#] - 0.5 &] & /@ zeroCrossings[Last /@ dt - 0.5]
```

> ```
> {{0.682995, 0.249992, 0.5}, {-0.183003, 0.249985, 0.5}, {0.682998, 0.249994, 0.5},
>  {-0.183003, 0.249984, 0.5}, {0.68301, 0.249999, 0.5}, {-0.182995, 0.24997, 0.5},
>  {0.682996, 0.249993, 0.5}, {-0.183001, 0.249981, 0.5}, {0.682997, 0.249993, 0.5},
>  {-0.183005, 0.249988, 0.5}, {0.683012, 0.25, 0.5}, {-0.182995, 0.249971, 0.5},
>  {0.682997, 0.249993, 0.5}}
> ```

If the curve is an orbit or other periodic trajectory, then the one might be interested in the unique intersections.  One can gather the clusters of points with this function and take the `Mean` to approximate the intersection.

```
clusters[pts_, dist_] := Gather[pts, EuclideanDistance[##] < dist &];
```

Example:

```
Mean /@ clusters[int, 0.001]
```

> ```
> {{0.683001, 0.249995, 0.5}, {-0.183, 0.24998, 0.5}}
> ```

A plot of the results:

```
Graphics3D[{
  {Opacity[0.1], PointSize[Small], Point @ dt},
  {Red, PointSize[Medium], Point[Mean /@ clusters[int, 0.001]]}}, 
  Axes -> True]
```

[image: z == 0.5]

#### Arbitrary planes

We can apply the method to arbitrary planes.  A function `plane` defining the plane, `plane[x, y, z] == 0`, is applied to the points and we find where the values cross zero; the function is needed in both `zeroCrossings` and `zeroPt`.

Here we will use `ConvexHull` to show the plane via a polygon containing all the intersection points.  We have to project the points onto a plane, which must be chose judiciously so that the projected points are not all collinear, if possible.

```
Needs["ComputationalGeometry`"]

plane[x_, y_, z_] := 2 x - 3 y - 2 z + 0.5;
With[{intersections = zeroPt[dt, #, plane @@ # &] & /@ zeroCrossings[plane @@@ dt]},
 Graphics3D[{
   {Lighter@Blue, PointSize[Small], Point@dt},
   {Darker@Red, PointSize[Large], Point[intersections],
    Red, Opacity[0.6],
    Polygon[#[[ConvexHull[Most /@ #]]] &[Mean /@ clusters[intersections, 0.001]]]}}, 
  Axes -> True]
 ]
```

[image: random plane]

#### Other surfaces

The method works to find where any function of the points crosses zero (in this case `surf`).

```
param[u_, v_] := {u v, u, 2 v^2 - 1};
surf[x_, y_, z_] := Evaluate[Subtract @@ Eliminate[{x, y, z} == param[u, v], {u, v}]];
Show[
 With[{intersections = zeroPt[dt, #, surf @@ # &] & /@ zeroCrossings[surf @@@ dt]}, 
  Graphics3D[{
    {Lighter@Blue, PointSize[Small], Point@dt},
    {Red, PointSize[Large], 
     Point[Mean /@ clusters[intersections, 0.001]]}}, Axes -> True]],
 ParametricPlot3D[param[u, v], {u, -1, 1}, {v, -1, 1}, 
  MeshStyle -> Gray, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.3]]
 ]
```

[image: Whitney umbrella]

Comment: +1 Thank you very much for this. The  code up to and including the `clusters` function really solves my problem. The extension to intersections with arbitrary planes and surfaces is also very instructional and useful.

Answer (score 2):

If you start by interpolating the each component of the curve you can easily solve for a simple plane like `z=0.5`:

```
dt = Table[{Sin[3 t] Cos[1 t], Sin[t] Sin[5 t], Sin[2 t]}, {t, -10, 10, 0.005}];
ip = Interpolation[dt[[All, #]]] & /@ {1, 2, 3};
FindRoot[ip[[3]][t] == 0.5, {t, 10}] (* ip[[3]] is the z component of the curve*)
(* {t -> 168.404} *)
#[t /. %] & /@ ip
(* {0.683013, 0.25, 0.5} *)
```

For other planes you can change the `FindRoot` criteria, for instance `FindRoot[2 ip[[3]][t] + ip[[2]][t] == 0.5, {t, 10}]`

Comment: Thanks for that. I had trouble finding all of the crossings though using `FindRoot`. I incorporated it into a forward seach style algorithm but I was still missing some points. I also tried to use `FindInstance`. Thanks for the answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

Defining a function `P[x_,y_,z_]  := a x + b y + c z` for suitable constant values `a`, `b`, `c`, the plane is the set of all points `P[x, y, z] == 0`, i.e. points that satisfy this equation are on the plane. Points for which `P[x, y, z] > 0` are on one side of the plane, while those giving `P[x, y, z] < 0` are on the other side.

So, the points you want are those on your curve with `P[x, y, z] == 0`, or an interpolation between any successive points on your curve that give opposite signs for `P`.