# How to plot an equation with unknown constant?

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

Suppose we have two equation

$f(x,y,c)=0$

and

$g(x,y,c)=0$

where $c$ is an unknown constant.

I am trying to plot a graph for $x,y$. One way to do it is to solve one of the equations for $c$ then substitute the value of $c$ in the second equation to obtain an expression for $x$ and $y$. Then we can use the ContourPlot to plot a graph for $x$ and $y$.

However, what if $f$, $g$ are too complicated and we can't solve for $c$ to substitute in the other equation to obtain the an expression for $x,y$. Is there another method or a special function one can use to plot without solving the equations?

Thanks.

**Example:**

$f(x,y,c)=c \left(c^3-c x^2+\log (c)+2 (x-1)^2\right)-(c-1)^2 y^2=0$

$g(x,y,c)=2 \left(-c \left(x^2+y^2-1\right)+2 \sin ^3(c)+(x-1)^2+y^2\right)=0$

In Mathematica terms:

```
f[x_, y_, c_] := c (c^3 - c x^2 + Log[c] + 2 (x - 1)^2) - (c - 1)^2 y^2;
g[x_, y_, c_] := 2 (-c (x^2 + y^2 - 1) + 2 Sin[c]^3 + (x - 1)^2 + y^2);
```

Comment: Do you have an actual example?

Comment: One way is to [plot it in 3D](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5968/12), extract the 3D curve (`Cases`), and drop one of the coordinates out of the three.

Comment: Another way is to plug in a value for `c`, [then solve the system for `{x,y}`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/275/12) numerically. There may be more than one solution. Do this for many values of `c` and connect the dots.  These suggestions are of course starting points.  What you are asking for is definitely doable, but definitely not trivial.  Good question.

Comment: @Szabolcs, How can I use `Cases` to drop the third coordinate?

Comment: As @Feyre suggests, an example would give people something concrete to work on.

Comment: @ChrisK, the problem is that the expressions for $g$  and $f$ are too long and complicated to be added here.

Comment: @MrDi can you make a minimal example that captures the essence of your real problem?

Comment: @ChrisK, I have added an example below my question.

Comment: Next time please add the example as Mathematica code.

Answer (score 4):

As suggested by Szabolcs in the comments:

```
f[x_, y_, c_] := c (c^3 - c x^2 + Log[c] + 2 (x - 1)^2) - (c - 1)^2 y^2;
g[x_, y_, c_] := 2 (-c (x^2 + y^2 - 1) + 2 Sin[c]^3 + (x - 1)^2 + y^2);

cp3 = ContourPlot3D[{f[x, y, c] == 0, g[x, y, c] == 0}, 
  {x, 0, 4}, {y, -5, 5}, {c, 0, 2}, ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.6], 
  Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 0, 
  BoundaryStyle -> {1 -> None, 2 -> None, {1, 2} -> Directive[Thick, Red]}]
```

[image]

```
Graphics[{Thick, ColorData[1, 1], 
  Cases[Normal@cp3, Line[ps_] :> Line[Most /@ ps], Infinity]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {-5, 5}}, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

This method does requires you to know the range of $c$ where the solutions may be found -- in this case, after some experimentation I took $c \in [0, 2]$. If you need to consider an unbounded range, you could define $\theta=\tan^{-1}c$ and plot $f(x,y,\tan\theta)=0$, $g(x,y,\tan\theta)=0$ over the range $\theta\in(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$.

Comment: In retrospect, I've answered this kind of question [before](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29789/484)...

Comment: Why does the solution take too long for some functions of $f$ and $g$?

Comment: MrDi: Probably because some functions $f$ and $g$ are expensive to evaluate? It has to perform $O(n^3)$ function evaluations, where $n$ is the value of `PlotPoints`.

Comment: Is there a different quicker method?

Comment: You can try reducing `PlotPoints`. Though that's not "a different quicker method", just the same method with lower quality.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach using some functions for tracking roots I [hacked together previously](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/104694/6358).

First, load the function `TrackRootPAL` defined [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/104694/6358).  Then, define your functions:

```
f[x_, y_, c_] := c (c^3 - c x^2 + Log[c] + 2 (x - 1)^2) - (c - 1)^2 y^2;
g[x_, y_, c_] := 2 (-c (x^2 + y^2 - 1) + 2 Sin[c]^3 + (x - 1)^2 + y^2);
```

Make a `ContourPlot` to get some idea where to start:

```
c = 0.5;
ContourPlot[{f[x, y, c] == 0, g[x, y, c] == 0}, {x, -2, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Looks like there are two roots.  Use `FindRoot` to find one of them:

```
init = FindRoot[{f[x, y, c] == 0, g[x, y, c] == 0}, {x, 2.5}, {y, 0.75}]
(* {x -> 2.3209, y -> 0.675456} *)
```

Now use `TrackRootPAL` to continue this root as a function of your parameter `c`:

```
Clear[c];
tr = TrackRootPAL[{f[x, y, c], g[x, y, c]}, {x, y}, {c, 0.4, 1}, 0.5, {x, y} /. init, NDSolveOpts -> {AccuracyGoal -> 6}]
```

This gives two solutions (one for each root) as pairs of `InterpolatingFunction`s, which you can `ParametricPlot`:

```
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[c], y[c]} /. tr], {c, 0.4, 1}, PlotRange -> {{-2, 5}, {-5, 5}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I used `TrackRootPAL` because it can go around corners to track both roots.  Hope this helps for your real problem.

Comment: What is `TrackRootPAL`? I am not sure it is defined in my Mathematica?

Comment: First, load the function `TrackRootPAL` defined [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/104694/6358)

Comment: I am sorry if this is a stupid question but how do you load a function? Do you just copy and paste the code?

Comment: Yes, that's all.

Comment: I am getting this error `ReplaceAll::reps: {init} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing.`

Comment: Did you run all the code in my answer step-by-step?  `init` is defined there

Comment: In your answer there  seems to be two big blocks of code with an example under each one. Which block of code do I need?

Comment: There seems too be a problem because only the first example in your answer works.

Comment: I am getting these errors `NDSolve::deqn: "\!\(\*
StyleBox[\"\\\"Equation or list of equations expected instead of \\\"\", \"MT\"]\)\!\(\* StyleBox[\"When\", \"MT\"]\)\!\(\* StyleBox[\"\"\", \"MT\"]\)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48394/discussion-between-chris-k-and-mrdi).

Comment: Did you read my message on chat?