# Projecting curves of intersection onto a plane

Tags: plotting

Referring to this page,

[Plotting implicitly-defined space curves](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5968/plotting-implicitly-defined-space-curves)

How can I project the curves of intersection onto the x-y plane?

Comment: This kind of questions usually receives much more attention if you show that you've tried _something_ before asking. Post some code ...

Comment: Add `ViewPoint -> {0, 0, \[Infinity]}, ViewVertical -> {0, 1, 
  0}, Ticks -> {True, True, None}`, I suppose it is a duplicate but I can't find a good link :). Also, maybe it is not, you want 3D or 2D plot as an output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same as David Park's answer but with 2D output

```
cp3d = ContourPlot3D[(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 8)^2 == 
    36 (x^2 + y^2), {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, {z, -2, 2}, 
   MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z}, y^2 + (z - 2)^2 - 4]}, 
   Mesh -> {{0}}, ContourStyle -> None, PlotPoints -> 30, 
   BoxRatios -> Automatic];

Graphics[Cases[cp3d, GraphicsComplex[p___, OptionsPattern[]] :> 
   (GraphicsComplex[p] /. {x_Real, y_Real, z_Real} :> {x, y})], Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using the example from [Plotting implicitly-defined space curves](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5969/5549)

```
ContourPlot3D[(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 8)^2 == 36 (x^2 + y^2), {x, -4, 
   4}, {y, -4, 4}, {z, -2, 2}, 
  MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z}, y^2 + (z - 2)^2 - 4]}, 
  Mesh -> {{0}}, ContourStyle -> None, PlotPoints -> 30, 
  BoxRatios -> Automatic] /. {x_Real, y_Real, z_Real} -> {x, y, 0}
```

[image]