# Trace of intersecting planes

Tags: plotting, intersection

I have a set of curved planes that intersect each other. I only want all the parts of all planes displayed that are above the intersecting traces. Further, I would like to highlight the intersecting traces. It sounds like a simple enough problem (maybe it is), but I couldn't finde any routine to do this. So, any help is welcome.
Here is an example:

```
    inputData = {
       {{0, .5, .5, 1200}, {0, 1, 0, 1500}, {.5, .5, 0, 1150}, {1/3, 1/3, 
         1/3, 1100}}
       , {{0, 0, 0, 1650}, {0, .5, .5, 1200}, {1/3, 1/3, 1/3, 1100}, {.5, 
         0, .5, 1300}}
       , {{1, 0, 0, 1650}, {1/3, 1/3, 1/3, 1100}, {.5, 0, .5, 
         1300}, {.5, .5, 0, 1150}}
       };

coords[{A_, B_, C_}] := {A/2 + B, A Tan[Pi/3]/2};
newCoordinates[data_] := Table[
   Join[coords[{data[[i, #, 1]], data[[i, #, 2]], 
        data[[i, #, 3]]}], {data[[i, #, 4]]}] & /@ 
    Range@Length@data[[i]]
   , {i, 1, Length[inputData]}
   ];
    data = newCoordinates[inputData];
    quad = Fit[data[[#]], {1, x, y, x^2, x y, y^2}, {x, y}] & /@ 
       Range@Length@data;

    Plot3D[quad, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}
     , MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}
     , RegionFunction -> 
      Function[{x, y, z}, 
       0 < Sqrt[3] x - y && 1.72 > Sqrt[3] x + y && z > 1100]
     , PlotStyle -> {Directive[Orange, Opacity[.5]], 
       Directive[Green, Opacity[.5]]}
     , PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 2000}}
     , BoundaryStyle -> Thick
     , BoxRatios -> {1.2, 1.2, 2}
     , Boxed -> False
     , Axes -> None
     , ImageSize -> 500
     ]
```

Comment: Adding a definition of your `newCoordinates` function might help.

Comment: My apologies! I added the required definitions. This are to make a ternary plot.

Comment: Do you really mean (flat) planes? These seem to be quadrics. Which is fine, just a bit confusing.

Comment: You are right, I mean curved planes. I now state this differently in the question.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5972/5

Comment: Thanks - I've seen this and wasn't sure it really is what I am looking for. But I'll study this again. Maybe I thought there would be a simpler solution.

Comment: @rm -rf I may be misunderstanding this query but I don't think it's a duplicate of that intersection curve question. This appears to ask how to "block" parts of the surfaces that fail certain inequalities. If so, one approach might be via `Boole`. I've not had time to try that out as yet, and anyway there are many other MSE people who can do that better than me.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Yes, you're right. I just went by the title and that they wanted to highlight the intersection, but I missed that there was more to the question. I'll leave the link up since it's somewhat related, but I'll remove the "duplicate" part of my comment. Thanks :)

Comment: This may do what you want.`Plot3D[Evaluate[
  Map[Piecewise[{{#, # >= Apply[Max, quad]}}] &, quad]], {x, 0, 
  1}, {y, 0, 1}, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, 
 RegionFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, z}, 
   0 < Sqrt[3] x - y && 1.72 > Sqrt[3] x + y && z > 1100], 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[Orange, Opacity[.5]], 
   Directive[Green, Opacity[.5]]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 2000}}, BoundaryStyle -> Thick, 
 BoxRatios -> {1.2, 1.2, 2}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> None, 
 ImageSize -> 500]`

Comment: @Daniel – looks great! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

*(This is [Daniel's answer from comments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39896/trace-of-intersecting-planes#comment119596_39896); it is interesting, it answers OP's question, and it generates pretty graphics, so it seems worth preserving)*

---

```
Plot3D[
 quad, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1},
 MeshFunctions -> {#3 &},
 RegionFunction ->
   Function[{x, y, z}, 0 < Sqrt[3] x - y && 1.72 > Sqrt[3] x + y && z > 1100],
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[Orange, Opacity[.5]], Directive[Green, Opacity[.5]]},
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 2000}},
 BoundaryStyle -> Thick, BoxRatios -> {1.2, 1.2, 2},
 Boxed -> False, Axes -> None, ImageSize -> 500
]
```

[image]

```
Plot3D[
 Evaluate[Map[Piecewise[{{#, # >= Apply[Max, quad]}}] &, quad]],
 {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1},
 MeshFunctions -> {#3 &},
 RegionFunction ->
   Function[{x, y, z}, 0 < Sqrt[3] x - y && 1.72 > Sqrt[3] x + y && z > 1100],
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[Orange, Opacity[.5]], Directive[Green, Opacity[.5]]},
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 2000}},
 BoundaryStyle -> Thick, BoxRatios -> {1.2, 1.2, 2},
 Boxed -> False, Axes -> None, ImageSize -> 500
]
```

[image]