# Find arc length

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I am trying to find the arc length for

[image]

using

```
n = 2; f[x_] := -2 Re[ExpIntegralEi[(ZetaZero[n]) Log[x]]] Log[x]/ Sqrt[x]
a = Quiet[FindMinimum[f[x], {x, 1.4}]];
b = Quiet[FindMaximum[f[x], {x, 1.7}]];
Plot[f[x], {x, (x /. a[[2]]) - 0.1, (x /. b[[2]]) + 0.1}, 
Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Medium], Point[{{x /. a[[2]], a[[1]]},
{x /. b[[2]], b[[1]]}}]}, ImageSize -> 300]

arc = NIntegrate[ Sqrt[1 + D[f[x], x]^2], {x, (x /. a[[2]]), (x /. b[[2]])}]
```

Am I doing something silly?

Comment: Maybe [ArcLength](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArcLength.html?q=ArcLength)

Comment: @Chenminqi,  I Googled "Mathematica arc length" but only ArcLengthFactor came up!! :/

Comment: FYI ArcLength: Introduced in 2014 (10.0)

Comment: @george2079, thanks - that was good timing then ;)

Comment: If you define `f` sans `Re[]`, and then use `Re[]` on the max, min, plot, and `NIntegrate`, they will all work. As it stands, `D` has trouble with the `Re` because it is not an analytic function.

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau, yes that works - thanks :)

Comment: Strongly related Wolfram Community thread: "[Computing arch length of a spline curve](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/29463)."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on @RunnyKine's comment the trouble is with `Re`.  It seems there should be a more elegant way to do this, but moving the `Re` outside the differential does the job:

```
 da[x_] = Sqrt[1 +
     (Re@D[(-2 (ExpIntegralEi[(ZetaZero[n]) Log[x]]) Log[x]/Sqrt[x]),x])^2  ]
 NIntegrate[da[x], {x, x /. a[[2]], x /. b[[2]]}]
```

> .308277

Also, yet another line measure approach:

```
 Total[Norm /@ 
     Differences@
          Table[{x, f[x]}, {x, (x /. a[[2]]), (x /. b[[2]]), .0001}]]
```

> 0.308216

Comment: Great - should have thought of that ! Thanks - should be a little more accurate :)

Answer (score 4):

If you just plot the region of the graph you're interested in:

```
pl = Plot[f[x], {x, (x /. a[[2]]), (x /. b[[2]])}, 
  Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Medium], Point[{{x /. a[[2]], a[[1]]}, {x /. b[[2]], b[[1]]}}]}, 
  ImageSize -> 300, PlotPoints -> 500]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Then, you can do:

```
ArcLength @ DiscretizeGraphics @ pl
```

> 0.30827679

Comment: great - thank you :) I searched for "Mathematica arc length" but only `ArcLengthFactor` came up! ... Any ideas why direct integration won't work? Am I missing something silly?

Comment: @martin, let me look into that.

Comment: @martin, if you evaluate `D[f[x], x]` by itself, you'll see where the problem is. You have a derivative of `Re` term left in there and I don't think *Mathematica* knows what to do with that.

Comment: Ah great - OK, thanks!

Comment: Cute, but how accurate is this? Does it just count pixels? If so, there are only two digits one can really trust. (I don't know what the OP is looking for, but I usually want more than two digits from my computations).

Comment: @IgorRivin I wouldn't recommend this method since it produces quite large errors, see two highest score answers to this question [Finding length of intersection of two surfaces](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58768/finding-length-of-intersection-of-two-surfaces).

Comment: @Artes that was `DiscretizeRegion` with `ImplicitRegion` and if you scroll down in the link you provided and look at the answer using `DiscretizeGraphics` you'll realize that the error does not apply here.

Comment: @IgorRivin, the answer to your question is no, it doesn't just count pixels.

Comment: @RunnyKine Nevermind, I wouldn't worry if one provided  traditional numerical results.

Comment: You can specify `PlotPoints->some big number` if you are concerned about the accuracy

Comment: @george2079, nice suggestion. I added that.

Answer (score 3):

Or Create an interpolation function from the plot and calculate its arc length. Note that I have modified the definitions of a and b.

```
n = 2; f[x_] := -2 Re[ExpIntegralEi[(ZetaZero[n]) Log[x]]] Log[x]/Sqrt[x]
a = FindArgMin[f[x], {x, 1.4}][[1]] // Quiet;
b = FindArgMax[f[x], {x, 1.7}][[1]] // Quiet;

plt = Plot[f[x], {x, a, b}];

f2 = Interpolation[
   Cases[plt, Line[pts_] :> pts, Infinity][[1]]];

arc = NIntegrate[Sqrt[1 + f2'[x]^2], {x, a, b}]
```

> 0.308277

Comment: Thanks for the solution - will give it a go in a bit :)

Answer (score 1):

In general, one may find the arc length of a graph of `f[x]` with `ArcLength[{x, f[x]}, {x, a, b}]` since V10.0, although its robustness improves (hopefully) with age.  In this case, the difficulty is `Re[]` in `f[x]`, and `Re[z]` is not a differentiable function of a complex variable. However, `Re[g[x]]` can be a differentiable function of a real variable `x`. The next problem is that `ComplexExpand` does not work in this case, as recommended in the documentation for `Re` (see "Possible Issues"). Thus, I am thrown back onto basic principles, namely, use the definition of the derivative, which will be found defining `fp[x]` below. Now we have to get `ArcLength` to use it.  To do this, we need to prevent `f[x]` from evaluating. It would be nice if it were defined as `f[x_?NumericQ]`; however, while that's convenient for this purpose, it is often inconvenient for other purposes.  But we can easily temporarily redefine `f[]` this way as done below, while also defining the derivative of `f[x]`. (The limit could be done inside `Block`; but (1) I wanted to show the result and (2) since it takes so long, it's nice to do it once and save the result. Actually, the result is partially cached, so recomputing gets faster.)

```
fp[x_] = (* takes 13+ sec. *)
 Limit[(f[x + h] - f[x])/h, h -> 0, Assumptions -> x > 0] // 
  FullSimplify
(*
x^(-(3/2) - ZetaZero[2]) *
  (-x - x^(2 ZetaZero[2]) + 
   x^ZetaZero[2] (-2 + Log[x]) Re[ExpIntegralEi[Log[x] ZetaZero[2]]])
*)

Block[{f, y = f[x]},
 f /: HoldPattern[D[f[x], x]] = fp[x];
 f[x_?NumericQ] = y;
 ArcLength[{x, f[x]}, {x, (x /. a[[2]]), (x /. b[[2]])}]
 ]

(*  0.308277  *)
```