# Integration over a (non-parametric) curve defined by indicator function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, regions, piecewise

I want to integrate the real function `myFun` defined on a 2D plane over the line `locus`, defined as the solution of a set of equality and inequalities. For instance, let's define

```
myFun[x_,y_]:= Exp[-(x^2+y^2)]/\[Pi]
locus[x_,y_]:= x>0 && y==0
```

This is just a simplified version of the general problem, in general we may not be able to esplicitate the line `locus` in a parametric form (and solve the integral, as in this case, with an appropriate substitution). Consider we can find it implicitly as the intersection of a region (defined by inequalities) with an equality (as given above).

How do I integrate `myFun` over the set `locus`? It should be something like

```
Integrate[
 Exp[-(x^2 + 
       y^2)]/\[Pi] Ind[x,y], {x, -\[Infinity], +\[Infinity]}, {y, \
-\[Infinity], +\[Infinity]}]
```

with `Ind[x,y]` an indicator function which restrict the integration on the correct set. This function probably involves Boole and DiracDelta function. For example, in this case it works

```
Integrate[
 Integrate[
  Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)] Boole[
    x > 0] DiracDelta[
     y]/\[Pi], {y, -\[Infinity], +\[Infinity]}], {x, -\[Infinity], +\
\[Infinity]}]
```

but it is just because we could "solve" the line `locus`. (NOTE the order of the variable - if swapped it does not work.)

But what about the general case? For example, what if the 2D plane is the complex plane and I have the (not necessarily straight) line

```
locus[x_,y_]:= Re[(x + I y)^2+(3 + I 5)]>0 && Im[(x + I y)^2+(3 + I 5)]==0
```

Comment: In version 10 you can integrate over a region. Have a look at `ImplicitRegion`.

Comment: I see that
Integrate[
 Exp[-(Abs[z]^2)]/\[Pi], {z} \[Element] 
  ImplicitRegion[Re[z] > 0 && Im[z] == 0, {z}]]
works, but not 
Integrate[
 Exp[-(Abs[z]^2)]/\[Pi], {z} \[Element] 
  ImplicitRegion[
   Re[(3 + I 5) z^2] > 0 && Im[(3 + I 5) z^2] == 0, {z}]]
Any hint?

Comment: In principle this question is a duplicate of [Finding length of intersection of two surfaces](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58768/finding-length-of-intersection-of-two-surfaces)

Comment: I really don't get it why 

Integrate[
 Exp[-(Abs[z]^2)]/\[Pi], {z} \[Element] 
  ImplicitRegion[Re[(3 + I 5) + z] > 0 && Im[(3 + I 5) + z] == 0, z]]

can't be solved.

Comment: A first comment is that `ImplicitRegion` expects real variables.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. If I define `myFun[z_] := Exp[-(Abs[z]^2)]/\[Pi]` and
`locus[z_] := Re[z + (3 + I 5)] > 0 && Im[z + (3 + I 5)] == 0`, using `Integrate[myFun[x + I y], {x, y} \[Element] ImplicitRegion[locus[x + I y] && x \[Element] Reals && y \[Element] Reals, {x, y}]]` it works. However, if I define `locus[z_] := Re[z^2 (3 + I 5)] > 0 && Im[z^2 (3 + I 5)] == 0` then integral is not solved, but I can't understand why.

Answer (score 1):

Your second example is still simple enough :

```
Reduce[(3 + x^2 - y^2 > 0) && (5 + 2 x y == 0), {x, y}, Reals] // ToRadicals
(* (x < -Sqrt[-(3/2) + Sqrt[17/2]] || x > Sqrt[-(3/2) + Sqrt[17/2]]) && y == -(5/(2 x)) *)
```

therefore the integral is

```
Integrate[myFun[x, -(5/(2 x))], {x, -Infinity, -Sqrt[-(3/2) + Sqrt[17/2]]}] +
Integrate[myFun[x, -(5/(2 x))], {x, Sqrt[-(3/2) + Sqrt[17/2]], Infinity}]
(* (1 + Erf[Sqrt[-5 + Sqrt[34]]] + E^10 Erfc[Sqrt[5 + Sqrt[34]]])/(2 E^5 Sqrt[\[Pi]]) *)
```

Comment: I appreciate the help, but the point is to not solve locus, but to put it implicicly. Locus and myFun are just MWE.

Answer (score 1):

One needs to use `ComplexExpand` to constrain the variables x,y to be Real in the expression of `locus[x+I y]`  -- for some unknown reasons the conditions `&& x \[Element] Reals && y \[Element] Reals` are not enough.

Here's the final code

```
myFun[z_] := Exp[-(Abs[z]^2)]/\[Pi]
locus[z_] := Re[z^2 (3 + I 5)] > 0 && Im[z^2 (3 + I 5)] == 0
Integrate[myFun[x + I y], {x, y} \[Element] ImplicitRegion[ComplexExpand[locus[x + I y]], {x, y}]]
```