# ContourPlot of an ImplicitRegion defined by the intersecton of equality and inequality

Tags: plotting, regions

I want to plot a line defined IMPLICITLY by the intersection of an equality and an inequality, i.e. a line that you can't easily simplify (and therefore take advantage of its form). Consider for instance the simple example

```
R=x > 0 && y == -((5 x)/3)
```

but assume you don't know which equalities and inequalities it involves (although you know it's a line and not a 2D region).

How can I plot the set R? I can't use RegionPlot as it only consider regions defined by inequalities, but at the same time ContourPlot

```
ContourPlot[R, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

does not work.

I know there is the function `ImplicitRegion`, but

```
ContourPlot[ImplicitRegion[R, {x, y}], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

does not work either.

I repeat, do not take advantage of the expressions in R - if you could a solution is to use `ContourPlot` with `RegionFunction`.

PS this question is related to [Integration over a (non-parametric) curve defined by indicator function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64207/integration-over-a-non-parametric-curve-defined-by-indicator-function?noredirect=1#comment180120_64207)

Comment: Is `RegionPlot` useful ?

Comment: No, RegionPlot allows only to plot sets defined only by inequalities.

Comment: `RegionPlot`+`ImplicitRegion` works for me. http://i.stack.imgur.com/e4C9m.png

Comment: Well, I'm surprised. 

`RegionPlot[R, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}]` 

works, but 

`RegionPlot[R, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]` 

doesn't. Any idea why?

Comment: @rhermans  I disagree with the close votes. Just because there is a simple answer does not mean it is a simple mistake.  I mean my first thought was why doesn't `ContourPlot` work here.  Before the region functionality of V10, `RegionPlot` would have failed miserably on such a problem.  To satisfy the OP's constraint is difficult with `ContourPlot`.

Comment: @MichaelE2, Touché, may be I'm failing to see how `ContourPlot` could be the correct tool to display a region considering that `RegionPlot` exists. I'm still not sure what should be done here, but I guess it's better to err in the safe side. Vote retracted.

Comment: @rhermans The region is, in fact, a contour.   But the way *Mathematica* works makes `RegionPlot` the best approach.   It seems to me that if one looks at an object as a contour, one would naturally consider `ContourPlot`. If other plotters work with regions, why not `ContourPlot`?  (It's not a ground-breaking question to be sure, but I think it passes muster.)  Thanks, in any case.

Answer (score 3):

### Answer

```
RegionPlot[ImplicitRegion[R, {x, y}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Documentation

[`ImplicitRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImplicitRegion.html)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[`RegionPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionPlot.html)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

This can easily be done with `ContourPlot`: you have an equality and an inequality.  Put the equality as the argument to `ContourPlot` and the inequality as the value of the option `RegionFunction`

```
ContourPlot[y == -((5 x)/3), {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 RegionFunction -> (#1 > 0 &)]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[Rahul's comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64297/contourplot-of-an-implicitregion-defined-by-the-intersecton-of-equality-and-ineq#comment180354_64297) is the way to do it with `ImplicitRegion` directly, since `RegionPlot` is the plotter to use with regions.  If a solution in terms of `ContourPlot` is desired, then a numeric function (or an equivalent equation) describing the region will be needed.

Here is one way to go from `ImplicitRegion` to `ContourPlot`.

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[x > 0 && y == -((5 x)/3), {x, y}];
ysol = Solve[RegionMember[reg, {x, y}], y];
ContourPlot[y == (y /. ysol), {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

There are two obvious limitations: (1) The limitations of `Solve`, which are more than sufficient for the present task.  (2) The the variable to be solved for, `y` or `x`, needs to be chosen appropriately in the case of a horizontal or vertical line.

What's going on is that `Solve` returns a [`ConditionalExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConditionalExpression.html)
that is undefined when `x <= 0`:

```
ysol = Solve[RegionMember[reg, {x, y}], y]
(*  {{y -> ConditionalExpression[-((5 x)/3), x > 0]}}  *)
```