# RegionPlot with PlotRange vs RegionPlot with domain

Tags: plotting, regions

Consider you want to plot `R = ImplicitRegion[x > 0 && y == -((5 x)/3), {x, y}];`

In [ContourPlot of an ImplicitRegion defined by the intersecton of equality and inequality](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64297/contourplot-of-an-implicitregion-defined-by-the-intersecton-of-equality-and-ineq?noredirect=1#comment180354_64297), it turns out that

```
RegionPlot[R, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}]
```

and

```
RegionPlot[R, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]
```

behave differently, and in particular the former works while the latter does not, giving the error

```
ImplicitRegion::bcond: "ImplicitRegion[x>0&&y==-((5\x)/3),{x,y}] should be a Boolean combination of equations, inequalities, and Element statements."
```

Any idea on the reason? In particular, the documentation reports the latter as the correct syntax to use (and the former as an optional form) so I would expect it to work.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation for `RegionPlot` in V10 has not been updated properly. It omits a new argument pattern now accepted by `RegionPlot`. That argument pattern is

```
RegionPlot[region, options]
```

The new pattern *is* documented under `ImplicitRegion` and `ParametricRegion`.

So two ways to get a region plot of the region under the line `y == -[5/3) x` and to right of the y-axis are

```
 RegionPlot[x > 0 && y < -(5/3) x, {x, 0, 200}, {y, -333, 0}]
```

and

```
RegionPlot[ImplicitRegion[x > 0 && y < -(5/3) x, {x, y}]]
```

Both return a plot that appears as follows:

[image: plot]

The form

```
RegionPlot[ImplicitRegion[x > 0 && y < -(5/3) x, {x, y}], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]
```

does not match the new argument pattern nor the old one, so you get an error message.

## Edit

This additional information is supplied to answer issues raised by the OP in a comment below.

- To see an example where the new pattern is used, look at the 1st example given under Basic Examples under [`ImplicitRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImplicitRegion.html).
- I chose the region defined by `x > 0 && y < -(5/3) x` because it has non-zero measure and will be visible in both forms of `RegionPlot`. As the documentation says under Details in[`RegionPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RegionPlot.html),

> `RegionPlot` can in general only find regions of positive measure; it cannot find regions that are just lines or points.

This does not seem to apply to the new form, but it certainly applies to the older form.

Comment: I can't find the new pattern neither on the documentation of `ImplicitRegion` nor in that of `ParametricRegion`. Which documentation are you referring? Also, you plotted the wrong region. With `x > 0 && y == -((5 x)/3)` I got a blank plot with `RegionPlot[x > 0 && y == -((5 x)/3), {x, 0, 200}, {y, -333, 0}]` -- but no errors