# Bug in ArcLength?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs, computational-geometry, geometry

fixed in **10.1** (windows)

---

With Mathematica 10.0.2:

```
ArcLength[Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {2, 0}}]]
ArcLength[Line[{{0}, {1}, {2}}]]
(* 2 *)
(* 2 *)
```

However,

```
ArcLength[Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {2.0, 0}}]]
ArcLength[Line[{{0}, {1}, {2.0}}]]
(* 1. *)
(* 1. *)
```

Comment: Certainly looks like a bug, especially since ArcLength[{{0.0},{1},{2}}] = 2.

Comment: And `ArcLength[Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {2.000001, 0}}]]` is back to 2. again...

Comment: Confirmed on 10.0.1 on Windows 7(64). This is quite horrible.

Comment: There are another problems with new geometric measure capabilities, read carefully e.g. answers to this question [Finding length of intersection of two surfaces](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58768/finding-length-of-intersection-of-two-surfaces). The anser by RunnyKine had involved a wrong result before a few edits.

Comment: The bug is actually in `RegionMeasure`. Try `RegionMeasure[Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {2., 0}}], 1]` and `RegionMeasure[Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {2, 0}}], 1]`

Comment: Has this been reported to support@wolfram.com?

Answer (score 15):

Yes, this is a bug in the more general function `RegionMeasure`.  I knew there were some edge cases in the handling of inexact numerics, but I was unaware of such a simple example.  I will forward this bug internally.

Workarounds include using the parametric (2-argument) form of `ArcLength`, and using `DiscretizeRegion` to pre-process regions before sending them to `ArcLength/RegionMeausure`:

```
In[21]:= ArcLength[DiscretizeRegion@Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {2.0, 0}}]]

Out[21]= 2.

In[22]:= ArcLength[DiscretizeRegion@Line[{{0}, {1}, {2.0}}]]

Out[22]= 2.
```

Comment: This seems to be an issue with any `Line` composed of collinear segments and having inexact numbers for coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

bug fixed in **10.1** (windows)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

[image: Mathematica graphics]

code

```
ArcLength[Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {2, 0}}]]
ArcLength[Line[{{0}, {1}, {2}}]]
ArcLength[Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {2.0, 0}}]]
ArcLength[Line[{{0}, {1}, {2.0}}]]
```