# Implicit region misses subset?

Tags: numerical-integration, geometry

**Context**

> I am interested in integrating a 2D function over lines defined implicitely

**Attempt**

Let me just start by integrating the identify on such sets of lines which 
a defined using [`ImplicitRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ImplicitRegion.html)

```
cond1 = ImplicitRegion[
  And @@ {Sin[ Pi x y] == 0, -2 < x <= 2, -2 <= y <= 2}, {x, y}]
dcond1 = DiscretizeRegion[cond1]
NIntegrate[1, {x, y} ∈ dcond1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

(* 24.9439 *)

Now clearly the implicit region is missing a small branch.
We can check this using a different setup involving [`DiscretizeGraphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DiscretizeGraphics.html):

```
tt = ContourPlot[Sin[Pi x y ] == 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
   Frame -> False, ContourShading -> False] // DiscretizeGraphics
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ArcLength[tt]
```

(* 25.6601 *)

**QUESTION**

Is this a bug? Would you know of a workaround (given that in the end I do not want to
integrate the identity but a known function over these lines)?

**UPDATE**

It is a bug which has disappeared in 10.0.2

Comment: See closely related problem [Finding length of intersection of two surfaces](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58768/finding-length-of-intersection-of-two-surfaces). See the edits of the most upvoted answer, it involved initially a bug, then I haven't checked it but it seems to be correct. Nevertheless it is in general a wrong idea to use approximate methods when symbolic approach is available (e.g. my answer to that question).

Comment: @Artes thanks for the comment. Would you agree that it is a bug though? (my real problem does not involve symbolic expressions)

Comment: Of course there must be a bug in those new capabilities of _Mathematica 10_, nonetheless you can exploit  another solutions to that question yielding correct results.

Comment: What version of Mathematica are you using on what platform?  With 64-bit 10.0.2 on OS X [I don't see the problem](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8qkdx.png).  Before trying this out I was going to say that I would be cautious about calling this a bug.  While the result is clearly wrong, it's likely wrong due to the fact that all numerical methods used for these sorts of calculations rely on heuristics: they are not guaranteed to give perfect results.  `ContourPlot` will miss pieces of curves very often, and when it doesn't miss them, if often cuts/smoothers sharp corners.  This is expected.

Comment: At the same time usually there are options that can be changed to get a more precise discretization.  I was going to try to find out how to do this, but then surprisingly I didn't see the problem on my machine.  I'm curious if this is due to a version difference (many problems fixed in 10.0.2) or due to slightly different numerical errors on different platforms/CPUs.  Also, while I wouldn't call it a bug, it might still be worth reporting to give the developers a chance to improve the reliability of the discretization algorithms.

Comment: I use  64-bit 10.0.1 on OS X

Comment: @chris Why don't you upgrade to 10.0.2 then?

Comment: I did and it worked :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that in fact [`DiscretizeGraphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DiscretizeGraphics.html) returns directly a region object,
so I can do

```
tt = ContourPlot[Sin[Pi x y ] == 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
Frame -> False, ContourShading -> False] // DiscretizeGraphics
```

then

```
NIntegrate[1, {x, y} ∈ tt]
```

(* 25.6601 *)

or more generally,

```
NIntegrate[x^2 y, {x, y} ∈ tt]
```

Pretty nifty!

So one could define a function

```
NImplicitRegion[cond, rg__] :=
 Module[{tt},
  tt = ContourPlot[cond, rg, Frame -> False, 
    ContourShading -> False];
  DiscretizeGraphics[tt]]
```

so that e.g.

```
NImplicitRegion[Cos[x y] == 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

returns

[image: Mathematica graphics]