# How to plot the graph of the equation F[x,y]=0 if y is real number, x is complex?

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, complex

I have an equation F(x,y;a,b,c,...)=0, where x and y are variables, a,b,c,... - parameters. y is a real number, x - complex. For every given y I need to solve this equation, i.e. to find Im(x) and Re(x) (this equation may have many solutions). After solving this equation I need to plot two graphs: the dependense of y from Im(x) and y from Re(x).

For example, F(x,y)=x^2 + sin(xy).

If y and x were real numbers, it would be possible to use ContourPlot. However, as my variables are complex, I have to solve this equation numerically and after that plot my graphs.

I have never come across such a problem, so could anyone tell me how to solve it?

Comment: `Solve`, `FindRoot` ? Post the code you have written so far.

Comment: Thanks. My code is too long, but I can explain. I tried to solve this problem in other way using ContourPlot: Manipulate[ContourPlot[Re[F(x,y,a,b)]==0,{x,0,5},{y,0,5}],{a,0,1},{b,0,1}] (or Im[F]). However, eventually I have realised that the unswer is wrong and, moreover, the calculations are too long and are not accurate at all. I understand how I should solve this problem (as I described above), but I have never done such things before, so I need advice.

Comment: Are you sure you know your way around *Mathematica* enough to tackle this problem ?

Comment: I am not sure, that's why I have decided to ask.

Comment: I suggest you open up the documentation and read how to define functions, call them, pass different arguments, etc.

Comment: Make the substitution `x = x1 + I * x2` and solve for real `x1` and `x2`. Of course, very soon you will have too many dimensions to plot on a flat computer screen :-) If you can obtain an analytical solution, try using `Plot3D` with `y` as a function of `x1` and `x2`.

Comment: Also on [Wolfram Community](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/479422?p_p_auth=kFbq33AD)

Answer (score 3):

### New way

The OP mentioned `ContourPlot` but its behavior is V10 makes my original solution practically unusable except for a very rough plot.  Another approach is to solve the equation for all the roots in a given region.  From the `ContourPlot`, one can see there are two types, ones that cross `y == -5` and ones that cross `y == 5`.  We can use `NDSolve` to solve the equation by first differentiating it (`ode`) and then integrating it (`sols[y0]`) using the intersections with the two planes as initial conditions (`ics[y0]`).  This approach gives us one of the solutions twice, but we can delete by comparing values of `x[y]` at `y == -5`.  This approach is much quicker and produces nice, differentiable, and accurate solutions.

```
eqn = x^2 + Sin[x y] == 0
ode = D[eqn /. x -> x[y], y]
(*
  x^2 + Sin[x y] == 0
  2 x[y] Derivative[1][x][y] + Cos[y x[y]] (x[y] + y Derivative[1][x][y]) == 0
*)

xmin = -5 - 5 I;
xmax = 5 + 5 I;
ymin = -5;
ymax = 5;

ics[y0_] := NSolve[eqn && Re[xmin] <= Re[x] <= Re[xmax] && 
     Im[xmin] <= Im[x] <= Im[xmax] /. y -> y0, x];

Clear[sols];
sols[y0_] := sols[y0] = Quiet[
   First@NDSolve[{ode, x[y0] == (x /. #), 
        WhenEvent[Re@x[y] < Re[xmin], "StopIntegration"], 
        WhenEvent[Re@x[y] > Re[xmax], "StopIntegration"], 
        WhenEvent[Im@x[y] < Im[xmin], "StopIntegration"],
        WhenEvent[Im@x[y] > Im[xmax], "StopIntegration"]}, 
       x, {y, ymin, ymax}] & /@ ics[y0],
   NDSolve::ndsz]

tolerance = 8;
mysols = DeleteDuplicates[Join[sols[ymin], sols[ymax]], 
   Quiet[SetPrecision[x[ymin] /. #1, tolerance] == 
      SetPrecision[x[ymin] /. #2, tolerance]] &];

Show[
 ParametricPlot3D[{y, Re@x[y], Im@x[y]} /. #, 
    Evaluate@Flatten[{y, x["Domain"] /. #}]] & /@ mysols,
 PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {y, Re[x], Im[x]}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that `tolerance` is used to determine how equal (up to what precision) two initial conditions have to be for them to be considered the same.  In this case, they're identical, but I wanted to show a more robust solution.

Note also that as far as robustness goes, we made some assumptions about where the initial points on the solutions could be found.

#### Original answer (`ContourPlot`)

Something like this, perhaps?  It's too slow for `Manipulate`, though.

```
plot = ContourPlot3D[
  {0 == Re[(x1 + I x2)^2 + Sin[(x1 + I x2) y]], 
   0 == Im[(x1 + I x2)^2 + Sin[(x1 + I x2) y]]},
 {y, -5, 5}, {x1, -5, 5}, {x2, -5, 5},
 ContourStyle -> None, Mesh -> None, MaxRecursion -> 2, 
 BoundaryStyle -> {1 -> None, 2 -> None, {1, 2} -> {{Lighter@Blue, Thick}}}, 
 AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The `BoundaryStyle` trick is from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5968/plotting-implicitly-defined-space-curves/5972#5972) by Daniel Lichtblau.

Also, it seems faster in V9 than V10 (< 80 sec. vs. > 1629 sec. with `MaxRecursion -> 1`).

---

The parts of the coordinates corresponding to `{Re[x], y}` are `{2, 1}`.  One can project the coordinates and ancillary options of `Graphics3D` to `Graphics` with the following.

```
With[{parts = {2, 1}},
 plot /.
  {GraphicsComplex[pts_, stuff__] :> GraphicsComplex[pts[[All, parts]], stuff],
   Graphics3D -> Graphics,
   HoldPattern[PlotRange -> pr_] :> (PlotRange -> pr[[parts]]),
   HoldPattern[AxesLabel -> label_] :> (AxesLabel -> label[[parts]])}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To get `{Im[x], y}`, use `parts = {3, 1}`.

Comment: Thank you @Michael for the link for the  `BoundaryStyle` trick - I have been trying to find it for several weeks now. (+1)

Comment: Thank you @Michael for this interesting idea. However, I'm not sure that this solution is appropriate for me, because you plot two graphs: Re(F[x,y]) = 0 and Im(F[x,y])=0, but I need the solution of the equation F[x,y]=0, i.e. Re(F[x,y])=0 and Im(F[x,y])=0 simultaneously. I mean, for example, I take y_1=0 and find x_1 = Im[x_1]+iRe[x_1] (maybe more solutions x_1', x_1'',...), then I take y_2=0.1 and find x_2 = Im[x_2]+iRe[x_2] (maybe also x_2',...) and so on. After that (using these numbers) I plot the dependense of y_i on Im[x_i] (also on Im[x_i'],...) and on Re[x_i] (again on Re[x_i'],...).

Comment: @Artem The plot is the intersection where the real and imaginary simultaneously vanish, i.e., where the complex value of `F[x, y]` is zero.  Remove the option `ContourStyle -> None` and you will see the two surfaces, one for `Re[F[x, y]] == 0` and one for `Im[F[x, y]] == 0`.  You can get the actual points from the plot, if you need them.

Comment: Thank you @Michael for your help. Can I further extract two 2D graphs from this 3D graph? I mean you plot F[Re[x],Im[x],y]=0, but I would like to get two projections of this graph Re[x],y and Im[x],y.

Comment: Dear Michael, thank you so much for your kind help!

Comment: @Artem You're welcome. :)

Comment: Dear @MichaelE2, may I ask you another question? I have tried to use your code for a very simple function and I have received a strange result. (* x-[Sqrt[y^2+I*y]]==0,{y,0,1}], denote Re[Sqrt[y^2+I*y]]=A and Im[Sqrt[y^2+I*y]]=B, so Re[x]=A and Im[x]=B*) 
Plot[{Re[Sqrt[y^2 + I*y]], Im[Sqrt[y^2 + I*y]]}, {y, 0, 1}]. The result which I receive using this straightforward method is essentially differet from the result I get using your code. (sorry, I don't know how to add pictures or .nb files here to demonstrate what I mean, but I can send it to you if you write your email).

Comment: [Your Plot output](http://i.stack.imgur.com/GCfa2.png) and [combined projections of the ContourPlot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OK1bo.png), for `{y, -5, 5}` and `parts = {1, 2}` and `parts = {1, 3}`.  They seem to agree.

Comment: Dear @Michael, I am sorry, this is my mistake.

Comment: Dear @MichaelE2, could you tell me what should I do in order to get "good" output? Mathematica accuratelu plots 3D graph, but backgroung of projections ir red (here is a link for this file). [link](https://yadi.sk/d/2zMyW_yCg3c5o)

Comment: And could you also suggest how can I improve the quality of the graph without changing MaxRecursion -> 1, because my computer aborts calculations when I use MaxRecursion -> 2

Comment: @Artem If you're willing to give up `ContourPlot3D` and manage a list of individual solutions, see my update.

Comment: Dear @Michael, but could you tell me what version of Mathematica do you use? The thing is that I can't use your code with my version 7 Mathematica.

Comment: @Artem I'm on V10.1.  (You might find it helpful mention you're using V7 in future questions, since a lot has changed since then.)  Instead of `WhenEvent`, you have to use the `"EventLocator"` method in V7.  Look it up in the docs for `NDSolve` or google it.  I forget the exact syntax.  You should be able to translate it.  I think the rest of it should work.

Comment: @Michael, ok, thank you!