# Using Manipulate to determine intersection of two surfaces

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

Here is what I have done thus far:

```
h = x^2 - y^2 + z;
g = z;
Manipulate[
 ContourPlot3D[{h == 0, g == k}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -4, 4}, {z, -2, 2},
  MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z}, h - g]},
  MeshStyle -> {{Thick, Blue}},
  Mesh -> {{0}},
  ContourStyle -> 
   Directive[Orange, Opacity[0.8], Specularity[White, 30]]],
 {{k, 0}, -2, 2, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

And the resulting image:

[image]

Clearly, I am doing something wrong? Any suggestions?

**Update:** I should have put `Mesh->{{k}}`.

```
h = x^2 - y^2 + z;
g = z;
Manipulate[
 ContourPlot3D[{h == 0, g == k}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -4, 4}, {z, -2, 2},
  MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z}, g - h]},
  MeshStyle -> {{Thick, Blue}},
  Mesh -> {{k}},
  ContourStyle -> 
   Directive[Orange, Opacity[0.8], Specularity[White, 30]]],
 {{k, 0}, -2, 2, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

Which works.

[image]

Comment: Do you get what you need if you used `Mesh -> None, BoundaryStyle -> {{1, 2} -> {Thick, Blue}}`?

Comment: `Mesh -> {{k}}, MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z}, z]}` ?

Comment: @Algohi: Yes, your suggestion does work, but it works because it doesn't put any mesh on g=k with this mesh function. If I were to change g=z to g=x+z, it doesn't put the mesh which is the curve of intersection. It just puts meshes at the z=k level on both contours, not where they intersect. But thanks for the help, as I learned a bit by playing with your idea.

Comment: @kguler: Your suggestion works. But where did you learn this? I went to the documentation for BoundaryStyle and there was no example of this type present. What does the `{1,2}` mean in `{{1, 2} -> {Thick, Blue}}`?

Comment: David, you can see [`(5968)`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5968/plotting-implicitly-defined-space-curves); uses the same trick, but still guler can provide more info.

Comment: David, this usage for `BoundaryStyle` is undocumented.  I must have learnt it from  Daniel's answer in the link given by @Sektor. `{1,2}` means the "boundary" between surfaces `1` and `2`.

Comment: @kguler, Just used your BoundaryStyle technique and posted a question on Mathematics Stack Exchange: [http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1315019/curve-of-intersection-of-two-surfaces](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1315019/curve-of-intersection-of-two-surfaces).