# Transforming from implicit Cartesian form to a parametric form

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, parametric-functions

#### First equation

$((1.2 x)^2 + (1.4 y)^2 - 1)^3 - (1.3 x)^2 y^3 == 0$

I wanna transform it into a parametric equation. I spent a much of a day working on it without success. The equation describes the following curve.

```
ContourPlot[
  ((1.2 x)^2 + (1.4 y)^2 - 1)^3 - (1.3 x)^2 y^3 == 0, 
  {x, -1.5, 1.5}, {y, -3/2, 3/2}, 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

I tried to use `NSolve` to get the $x(t)$ and$y(t)$:

```
NSolve[{((1.2 x)^2 + (1.4 y)^2 - 1)^3 == t, t == (1.3 x)^2 y^3}, {x, y}]
```

I get many solutions for $x$ and $y$. As we know a suitable choice of $x(t)$ will give me a unique $y(t)$ and a parametric function.

---

#### Second equation

```
fun[x, y]= 
  0.0027031 (Sin[x]^4 (Cos[x]^4 + Sin[x]^4)) + 0.0027031 Cos[x]^4 + 
  00346524 Sin[x]^4 Cos[y]^2 Sin[y]^2 + 0.034624 Sin[x]^2 Cos[x]^2
```

Actually I want to transform it into a spherical form. But I infer from the  **Application** section of [`CoordinateTransform`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoordinateTransform.en.html) that, if I can just get $x(t), y(t), z(t)$, then I can use `CoordinateTransform["Cartesian" -> "Spherical", {x[t], y[t], z[t]}]` to make the transform.

These two questions are both about transforming a function from implicit Cartesian form to a parametric form. So I thought it would be OK to ask them together in one post.

Comment: Does it have to be that particular heart curve? There are other curves that have parametrizations…

Comment: @J.M. Actually I wanna convert any curve equation to be parametrics equation.But no information is found in these aspects in net.

Answer (score 5):

Since the origin is inside, we can parametrize the curve with a rotating line.  Since a line through the origin has two points of intersection, we have to piece together the two solutions `Solve` returns.  They're in terms of `Root` objects, and unfortunately each parametrize half of the hearts (above and below the x-axis).  One has to inspect each to figure out how to piece them together.

```
eqn = ((1.2 x)^2 + (1.4 y)^2 - 1)^3 - (1.3 x)^2 y^3 == 0 // Rationalize;
sol = Solve[{eqn, Cos[t] y == Sin[t] x}, {x, y}, Reals];
Length@sol
(*  2  *)

heart = Piecewise@ Transpose@ {{x, y} /. sol, {Pi <= t <= 2 Pi, 0 <= t < Pi}};

ParametricPlot[heart, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Alternative**

We can get a single periodic polar parametrization this way. Since the equation `eqn` is

```
-(169/100) x^2 y^3 + (-1 +  (36 x^2)/25 + (49 y^2)/25  )^3 == 0
```

We can solve for `(36 x^2)/25 + (49 y^2)/25`, which is nearly the distance from the origin. (One can rescale `x` and `y`, but that is not algebraically necessary, as we shall see.)

```
{sol1} = Solve[eqn /. (36 x^2)/25 + (49 y^2)/25 -> p, p, Reals];
sol2 = sol1 /. {p -> (36 x^2)/25 + (49 y^2)/25} /. {x -> r Cos[t], y -> r Sin[t]};
sol3 = Solve[sol2 /. Rule -> Equal, r, Reals];
radius = r /. First@sol3;
heart = radius {Cos[t], Sin[t]};
```

Again there are two antipodal solutions in `sol3`, but for some reason the last one has discontinuities at `t` equal to integer multiples of `Pi/2`.

So one can plot the curve with either of the following:

```
ParametricPlot[heart, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Red]
PolarPlot[radius, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

Comment: If the OP was fine with a parametrization with `InterpolatingFunction[]` instead of something more explicit, an approach similar to [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/64923) could be done.

Comment: @J.M. Yes, I thought of that, but this trick is an old friend. It's good to get him out of the house once in a while. :)