# ParametricPlot3D etc. with parameters satisfying an implicit relation

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, parametric-functions, constraint

I need some help on plotting the curve generated by a vector,  given its three components as a function of two parameters, e.g. s1 and s2, whose range are known, and they have to satisfy a given constraint equation. Below is a simple example:

I can plot a surface of such a vector e.g. : `ParametricPlot3D[{s1, s2, s1}, {s1, 0, 2 Pi}, {s2, 0, 2 Pi}]`, which gives a plane. Now I need to add a constraint,  e.g. `Cos[s1] + Cos[s2] + Cos[s1] Cos[s2] = -1`. Then I expect the desired figure to be a curve. But I wonder how to plot this curve? Should I use the ParametricPlot3D function or what else? and how?

Please note that the above is just a simple example, and in my case, I may not be able solve for the constraint equation.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Update II:

Finally I notice that the answer by Michael is probably right, the inconsistence is due to my formulation error, so I have deleted that part. Thanks a lot for all the help!

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5968/plotting-implicitly-defined-space-curves

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to use `MeshFunctions` to plot `F[..] = 0`:

```
MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z, s1, s2},
   Cos[s1] + Cos[s2] + Cos[s1] Cos[s2] + 1]},
Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshStyle -> {Directive[Thick, Lighter@Blue]}
```

The function `F` is the mesh function

```
Function[{x, y, z, s1, s2}, Cos[s1] + Cos[s2] + Cos[s1] Cos[s2] + 1]
```

where the equation `F[..] == 0` is specified by the option `Mesh -> {{0}}`.

Here is a look at the solution, with a more complicated surface:

```
GraphicsRow[{
  (* the curve + surface *)
  ParametricPlot3D[{s1, s2, s1^2/2 - Pi s1 + Cos[2 s2]}, {s1, 0, 
    2 Pi}, {s2, 0, 2 Pi},
   MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z, s1, s2}, 
      Cos[s1] + Cos[s2] + Cos[s1] Cos[s2] + 1]},
   Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshStyle -> {Directive[Thick, Lighter@Blue]}],

  (* the curve *)
  ParametricPlot3D[{s1, s2, s1^2/2 - Pi s1 + Cos[2 s2]}, {s1, 0, 
    2 Pi}, {s2, 0, 2 Pi},
   MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z, s1, s2},
      Cos[s1] + Cos[s2] + Cos[s1] Cos[s2] + 1]},
   Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshStyle -> {Directive[Thick, Lighter@Blue]},
   PlotStyle -> None]
  }]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: HI Michael, thanks a lot, this is very helpful! it solves my problem, but I have a related question: I can plot the curve as you described, but I wonder if I can map this curve to a curve on a unit sphere, i.e., for any vector on the previous curve,  the intersection of this direction and the unit sphere will form a point, and all such points on the sphere will form another curve. I wonder if this is possible?  The reason I ask this is because the final curve I need is on the unit sphere. Thanks again!