# How can I plot a line in three dimensions?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I'm a newbie at Mathematica. I'm trying to build a line in  three dimensions. The best I can do is to build two planes and get a line on the intersection of those planes, like this:

```
Plot3D[{y = 2 + x, z = 2 - x}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
  ColorFunction -> "RustTones"]
```

It would be nice if someone also can share code showing how to build a line using two vectors.

Comment: `=` means you define `y` to be `2+x`, you are essentially running `{2 + x, 2 - x}`

Comment: Look up `Line`, or `Arrow`, and `InfiniteLine`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to draw a complicated line, take a look at `ParametricPlot3D`

```
ParametricPlot3D[{x, 3 Sin[x], x^2}, {x, -1, 2}]
```

[image]

If you just want to draw a straight line, take a look at `InfiniteLine`

```
Graphics3D[{InfiniteLine[{2, 1, 1}]}, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, Ticks -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
eq1 = y - x - 2;
eq2 = z + x - 2;
```

One can solve a system of equations

```
sol = {x, y, z} /. Solve[{eq1 == 0, eq2 == 0}, {x, y, z}]
```

> {{x, 2 + x, 2 - x}}

to get the intersection in parametric form:

```
ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate@sol, {x, -2, 2}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}]
```

[image]

---

A different approach is to use `Mesh` functions:

```
ContourPlot3D[{eq1 == 0, eq2 == 0}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 
  6}, MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z, f}, eq1 - eq2]}, 
 MeshStyle -> {Thick, Red}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
 ContourStyle -> Directive@{Opacity[0.5]}]
```

[image]

One can fade the surfaces completely to have only the highlighted intersection left:

```
ContourPlot3D[{eq1 == 0, eq2 == 0}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 
  6}, MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z, f}, eq1 - eq2]}, 
 MeshStyle -> {Thick, Red}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
 ContourStyle -> Directive@{Opacity[0]}, BoundaryStyle -> Transparent]
```

[image]

Comment: Regarding your last example: see [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5972).

Answer (score 4):

You could use the equation to generate points and use `ListPointPlot3D`:

```
y[x_] := 2 + x;
z[x_] := 2 - x;
ListPointPlot3D[Table[{x, y[x], z[x]}, {x, -2, 2, 0.01}]]
```

[image: Points]

You could use a `Graphics3D` with `Line` (this is the one I would recommend, use `Axes` if you want `Plot` type axes):

```
Graphics3D[{Red, Line[{{-2, y[-2], z[-2]}, {2, y[2], z[2]}}]}]
```

[image: graphics]