# Finding intersection points of two surfaces (lists)

Tags: plotting, computational-geometry, intersection

I would like to find the intersection points of two surfaces which are constructed with `ListPlot3D`. The first list is

```
x={{0.687522, 0.672048, 0.657758, 0.644584, 0.632436, 0.621219, 0.61084,
   0.601212, 0.592255, 0.583898, 0.57608}, {0.718239, 0.70296, 
  0.688594, 0.675148, 0.662596, 0.650892, 0.639979, 0.629794, 
  0.620276, 0.611365, 0.603006}, {0.744103, 0.729406, 0.71536, 
  0.70202, 0.689407, 0.677517, 0.666327, 0.655806, 0.645912, 0.636603,
   0.627836}, {0.76593, 0.752001, 0.738512, 0.725536, 0.713119, 
  0.701286, 0.690045, 0.679387, 0.669294, 0.65974, 
  0.650698}, {0.784468, 0.771368, 0.75855, 0.746088, 0.734038, 
  0.722443, 0.711325, 0.700697, 0.690559, 0.680901, 
  0.671708}, {0.800344, 0.788064, 0.775953, 0.764077, 0.752495, 
  0.741253, 0.730386, 0.719917, 0.709859, 0.700215, 
  0.690982}, {0.814062, 0.802558, 0.791142, 0.779875, 0.768808, 
  0.757989, 0.747455, 0.737236, 0.727353, 0.717818, 
  0.708637}, {0.826019, 0.815231, 0.804478, 0.793809, 0.783271, 
  0.772908, 0.762756, 0.752847, 0.743206, 0.733851, 
  0.724796}, {0.836524, 0.826392, 0.816257, 0.806161, 0.796144, 
  0.786244, 0.776496, 0.766933, 0.757579, 0.748456, 
  0.73958}, {0.845825, 0.836288, 0.826724, 0.817166, 0.807648, 
  0.798205, 0.788868, 0.779666, 0.770625, 0.761767, 
  0.75311}, {0.854114, 0.845118, 0.836077, 0.82702, 0.817975, 
  0.808973, 0.80004, 0.791203, 0.782487, 0.773913, 0.765501}}
```

The second list is :

```
y={{0.86018, 0.823767, 0.783404, 0.740538, 0.697531, 0.656804, 0.619925,
   0.58739, 0.558988, 0.534209, 0.512495}, {0.868675, 0.835506, 
  0.798953, 0.760038, 0.720471, 0.682171, 0.646621, 0.61455, 0.586049,
   0.560854, 0.538561}, {0.876074, 0.845573, 0.812132, 0.776497, 
  0.739939, 0.703976, 0.66993, 0.638615, 0.610325, 0.584988, 
  0.562348}, {0.882593, 0.854335, 0.82349, 0.79062, 0.756691, 0.72291,
   0.690421, 0.660043, 0.632184, 0.606922, 0.584127}, {0.888395, 
  0.862052, 0.83341, 0.802903, 0.771278, 0.739504, 0.708556, 0.679212,
   0.65194, 0.62692, 0.604125}, {0.893601, 0.868915, 0.842169, 
  0.813704, 0.78411, 0.754168, 0.724707, 0.69644, 0.669857, 0.645204, 
  0.622538}, {0.898304, 0.875068, 0.849974, 0.823293, 0.795497, 
  0.767223, 0.739173, 0.711991, 0.68616, 0.661967, 
  0.63953}, {0.902579, 0.880625, 0.856984, 0.831874, 0.805679, 
  0.778923, 0.752202, 0.726087, 0.701042, 0.677375, 
  0.655245}, {0.906485, 0.885673, 0.86332, 0.839607, 0.814846, 
  0.789472, 0.763993, 0.738914, 0.714668, 0.691571, 
  0.66981}, {0.91007, 0.890283, 0.869082, 0.846617, 0.823147, 
  0.799035, 0.774713, 0.750629, 0.727182, 0.704681, 
  0.683333}, {0.913376, 0.894513, 0.874348, 0.853006, 0.830703, 
  0.807745, 0.784502, 0.761367, 0.738705, 0.716816, 0.695914}}
```

I join them with `Join[{x}, {y}]` and the `ListPlot3D` looks like:

[image]

I would like to find the intersection points of those two surfaces.

Comment: What is it that you _really_ want? If you are talking about the 121 points in each `x` and `y`, then there are no points common for both: `ContainsAny[Catenate@x, Catenate@y]` yields `False`. I guess you'd want an `Interpolation` of the surfaces and their (numerical) intersection. But please explain in what form do you want it: a list of 3D points, a function that gives such point given one of the coordinates, an `InterpolatingFunction` describing the curve in 3D, an analytical approximation?

Comment: Ye there are no point in common. I want the numerical intersection of the interpolated surfaces. I just want to see the values of k and l for each intersection point (x^*).  A list of 3D points can be usefull I guess.

Comment: There are already good answers, but here is a way to get approximate common values. `In[383]:= fullx = Flatten[MapIndexed[Flatten[{#2, #1}] &, x, {2}], 1];
fully = Flatten[MapIndexed[Flatten[{#2, #1}] &, y, {2}], 1];
nfx = Nearest[fullx];
nbrs = Map[{#, First[nfx[#]]} &, fully];
close = Select[nbrs, Norm[#[[1]] - #[[2]]] < 1/100 &][[All, 1]]


Out[387]= {{1, 7, 0.619925}, {2, 7, 0.646621}, {3, 7, 0.66993}, {4, 7,
   0.690421}, {5, 7, 0.708556}, {6, 7, 0.724707}, {7, 6, 
  0.767223}, {7, 7, 0.739173}, {8, 6, 0.778923}, {9, 6, 
  0.789472}, {10, 6, 0.799035}, {11, 6, 0.807745}}`

Comment: `ListPlot3D[Join[{x}, {y}], Axes -> True]` gives the range `{1, 11}`; your plot is inconsistent with your description.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using an approach first presented in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5972):

```
xf = ListInterpolation[x]; yf = ListInterpolation[y];
g1 = Plot3D[{xf[x, y], yf[x, y]}, {x, 1, 11}, {y, 1, 11}, 
            AxesLabel -> {"a", "b", "z"}, Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5]];
g2 = Plot3D[{xf[x, y], yf[x, y]}, {x, 1, 11}, {y, 1, 11}, 
            BoundaryStyle -> {1 -> None, 2 -> None, {1, 2} -> {Directive[Thick, Red]}},
            Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> None];
Show[g1, g2]
```

[image: intersection of two interpolating functions]

Answer (score 5):

Let

```
data = {x}~Join~{y};
```

Create integer coordinates:

```
coords = CoordinateBoundsArray[{{1, Length@x}, {1, Length@y}}];
```

Next we join the data with the coordinates for the interpolation:

```
plane1 = Interpolation[Join @@ (Transpose /@ Transpose[{coords, x}])]
plane2 = Interpolation[Join @@ (Transpose /@ Transpose[{coords, y}])]
```

Their plot:

```
plot = Plot3D[{plane1[a, b], plane2[a, b]}, {a, 1, Length@x}, {b, 1, Length@y},
  AxesLabel -> {"a", "b", "z"}, Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5]];
```

Some of the absolute options will be useful:

```
pr = AbsoluteOptions[plot, PlotRange][[1, 2]]
box = AbsoluteOptions[plot, BoxRatios][[1, 2]]
```

Then, a function to find the `b` coordinate for each `a` coordinate (starting value based on `plot`):

```
root[a0_] := With[{a = a0}, b /. FindRoot[plane1[a, b] == plane2[a, b], {b, 6.}]]
```

Their plot:

```
Plot[root[a0], {a0, 1, 11}, AxesLabel -> {"a", "b"}]
```

[image]

The 3D intersection is a parametric line:

```
line = ParametricPlot3D[{a0, root[a0], plane1[a0, root[a0]]}, {a0, 1, 11},
  AxesLabel -> {"a", "b", "z"}, PlotRange -> pr, BoxRatios -> box, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}]
```

[image]

lying on the intersection of the planes:

```
Show[plot, line]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I am going to work in the $k$-$l$-$x^*$ space you seem to prefer.

Here are the two sets of $x^*$ points, which I am presuming are evaluated on the grid

```
CoordinateBoundingBoxArray[{{0., 0.}, {1., 1.}}, .1]
```

That is, the grid with $k$ runs for 0 to 1 in steps of 0.1 and $l$ does the same.

```
xStar1 =
  {{0.687522, 0.672048, 0.657758, 0.644584, 0.632436, 0.621219, 
    0.61084, 0.601212, 0.592255, 0.583898, 0.57608}, 
   {0.718239, 0.70296, 0.688594, 0.675148, 0.662596, 0.650892, 
    0.639979, 0.629794, 0.620276, 0.611365, 0.603006}, 
   {0.744103, 0.729406, 0.71536, 0.70202, 0.689407, 0.677517, 
    0.666327, 0.655806, 0.645912, 0.636603, 0.627836}, 
   {0.76593, 0.752001, 0.738512, 0.725536, 0.713119, 0.701286, 
    0.690045, 0.679387, 0.669294, 0.65974, 0.650698}, 
   {0.784468, 0.771368, 0.75855, 0.746088, 0.734038, 0.722443, 
    0.711325, 0.700697, 0.690559, 0.680901, 0.671708}, 
   {0.800344, 0.788064, 0.775953, 0.764077, 0.752495, 0.741253, 
    0.730386, 0.719917, 0.709859, 0.700215, 0.690982}, 
   {0.814062, 0.802558, 0.791142, 0.779875, 0.768808, 0.757989, 
    0.747455, 0.737236, 0.727353, 0.717818, 0.708637}, 
   {0.826019, 0.815231, 0.804478, 0.793809, 0.783271, 0.772908, 
    0.762756, 0.752847, 0.743206, 0.733851, 0.724796}, 
   {0.836524, 0.826392, 0.816257, 0.806161, 0.796144, 0.786244, 
    0.776496, 0.766933, 0.757579, 0.748456, 0.73958}, 
   {0.845825, 0.836288, 0.826724, 0.817166, 0.807648, 0.798205, 
    0.788868, 0.779666, 0.770625, 0.761767, 0.75311}, 
   {0.854114, 0.845118, 0.836077, 0.82702, 0.817975, 0.808973, 
    0.80004, 0.791203, 0.782487, 0.773913, 0.765501}};

xStar2 =
  {{0.86018, 0.823767, 0.783404, 0.740538, 0.697531, 0.656804,
    0.619925, 0.58739, 0.558988, 0.534209, 0.512495},
   {0.868675, 0.835506, 0.798953, 0.760038, 0.720471, 0.682171,
    0.646621, 0.61455, 0.586049, 0.560854, 0.538561},
   {0.876074, 0.845573, 0.812132, 0.776497, 0.739939, 0.703976,
    0.66993, 0.638615, 0.610325, 0.584988, 0.562348}, 
   {0.882593, 0.854335, 0.82349, 0.79062, 0.756691, 0.72291,
    0.690421, 0.660043, 0.632184, 0.606922, 0.584127},
   {0.888395, 0.862052, 0.83341, 0.802903, 0.771278, 0.739504,
    0.708556, 0.679212, 0.65194, 0.62692, 0.604125},
   {0.893601, 0.868915, 0.842169, 0.813704, 0.78411, 0.754168,
    0.724707, 0.69644, 0.669857, 0.645204, 0.622538},
   {0.898304, 0.875068, 0.849974, 0.823293, 0.795497, 0.767223,
    0.739173, 0.711991, 0.68616, 0.661967, 0.63953},
   {0.902579, 0.880625, 0.856984, 0.831874, 0.805679, 0.778923,
    0.752202, 0.726087, 0.701042, 0.677375, 0.655245},
   {0.906485, 0.885673, 0.86332, 0.839607, 0.814846, 0.789472,
    0.763993, 0.738914, 0.714668, 0.691571, 0.66981}, 
   {0.91007, 0.890283, 0.869082, 0.846617, 0.823147, 0.799035,
    0.774713, 0.750629, 0.727182, 0.704681, 0.683333},
   {0.913376, 0.894513, 0.874348, 0.853006, 0.830703, 0.807745, 
    0.784502, 0.761367, 0.738705, 0.716816, 0.695914}};
```

Now I am going to make interpolating functions for these $x^*$ values over the grid.

```
pts[x_] :=
  With[{grid = CoordinateBoundingBoxArray[{{0., 0.}, {1., 1.}}, .1]},
    Catenate[Transpose /@ Transpose[{grid, x}]]]

xStar1Pts = pts[xStar1]; xStar2Pts = pts[xStar2];
```

I now have data in a form `Interpolation` likes.

```
xStar1PtsF = Interpolation[xStar1Pts]; xStar2PtsF = Interpolation[xStar2Pts];
```

Now I will find the points along the intersection of `xStar1PtsF` and `xStar2PtsF`, which are the roots of `xStar1PtsF - xStar2PtsF` at the 11 $k$-coordinates of the grid and near $l$ = .5.

```
kPts = Subdivide[1., 10];
lPts = 
  (FindRoot[xStar1PtsF[#, l] - xStar2PtsF[#, l], {l, .5}] & /@ kPts)[[All, 1, 2]]
```

> ```
> {0.637846, 0.629023, 0.616597, 0.60183, 0.585783, 0.569174, 0.552539, 
>   0.536255, 0.520555, 0.505568, 0.491337}
> ```

Now I put this all together to get the 3D coordinates of the intersection points.

```
 klPts = Transpose[{kPts, lPts, MapThread[xStar1PtsF, {kPts, lPts}]}]
```

> ```
> {{0., 0.637846, 0.607112}, {0.1, 0.629023, 0.636951}, {0.2, 0.616597,  0.664536}, 
>  {0.3, 0.60183, 0.689845}, {0.4, 0.585783, 0.712876}, {0.5, 0.569174, 0.733694}, 
>  {0.6, 0.552539, 0.752417}, {0.7, 0.536255, 0.769201}, {0.8, 0.520555, 0.784227}, 
>  {0.9, 0.505568, 0.797682}, {1., 0.491337, 0.809751}}
> ```

And, finally, here is the plot of everything.

```
Show[
  Plot3D[{xStar1PtsF[k, l], xStar2PtsF[k, l]}, {k, 0, 1}, {l, 0, 1}, 
    AxesLabel -> {"k", "l", "x"^"*"}],
  Graphics3D[{Red, Sphere[#, Scaled[.015]] & /@ klPts}]]
```

[image: plot]