# Better discretization for intersections of algebraic surfaces

Tags: computational-geometry

I am looking for better, preferably analytical approaches to discretize intersections of algebraic surfaces. When surfaces are not identical, these solutions are either curves or points.

An extremely simplified example of problems with plain old `DiscretizeRegion` can be seen below. In this case algebraic surfaces are just spheres, and their intersection is a circle. In this example, I extract points in the discretized version for a specific pair of spheres, and rotate them to match a planar circle:

```
MeshPrimitives[DiscretizeRegion@RegionIntersection[Sphere /@ {-#, #}], 0] /.
    coord : {Repeated[_?NumericQ, {3}]} :> 
     RotationTransform[{#, {0, 0, 1}}][coord][[1 ;; 2]] &@
  {0.09666984222273534`, 0.3622850077710253`, 0.33076353297934696`} // Graphics
```

[image]

That doesn't really look like a good distribution one would expect from just intersecting two spheres. Histogram of line lengths looks equally bad:

```
RegionMeasure /@ 
    MeshPrimitives[
     DiscretizeRegion@RegionIntersection[Sphere /@ {-#, #}], 1] &@
  {0.09666984222273534`, 0.3622850077710253`, 0.33076353297934696`} // Histogram
```

[image]

I can limit size of these gaps with `MaxCellMeasure`option, but it doesn't really remove the problem involving non-uniformity:

```
RegionMeasure /@ 
    MeshPrimitives[
     DiscretizeRegion[RegionIntersection[Sphere /@ {-#, #}], 
      MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> .01}], 1] &@
  {0.09666984222273534`, 0.3622850077710253`, 0.33076353297934696`} // Histogram
```

[image]

What other methods there are to improve quality of such discretizations? Note that spheres are just an example; I'm looking for a general solution for intersections of arbitrary polynomial surfaces.

**EDIT:** I think this can be accomplished with `SemialgebraicComponentInstances` and `NDSolve`, but it's work in progress.

Comment: Maybe you can adapt some of the solutions [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5968) to this case?

Comment: @J.M. This answer seems quite similar to approach I'm developing: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/64923/3056

Comment: That's what I thought; I also linked to a nice paper in the comments to that answer.