# Plot intersection curves of surfaces

Tags: plotting, graphics

Writing:

```
r[k_] = {k, 2 Sqrt[6] Cos[u], 2 Sqrt[6] Sin[u]};
ParametricPlot3D[r /@ {-1, 1}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

I get:

[image]

and this is fine. On the other hand, writing:

```
A = ImplicitRegion[3 x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 27 && x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 25, {x, y, z}];
RegionPlot3D[A]
```

I get:

[image]

and I do not understand why. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Unless you use some special regions the region plot is still based on sampling and it is tough to get informative results for 1D region in 3D. So you have to improvise like in at least closely related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5968/5478 The accepted answer works almost out of hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is simply because you said `== 27` there. The region is simply too small to show. very thin region!  (line thin)

You could try

```
a=ImplicitRegion[3 x^2+y^2+z^2<=27 ,{x,y,z}];
b=ImplicitRegion[x^2+y^2+z^2<=  25 ,{x,y,z}];
Show[RegionPlot3D[a,PlotStyle->Red],RegionPlot3D[b,PlotStyle->Blue]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

Reparametrizing:

```
f[u_, v_] := Sqrt[27] {Sin[u] Cos[v]/Sqrt[3], Sin[u] Sin[v], Cos[u]}
g[u_, v_] := 5 {Sin[u] Cos[v], Sin[u] Sin[v], Cos[u]}
```

From inspection the cartesian definitions intersect at circles in y-z plane at$x=\pm 1$. This can be done:

```
(* the 2 surfaces *)
p = ParametricPlot3D[{f[u, v], g[u, v]}, {u, 0, Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, 
Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 50]
(* the cartesian definition *)
f[x_, y_, z_] := 3 x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 27
g[x_, y_, z_] := x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 25
(* visualization *)
Show[p, ParametricPlot3D[{x, Cos[u] Sqrt[25 - x^2], 
    Sin[u] Sqrt[25 - x^2]} /. 
   Quiet@Solve[f[x, y, z] == g[x, y, z], {x, y, z}], {u, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image]