# How to find the intersection curve between two surfaces

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to find the graphic of the curve of the intersection of the hyperbolic paraboloid $z=y^2-x^2$ and the cylinder $x^2+y^2=1$. I could show them together:

[image]

I want to see the curve of intersection highlighted, is it possible? I've already searched everywhere without success.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5968)?

Comment: @J.M. Thank you very much. I followed one of the answers and plot: ContourPlot3D[{x^2 + y^2 == 1, z=y^2-x^2},
   {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, {z, -2, 2},Contours -> {0}, ContourStyle -> Opacity[0], Mesh -> None, 
 BoundaryStyle -> {1 -> None, 2 -> None, {1, 2} -> {{Green, Tube[.03]}}}, 
 Boxed -> False]. Mathematica tells me y^2-x^2 is not a valid variable

Comment: Clear all variables (``ClearAll["Global`*"]``) and try again. Also, your second equation should be `z == y^2 - x^2`; `=` and `==` are different things.

Comment: @J.M. Thank you again, it worked. However I couldn't put them together, Mathematica says: Show
:Could not combine the graphics objects in  Showp1,p2, .

 General
:Further output of  Get::noopen  will be suppressed during this calculation.

 Get
:Cannot open  1241>> .

 Get
:Cannot open  1241>> .

 Get
:Cannot open  1>> .

Comment: @J.M. I put Show[p1,p2,p3], where p1=Plot3D[z=y^2-x^2,{x,-2,2},{y,-2,2}], p2=ContourPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 == 1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}],p3=ContourPlot3D[{x^2 + y^2 == 1, z==y^2-x^2},
   {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, {z, -2, 2},Contours -> {0}, ContourStyle -> Opacity[0], Mesh -> None, 
 BoundaryStyle -> {1 -> None, 2 -> None, {1, 2} -> {{Green, Tube[.03]}}}, 
 Boxed -> False]

Comment: Try removing the `ContourStyle -> Opacity[0]` in the code you have. Also, you have again made the mistake of using `=` in `p1`; it is not necessary there. Please do be careful about this.

Comment: It worked when I write p3=ContourPlot3D[{x^2 + y^2 == 1, z==y^2-x^2},
   {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, {z, -2, 2},Contours -> {0}, Mesh -> None, 
 BoundaryStyle -> {1 -> None, 2 -> None, {1, 2} -> {{Green, Tube[.03]}}}, 
 Boxed -> False]. Thank you very much. However the show command still have the same problems

Comment: @J.M. When I wrote: p1=Plot3D[z==y^2-x^2,{x,-2,2},{y,-2,2}], this gave me an empty box. Did you know why?

Comment: You don't need the `z==` in `Plot3D[]`, as you can see from the documentation. Also, the `ContourPlot3D[]` without the `ContourStyle -> Opacity[0]` should already be showing the two surfaces, so I don't understand why you insist on using `Show[]`.

Comment: I've just made a commentary, it's already worked with ContourPlot3D. Thank you again! you helped me a lot.