# Intersection points of Taylor polynomial and trigonometric function

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, series-expansion, trigonometry

I seem to be unable to find intersection points between following functions, and plot both functions and points on the same plot:

```
a[x_, y_] := Cos[x^2 + y^2];

d[x_, y_] := Evaluate[Series[Cos[x^2 + y^2], {x, 0, 4}, {y, 0, 4}] // Normal];
```

This is what I've tried so far

```
ContourPlot3D[{a == 0, d == 0}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z, f}, a - d]}, MeshStyle -> {{Thick, Black}}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
ContourStyle -> Directive[Orange, Opacity[0.5], Specularity[White, 30]]]
```

Plotting them with `Plot3D`:

```
Plot3D[{a[x, y], d[x, y]}, {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}]
```

seems to give rather different results.

Comment: What are `a` and `d`?

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/275)?

Comment: OK, but should that be `a[x, y] == 0`, etc., in the contour plot, then?  And should `b` and `g` be changed to `a` and `d`?

Comment: @J. M. Thanks for link. I've looked at it, but it it deals with 2D, while I am looking for 3D implementation. @Michael E2 My mistake, changed to `a` and `d`.

Comment: Your description of the problem sounds like you're solving `a[x, y] == d[x, y]` (not like J.M.'s link), but the `ContourPlot3D` code suggests you might be solving the system `{a[x, y] == 0, d[x, y] == 0}` (exactly like J.M.'s link).  Which is it?

Comment: So, you want the *curves* of intersection and not points? Have you seen [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5968)?

Comment: @J.M. You keep beating me to the question I want to link! :)

Comment: @Michael, it helps a lot when they're problems I've tangled with before. ;)

Comment: @J. M. Checked both provided link, but still cannot get it. Using `ContourPlot3D` I get nothing even close to intersection of those two plots. Used simple `Plot3D` to check how it looks like, and my `ContourPlot3D` is far from this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a brute force approach.

```
a[x_, y_] := Cos[x^2 + y^2]
d[x_, y_] = Series[Cos[x^2 + y^2], {x, 0, 4}, {y, 0, 4}] // Normal;

Plot3D[{a[x, y], d[x, y]}, {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi},
  PlotRange -> 2,
  ClippingStyle -> None]
```

[image: plot]

```
mesh = Catenate[CoordinateBoundingBoxArray[{{-π, -π}, {π, π}}, .0025]];
xyPts = Select[mesh, Norm[#] > .75 && Abs[a @@ # - d @@ #] < .01 &];
xyzPts = {Sequence @@ #, a @@ #} & /@ xyPts;
ListPointPlot3D[xyzPts, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: intersections]

Notes

- The evaluation of the expression for `xyPts` is rather slow.
- The excluded the points having a norm less than .75 to speed up the plotting. The empty circle in the center of the plot would otherwise be filled.